# The Programming Language Quiz, Mark II - Robbers

Tags: code-challenge, cops-and-robbers, obfuscation

[Cops challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops)

### The Robbers' Challenge

1. **Find a vulnerable answer.** That is, an answer which hasn't been cracked yet and which isn't *safe* yet either.
2. **Crack it by figuring out its language.** That is, find *any* language in which the given program is a valid program (subject to the rules outlined in the Cops' Challenge above). It doesn't matter if this is the language the cop intended.

   Once you have found a working language, post an answer to the Robbers' thread and comment below the Cop's answer. If you don't have enough reputation to comment, say this in your answer and someone will comment for you.

**The output format must be the same as the cop's intended solution in order to constitute a valid crack.**

**Every user only gets one guess per answer.** This includes telling other people the answer, or hints towards your guesses. You must not crack your own answer (obviously...).

The user who cracked the largest number of answers wins the robbers' challenge. Ties are broken by the sum of bytes of cracked answers (more is better).

**Good luck Robbers!**

Comment: **Important**: Please be nice to TIO and don't just (write a script or manually) test all of the languages there. TIO is very busy already.

Comment: I feel like the whole Cops/Robbers thing is backwards. Shouldn't the Robbers be hiding their programs and Cops be trying to bust them?

Comment: @JoKing ... just PPCG terminology. There is no reason to be incompatible, and there is absolutely no reason to change all the past [tag:cops-and-robbers] ---questions--- challenges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [23](http://web.archive.org/web/20071012224934/http://www.philipp-winterberg.de/software/23e.php), [posted](/a/155255) by [jimmy23013](/u/25180)

```
22,1,16,10,10,-1,1,10,2,12,27,0,211
```

Answer (score 21):

## Game save of [the Powder Toy](http://powdertoy.co.uk/Download.html), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155079/44718) by [moonheart08](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77964/moonheart08)

`xxd` dump:

```
00000000: 4f50 5331 5c04 9960 961c 0c00 425a 6839  OPS1\..`....BZh9
00000010: 3141 5926 5359 b855 1468 00c2 eaff f6ff  1AY&SY.U.h......
00000020: 5446 0c4a 01ef 403f 2f5f 74bf f7df f040  TF.J..@?/_t....@
00000030: 0203 0000 4050 8000 1002 0840 01bc 16a5  ....@P.....@....
00000040: 61a2 6909 18c1 4c64 4f22 7a83 4030 08c9  a.i...LdO"z.@0..
00000050: a323 6932 0c8f 536a 0d0a 34f4 a635 31aa  .#i2..Sj..4..51.
00000060: 7a4d 0c8f 5000 0006 4681 ea00 3469 e90e  zM..P...F...4i..
00000070: 1a69 8219 0d34 c8c9 8403 4d00 6134 6993  .i...4....M.a4i.
00000080: 0008 1a09 1453 4ca0 311a 7a9a 68d3 468d  .....SL.1.z.h.F.
00000090: 0003 d4c8 000d 000d 0f98 debe 75b8 487f  ............u.H.
000000a0: 2256 900d a121 2107 bb12 1208 4409 e89e  "V...!!.....D...
000000b0: ddeb 1f17 e331 5ead 7cec db16 65d5 6090  .....1^.|...e.`.
000000c0: 2422 b0ca cc2a 5585 c9c9 dc44 4ac0 f14d  $"...*U....DJ..M
000000d0: 6076 5a40 8484 536a 953b b44b 190a 90f0  `vZ@..Sj.;.K....
000000e0: 8a20 310e 95ad ca24 2d4b 0097 1a69 a919  . 1....$-K...i..
000000f0: 8d5b 0010 0242 1c59 8981 409a ec10 9024  .[...B.Y..@....$    
00000100: 2369 e1d8 a222 53dc 8231 dc4f a891 4b0b  #i..."S..1.O..K.
00000110: cf61 20d8 c1b4 4269 e25b 072d 5fb4 f1c4  .a ...Bi.[.-_...
00000120: a66b 62c8 069c ebc6 0225 9900 9852 21e9  .kb......%...R!.
00000130: d2e3 63d8 069a 7a69 124e eafc 3c5d 4028  ..c...zi.N..<]@(
00000140: dd15 6f81 0d2b 8007 816d f581 36f9 e58f  ..o..+...m..6...
00000150: 8cec 30e0 0378 40f9 b52c 4a17 b999 808d  ..0..x@..,J.....
00000160: d583 106f fd5e aaf5 ea8f a01b f5fc 9be5  ...o.^..........
00000170: 8e40 e05d 3a0a 2470 964d ef31 4c17 45da  .@.]:.$p.M.1L.E.
00000180: 3242 6692 251a aacc 6523 220c 73a7 7e3b  2Bf.%...e#".s.~;
00000190: cecf 635d 3cb6 08a0 7930 9566 0833 1d90  ..c]<...y0.f.3..
000001a0: 993a 5b8a e548 b34c 3fa8 0cbe 84aa d23e  .:[..H.L?......>
000001b0: 0129 c73b 1859 afa8 a984 990d cb0c db77  .).;.Y.........w
000001c0: 8fa8 df2f eda2 b779 72a7 4333 9382 0794  .../...yr.C3....
000001d0: 1f14 2340 c199 344a 48e1 6214 85a8 82a9  ..#@..4JH.b.....
000001e0: 5f6a 5a55 6993 6395 4350 41a2 396f 3613  _jZUi.c.CPA.9o6.
000001f0: 20f1 4d52 d289 b60f 2ea1 0040 8009 08ea   .MR.......@....
00000200: e782 4084 847f 8bb9 229c 2848 5c2a 8a34  ..@.....".(H\*.4
00000210: 00
```

- First, de-compress it with 7zip
- Then, run `strings` on it, you will find some strings like "gravityEnable", "aheat_enable"
- Google these magic words, and you will got this game's source code page

Comment: Well done! To note, The Powder Toy actually counts as a language. It is capable of everything that specifies a language on this site (Yes, someone built a computer in it), and is also within the rules of this cop&robbers (It has a wikipedia page, in the form of a redirect to falling sand games)
It was fun to come up with an answer like this, and i congratulate @tsh on figuring it out.

Answer (score 17):

## [Beatnik](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Beatnik), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155052) by [fergusq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66323/fergusq)

Output as `xxd` dump:

```
00000000: 0102 0304 0506 0708 090a 0b0c 0d0e 0f10  ................
00000010: 1112 1314 1516 1718 191a 1b1c 1d1e 1f20  ............... 
00000020: 2122 2324 2526 2728 292a 2b2c 2d2e 2f30  !"#$%&'()*+,-./0
00000030: 3132 3334 3536 3738 393a 3b3c 3d3e 3f40  123456789:;<=>?@
00000040: 4142 4344 4546 4748 494a 4b4c 4d4e 4f50  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
00000050: 5152 5354 5556 5758 595a 5b5c 5d5e 5f60  QRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
00000060: 6162 6364                                abcd
```

I tried it with [this interpreter](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/beatnik/impl/BEATNIK.c).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVdbcts2FP0WV3GdfIiyKFu0nTS1wqRumsxk0sQex19O/QGBoIiIAjAEaNnNeDdZQzeQhbkX4EOiKmWsNvUDMi@Ae859gDimgwml9/u78Ovrk4sPb98BF4blKmc4wozEDMa38IoYYqTgFM5kriTXDJ5PclKwXyRlRIyJZnsyn7zwAIBAJsUEDJ8xIBO5Bxcp15ASDUIaGDMmwDBtWFzN4I8qxhn6juWMcLEHu/ue95gLmhWI/lybmMu99EXLlHMxaduouVXMmjyakhx2SXxNBGV@@RTYsHqjag6DyxkxK3M4gqY5GY@zehtaC6H5RLAYnEVJ5V9LHuOE/UDmOvVbS2oQOxCKSZwwU29xEDZGvwdfvE6JoQKgs/hTOMSvq5HXsWt4NAw@B9MoDHRgcF9nnnIk5X@O0Bv1bUpEr7cTvT594zx1rAd@FX3G/R3e7@PHndfZ309oJjXzE8Sul3ShOypX1IZk1SBXDTerhtsuPqgIHxfkpiUTPeeGpn6TSNUr7R2KTQJPjgFb7QyzBoLdGJjLPLb1xnn0V9dMBaFlbG02v8u@RhuXjrGk01GD9LREkgpEMRtjLxMRQ8w1JYjITQOKBX24058ap2YuK8c6ABLHYFI2C1w/QM50kS0QbAgOpu/Gh6M9c2hvhSrMop1cHA7mmmQFa6G0em4LoJ@bsEqfFkIWpo3bABlr87eMJRw2GAclCuZNF2NjvUPCc41jLmegGZUiXptJEy1Xq0nrwGxBI1xHY05UVb8mufYRxoRO14LrfzAxrYbdgtBBO/dV4NigZs4p2xy6WfvwAMDDVUA95QpIykgMoh@6I4lv5aTqBXw9/8ly@b1DaqKlE1qaeOLvlB0CyztqnixDJg8he7QtWdE1/5Lvj6D7ZC1d10bif0hsfY8h0364LdenW3H9AXn9T2zLN@9HI91JBZVL1B@zms00Gq5ui1lC8N3htp2g8kjxFWajGmRMTExq009QkQzQ4caQ7uw16nWQeJELQIg7b51KUO6Gc/d2UE99uoq@hMEhfh8EYXCE4xF@PgueBNYaluPQ/RG6BUc4iUuGdwicyNxHCTDaVTs4qn6/vEJ5P@KaZColPmK@bKCMzOSc5dY46JLu1bFLBqaea60IxrNrL@E6NXdNQNwFtE4uKaeJwCwCW2LFnxsrB0pOyumCSgLstABbU2tmFkTUEpG2NmsRwUp@kIYdYwdg9ZJCUMOlAKJ1MWMaF9ui2u4YswkXAiUiyASrbMuO7Y2966tB2LOceJbhKkBuqEUtMdcEdaRqMNgU77po3Or1KXBTGGgZcSvctrDUBg/ep8NSA7oeU7anWzI442MncDdIUsuvPUWtnEx8rSqRGJUog4FWVml2ykd8KI9PRY9WlFFjm8R/9Obk4uR3eH1@fnp@jAcGZjJn1dUJmH3n4w/xyB4YdsONf9gbrRyZDUoZqKNVk@j3ryLq1j/mCZ5e@O3046vzkzPPw7pfuKpim9sSY2HsJKJntyv/LKB2KP9Z2CTCG91to6ROTqfuXsU80SgKD3uwbF2kxPKyb6vveIZqtduOEqk3ArdLxDy5v79/z00XzLev377ClBSCc0FgyjJCXnrveVbNfPuLa44tUto/Fpjgolis10RIeey9y6VMU3V7mw4uLy/t7yVceh@KaWEMIYrDVF5zsfM3)

Comment: Welcome to the site! I have commented on the cops post for you, but there is some doubt about whether this actually works in Beatnik. Could you provide the interpreter/compiler you tested this solution on?

Comment: [Are you sure it's beatnik](https://tio.run/##S0pNLMnLzP7/3zezRF2h5PCSw0sUshNL8zIz8xIVslNzEhPtuXwzc6Ayh7dlFmfmKRRAxINL8xSKS0sR6osT8/Lzrbi8i/LzMzIKKiszdKOiokA4SiGKy680u7SkJDGxIFMhO78sM0/x/38A)?

Comment: At least it works with [this Beatnik interpreter](https://github.com/graue/esofiles/blob/master/beatnik/impl/BEATNIK.c).

Comment: Also, thanks for commenting, caird! :)

Comment: No! I tried Beatnik! So many times! :'(

Answer (score 12):

## [Element](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Element), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155054/78059) by [NoOneIsHere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48922/nooneishere)

```
1 100'[2:`1+a`]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S81JzU3NK/n/31DB0MBAPdrIKsFQOzEh9v9/AA)

Don't have enough rep to comment.

Answer (score 8):

## [COM file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155023/44718) by [NieDzejkob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55934/niedzejkob)

```
huCX5DBP^h~0_GG1<h32X542P[18F18h42X%AAP[h!.X%OOS`M a@<euws
```

- Download [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/) (if you are not working on 32 bit windows / dos)
- save the content as `1.com`
- execute it

btw, I know nothing about COM file. The code looks similar to EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE for me. So I just tried to download DOSBox and run it.

Answer (score 8):

## [festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festival_Speech_Synthesis_System), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155471/66323) by [quartata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45151/quartata)

```
;#.#;‏⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠‌​
;echo {1..99};
(SayText "")
(SayText "hs sh (but which?) fl")
(SayText "link herring obscure, blame2 premier")
(SayText "don't forget to look up")
(define(f x)(cond((> x 100)())((print x))((f(+ x 1)))))
(f 1)
```

Run with `festival -b file.txt`. It prints some warnings for me like `Linux: can't open /dev/dsp` but I guess that's allowed in the rules. Alternatively it may play some noises if the system has audio enabled.

Comment: The link `festival` in the header line is broken.

Answer (score 6):

## [Milky Way](https://github.com/zachgates/Milky-Way), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155039/64121) by [tfbninja](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69912/tfbninja)

```
print-ZL¡;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83Mya7ULU@s/P@/oCgzr0Q3yufQQuv//wE)

The actual code is `ZL¡` which works as following:

```
Z      push 100 to stack
 L     inclusive range
  ¡    output ToS and exit
```

Comment: Good job! Did you brute force TIO?

Comment: @tfbninja No, I've actually [used the language before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A64121+milky-way)

Comment: Did the upside down excl. give it away? I didn't see another way to print out.

Comment: @tfbninja Yes that was what reminded me of the language. `!` outputs without terminating the program. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83Mya7ULU@s/P@/oCgzr0Q3ykfR@v9/AA "Milky Way – Try It Online"). The command is missing in the command list, but is used a lot [in the examples](https://github.com/zachgates/Milky-Way#for-loops).

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 6):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), [posted](/a/155043) by [ovs](/u/64121)

```
"0" < q <= s' * 1e' * g * 1061 * 19 * 77
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X8lAScFGoVDBxlahWF1BS8EwFUSmg1gGZoYgyhJImJv//w8A)

Answer (score 6):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155093/9365) by [Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien)

```
??MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution
Map[Print,1..100]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/397etzSnJLMssSgzsSTVo7IgtSg9NT83taQoM9klsxhIJZWWZObncfkmFkQHFGXmlegY6ukZGhjE/v8PAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Huginn](https://codestation.org/?h-action=menu-project&menu=submenu-project&page=&project=huginn), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155058/12012) by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

```
main(){i=1;while(i<101){print("{} ".format(i));i+=1;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxDoAgEATArxgqiMFIjT6GQmETOQiiFoSvezr1hMuDiDk6kFQNq7FPwLFJLGY2quUCqlK0PohpTyW6KqGUxfjH3pnflCsSnaw1Je2Kvz8)

Answer (score 5):

## [Golunar](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Golunar), [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155094/76162)  by Esolanging Fruit

```
814918243305927192311963944207
```

Translates to the brainfuck program:

```
++++++++++[->++++++++++<]>[->+.<]
```

Comment: Do you have a Golunar interpreter handy?

Comment: @MDXF, no interpreter, but a [translator](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri8b%22%3E%3C%2B-.%2C%5B%5D%22f%3D1%3E&input=239234107117088762456728667968602154633390994619022073954825877681363348343524058579165785448174718768772358485472231582844556848101441556) from a [previous PPCG question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52712/brainfk-to-unary-and-back)

Comment: If you want to check [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155090/76162), I've already done so, and it's not Golunar (and I don't think Esolanging Fruit would use the same language twice)

Comment: Thanks for the link but I guess I won't need it based on ^ :P

Answer (score 5):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), [posted](/a/155102) by [Adyrem](/u/77759)

```
i=100 while(i>0){p(100-i+"d")!}i=%<>--1;if(_@==0){_@=-100}end;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/z/T1tDAQKE8IzMnVSPTzkCzukADKKCbqa2UoqSpWJtpq2pjp6traJ2ZphHvYGsLVACkdIFKalPzUqwV/v8HAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Unbalanced](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Unbalanced), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops/155036#155036) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656)

I can't write any program in this language, just that there are a lot of unbalanced parentheses. Which reminds me of this language.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVfbbuM2EH3XVwyEBUzClzq9V7AN9LKLDdBiC2z7ZBu7jEzHQmXJIOWsso6/PZ0hdSElOy1QoEpiS8PDM2eGw6GyE/ovmabPz8n@kKsC3j/qQu4nr7OHROXZXmZFUI38Igox@TXRvuHnnVBBECSZTjYSogjeFyrJ7mG8gNusoC9raCBscB5EHzjcwByW69Z6GkSi5PAZzXTPqgFRAvs8vOHcm98gzx3k2EWKBidc1GceBPmx@EfBNabxSJJF6di7muuRVnSPo1HtYcce1tPt4Eh4sPU1syWqlvdSrUfQ3PLrI0SwXEOJ5CXdswGzwhhLo7TkI1D4MIetEYZGlNbYPfxy7WOX45t1i@Ivsw67rPwaa01qUOsOK1MRjjnMaaR83vUFXsc6XfehaYkJW3ehxjpdW@iy1aEuxOer685AbldLPZJG02jpyFleVN5Yp6Opm5mFI7OXlU5OFl6ggJeDnVrssop09sI6Gl9pG@PMUUyXt45oQ26DNeBTEzbRNAE65X6Do@qYgbN10ZQC23ZMLUcl5HQxdafuogfE3u0AtE3@9cZy9hVxaShcp62p9thYGsUBPOHzfI5xzXvmL6y5mbXFLyfYIDiIzYak@y0BRY0oFO4/tfCmAdQGkxxNyRGjO5JeD@jSmHC7Othzg532sMMbNF7EXuIdu7wfDBKuYa1@P9S6VdMARcSUPKRJLArsoltdvKopkAH3C24JjJPDcIgG/HDROttcQJ8H6BV97Mlts9jkuXmoxjGl5jwzD1jopgDMQxlUX7ikqdAFCZ3DtBp@BUmWFHY0L3ZSfUq0xCSY9pygD3VQsvCjviakhev8qGKJ1Idj0ThiK5tZKgolH6RCR8Jk447TnqIk2om03@2cGmeYbFvAjJAtyZ2901jmEP6Z3YlUZLHcwHQyDVGWfpOKTo3@lOdpPcAG40EUR7boZSr3EEM4vfnyq6@/@fa7738IkfSNSLXspqi@5vCHOsqarWzggcbV7abO3q6rsXrV7BMro1LTuuENBhoxa0YbVRimgRxoUwoVjUvp0Ttw9CHoKHdtzMRMfyU3PoWp92a81KRB8P6cCk/XhTm1YrOqgmSrPJZa35pC6ApvKsdDoZ9wED1q44hyzkzVPlJm8N0lHKDbvTgAK/KKYJKrDaeenBiYv05zkErlCsLb7EGkycaWUtjzuRq84BQH/4PXK06pUpZKYtULSk3d@5/wcTaGEjfUTqaH32R2dAq9Mc3hmKVJJnGBw3AUgFf4b@1bteE0O1KqCqPFvYzs/apwZizzQ4EbSK@rLfhhm6S4PdW9nkwmFm8/ceHHYgTjsdBxkozxvFzhz7tjgSFpEPSLdojxvVzE6BfifCP1pJ0sabIsZXwsJE19bW/xgNlJ2CYK0x7n@73INhQeSTjSvwFE7eglVod0R6SUm5WR8zvmqiDGRMOesoVsIMukcIU80JyqcXiTJNTtJDvu7zCEfGusSZtNlxAXapNg4YvHegmd1WwPiQ6GVl/v8k/2KAgBG9VeJKan3b4Dxu3THDY5BBCnpibuZfEjrkgAKfbYrdl13hZkuGgkrmpFOItTdzFwWkrqVRWEZXkxsThOwABw/VApHn8J9mJm@mC4C60b/vRUWzDHtZFTVvD9qK7J4TBcZSHHHoo7gF7gLnI@9DirbHdpK3OflcKh3FNPxcaWPQL7SEwflyh4ZCWO0M@oYcYXJ8Md1CcTJpM01SzkMAD3whOqOKoMq567A9KcAx7QCU32Qqvq3A/NJ2h9YSKpGSgC@pi@WzNLbN7QLr0@z3usMrfN1V5UGxbTR/KtVtFT32zxeqRamVVpDvF4pyZble@rkuZgji27UH6115Xw6sWsh2FwPeQ4z/BNCRg1YS8E1nvtYH5vL0SSVtnx8sOD5@fnsXzms//h4jN@WpwW5xk78dn5vGALhr8zsszY3w)

The language seems to be not on TIO, so I just run the Haskell interpreter.

Answer (score 5):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), [posted](/a/155099) by [boboquack](/u/60483)

```
#define ss "/}O'=){/'HI}-){"
+1<2+3
"}@"$>!'d'/1
> ss ss {<}
1/1=2-1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/185JTUtMy9VobhYQUm/1l/dVrNaX93Ds1ZXs1qJS9vQxkjbmEup1kFJxU5RPUVd35DLDqQUiKptarkM9Q1tjXQNrf//BwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Quartic](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Conor_O%27Brien/Compilers/Quartic), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155274/61384) by Conor O'Brien

```
decl	a,z,e
set	a,1
set	z,1
loop	z
print	a
cmp	e,a,'d'
if	e
dec	z
end
inc	a
end
```

The program made perfect sense. The challenge is to figure out what language it was. Luckily, I was able to use [complex techniques](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22decl%22+%22set%22+%22loop%22+%22print%22+%22cmp%22&oq=%22decl%22+%22set%22+%22loop%22+%22print%22+%22cmp%22&safe=active&ssui=on) to find an esolang with the right commands.

Answer (score 5):

## [Curry](http://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/currywiki/start), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155091/69655) by [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656)

```
f[]=""
f([x]++s)=show x++" "++f s
main=putStr(f[1..100])
```

Curry is a language that happens to be both a functional language and a logic language. The logic features allow patterns like `([x]++s)` to be valid.

This crack requires a Curry implementation such as PAKCS or KICS2 that is more full-featured than the one on TIO.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (8cc + ELVM)](https://github.com/shinh/8cc/tree/eir), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155533/71256) by [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)

```
main(X){while(X++<100)putchar(X);}
```

You can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BPTcxM08jQrO6PCMzJ1UjQlvbxtDAQLOgtCQ5I7EIKGFdq65gp@Csl8yln19Qop@aU5arm1mkn5SZp2@RnKygG6ygm6/gil1Bak6mguv//wA) In a shell

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155574/76162) by [TheNumberOne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32700/thenumberone)

```java
/*‮*/ inter\u0066ace S‭{/*//Hello World!‮*/static void main(/**/String[]a‮){for(char b‮=0;b‮++
<10/*‮*/*10;)System\u002e/*‭*/out/*‮*/.print(b‮);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoIwGIR3n6Ju8BP9iwMLuLszOKhDhapFaEkpJIaQ8EL4ULxIpYbpcpfv7grWsZ2quSzyt7UI8/gFJEIarq8tpVHEMk7SeZx6BMQTL0tFzkqX@fZPNoYZkZFOiZxUTEgPATA1Wsjn5cYWxO8fSnvZi2lyX@yRxk6CYJOEdH2DkMZ@@mkMr9zlgbt8AlStWYl9vQwazzX9eBis/QE)

All the commented out [right to left override](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm) characters really mess with the flow of the code. Along with replacing the escaped characters, the actual code looks like:

```java
interface S{static void main(String[]a){for(char b=0;b++
<10*10;)System.out.print(b);}}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Commentator](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Commentator), [posted](/a/155033) by [caird coinheringaahing](/u/66833)

```
print "H e l l o, W o r l d!", end = 10
for i in range( 1 0 0 ):
        print i
;{-Haskell ?-}
#Python?
(({- Execute some# brainflak here#}))
;-}Perl: bvgk,l/;'juhedwsed/*{-:
05AB1E: 12DD/* Way to convert to float, nice :)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxb4MwFAZ3/4qvYShEWEClLEZVlCqRMmbL7MAjuBi/yDhpI8Rvp1Tt3XLTVdz35IIO7Of55o0LWB1BsIuc4gyGX7J@WaUgV@MdRS4a9jAwDl67K8UokC8mSuCfv5ER5SiPeujIWmzlJKLTM7TstiKOR4nDN1X3QBi4pwgXr41rrO7QkqdoShJRyulE3ipcHtcutVn5@nlvqf4aqM7Wo1Qi3@w@ioNC8bbfZ2uc9ROBUbF7kA@/2VjWIYUzFUEl8/wD)

Answer (score 4):

## Fortress, [posted by Zachary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155083/77964)

```
export Executable
run(args) = do
for i<-seq(1#100) do
println(i)
end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

## [???](https://github.com/ararslan/qqq-lang), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155082/12012) by [Unihedron](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21830/unihedron)

```
......";........-,'";'";.;;.---,'"....'"-........;,'".........'";.!--!;,'".........'";;;.--,,,,,,,,,,;..........";!--.!--!;;;,'"--,";,,,,,,,,!,!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY25EQAxCANrgcQJUgOqiv4DzvgLTkPCzgoys4orLp4ghmsOJQK9NR2OK@ggbi4aYH@4yvHyrven6e@OujU11/UszKo@)

Comment: HA! A language called `???` how ironic that he told you the language in the cops thread initially.

Answer (score 4):

## [MiLambda](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MiLambda), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155086/41024) by [Esolanging Fruit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61384/esolanging-fruit)

```
v
E
Ξ
ς
v<
E`A:*[>+.<]
υ^
ε
Ξ
ς
v<
Δ
Θ
>σλ
```

[Online interpreter](http://alc.comuf.com/milambda.php)

I just remembered this language exists, so I searched up for its name. The `[>+.<]` part made it look an awful lot like brainfuck.

Comment: I was relying on no one knowing what this language was...

Comment: @EsolangingFruit Reminder: You're on PPCG.

Answer (score 4):

## [Prelude](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155129/31957) by [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)

```
for{# [1+1];
64+(1-v(1-)++);
100^x; rev!}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyhKzSlNSf3/Py2/qFpZIdpQ2zDWmsvMRFvDULcMiDW1tTWtuQwNDOIqrBWKUssUa///BwA)

I thought the `v` and `^` chain placement looked familiar!

Answer (score 4):

## [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155297) by [nelsontruran](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71883/nelsontruran)

```
i=1
loop,100
 send % i++ . ","
```

I'm not sure if this is valid language defined by OP (free as in beer) since it seems only works on MS Windows.

// Btw, I'm a Dvorak layout user on Windows. That's why I know this language.

Comment: ... because Windows is not free? Does it work in Wine?

Comment: @user202729 I've no idea. never tried.

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155545/61563) by MickyT

```
      +     .  :     +   .        +       .         +     .    v      +           .           +     .            +   .    ^         +  
 .              +   .               +     .                +   .                 +   .        ;          +   .               
    +   .                    +           .                     +         .                      +     .   "           "         +   .    
                    +     .                         +   .                          +     .                           +  
 .                            +       .             @                +   .                              +     .                           
    +         .                                +   .               (       "           +   .                               
   +   .          )                         +   .                                    +   .                                     +   .      
                                +           .                                       +   .                                    
    +   .                                         +   .               ;                           +     .                           (      
          +         .    )                                       +   .                   
                          +     .                                              +   .                                )               +   
  .                   |                             +   .                                                 +   .          
                                        +   .                                                   +   .                                      
              +     .                                                     +   .  ^                                   
          (       +         .                                                       +       .                                         
               +     .                              "                           +       .                                        
                  +   .           :                               :                 +   .                                            
                +       .                (                                             +     .       
                                                ^       +       .                                                               +  
 .                                              |                 +   .                                             (                
    +     .                                    ^|^                              +   .                                                       
            +   .                              |||                     )                 +   .                                 
                                    +     .    AAA                                                                  +     .             
                                               VVV           +       .         "                                                     
          +       .                                                      "                   +     .                                                           
               +     .                          ;                                                 +   .   
                                                                         +     .                                                   
                          +   .                 )                                                             +         .         
                                    )                        1         +   .                          (                                 
                     +       .                                              (                                   +     .            
                                                                      +     .                                                     
 ^                             +     .                                                                 ;                   +     .     
                                                                                +         .    ;                                         
                                         +   .                                                         )                      
        +             .                                                                                        +     .                  
                          "                                             +         .                                          
                                                +   .                                                                                      
     +     .                   ^                                                                         +       .            
                                                                                 +     .                                                      
                                        +   .                                                                              
                 +   .                       ;                                                    ^                     +     .                   
                                                                              +     .                                 
                                                     (            +   .                        )                                     
                                      +     .                                                                                        
            +     .    "                                                                                          d       +   .             
                  )                                                                       +     .             )               
                                                                           +         .                                    )              
                                                      +   .                          )                                          
     (           "                     +       .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVg9a8QwDN31K4Qnm0Kga7I0fyKjoe1xUAodCu2U/57S0LvaiT8kWSEeDs6RpWe9Jyl3L5/Pbx/Xr9f3ZcF1PayfHWJ//9ohhs@CjX9rxO/YJraLLMOtdcOHWxAbbSDkveVMN7tD2RrybgqXS1mknwfITbBr9qCgfDrvPf@0ejxNQPqGsdETEwkNDZBSWg5qdykmgVtjb@ycNO8Cw9ASKLbkJHGRAA93znpoUoLdZWIjC9d4bWhBJ02vSxyC9LlZSVaFU4Da0pGfAwUK4qieF9VSGzpSi5N@HiQCNJoQoE5eX3HRt8sGyPewAkY6ruxvy4uJlc5cSjvgF6UtjFuSJz/7YxrFjhaCo3meST2WigqYShrHEZtXKvlcfU7TVCwZ00pHo@6N1oht65mDeHwBai35tYFbdE4BaAyWlIZs2EdqOVphLoQqtTLa4GxB/ELwh/muFU7oW6880uIbNIpEcVBlRQ6pn2caDHAJBtlbo@DfjTYWVMggYMlXglcX7RFdQquo4URGgBVkkITwzIzBOdTIwloyP05TC1pDhPrS/xfL4GHrks0hSHMpS6M7UI7Mxu1UkFS6huPKwlbn1r3pLssP)

Running `tr -d ' \n:v^;"@()|AV1d'` (i.e. deleting everything except `.` and `+`) gives this:

```
+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.
```

Comment: good job, had intended to put a couple of > and <'s in there to stop brainfuck.  Intended option was [onefuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/OneFuck)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155762/71256) by  [Magic Octopus Urn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59376/magic-octopus-urn)

```
2̵̨̛̆̈̈́̂ͦͣ̅̐͐ͪͬͤͨ̊̊ͭ̑͛̋͏̠̰̦̥̼̟̟̀3̶̵̨̥̜̼̳̞̺̲̹̦͈̻̫͇̯̬̮͖̔̅ͮͭͨͧ̾͑ͣ̑̑̃̄̚͝5̸̸̧͖̼͚̩ͧͦ͋ͭ̐ͤͣ̄̆ͦ2̶̢̻͕̼̹̟̦̮̮͇͕̥̱͙͙̻͔̫̞̈̓̿̎ͦ͑ͩ͐̔̿̓͟͠A̴̺͍̮̠̤̫̙̜̹͎͒͂̌ͣ̊ͤͨ͂͒ͣ̉͌̄ͭ̑͟͠͡͝à̄̍̿̎ͯ̑̀̃̂ͣ̆̂̓̂ͬ̉̉͝҉̹̠̤̻s̏̓̓̃ͮ̌͋̅̎҉͈̝̩̻͡a̵̛̬̩̙͈͍̙͇͖͈͔̝̘̼̤͚ͨͣ̍̇̐ͧͥ̅̊ͥͅs̷̡̝̰̟̲͚̱̦͓͙̖̅̊̉̒̀͡A̢̛͓̜͇̻̦̮̭̣̮̱͎͒ͪ̿̇̓ͫ̍ͯ̀R̵̴̴̸̹̰̪͎̹̗̹̟̱̘͊̋̎̋̅ͫͬ͐̐͌A̸̧̝͍͍͔̣̮̾̓ͣ̓̍́ͬ͝g̨͕̣͎͕̳̟̱̭̲ͭ͛̎͆̔̃́8̶̬͓̱ͧ̄͌́̉́̀͜6̢̡͈̭̟̳̮̦̞͖̘͍̗ͩ̑̎̄̑ͮ̊̉ͯ̓̽͝8̾ͪ̉͊̑͏̤̩͈̤̣͙̭̟̳̮͎̣͈͖̖͕͕̫͠͠5̶̳̲̹̳̣̪͈̝̝̯̩̲̰̭̘̭̗ͮ́ͯ̐ͧ͑͛̇̂ͩ̓ͫͦ̔̽͐ͯ̅ͦ̕͠͠͡6̴̪͇̣͙̦͖̝̠̤̻̩̰̣͉̰̯̟͕ͯͩͮ̋̒̍ͦ̎̇ͦͮͣ̉̃͗8̷ͨͬͫ̌̀̅͊͐̇͐̚͝҉̰͔̫̤̱̦̯̟̼̝̼̣̀͡6̸̫͔̜̾̓̒̚ͅ7̀ͮ̄̊ͧ͐͗͑̾̊ͨ̚̕͞҉̣̮͙̝͔̻̯̫̥͔8̶̮̭̭̪̯͖̯̭͖̆ͣ̊ͩ̊ͨͧ͗̋̐ͧͫ̅́͘ͅ
̨̛̝̬̠̯̗͓̦ͦ̀͂̐͛̆ͬ̏̀ͣͭ͊̒͌͝3̶̧̡͇̤̩̘̦͍̜ͦͣ̋̚5̶̴̨̥̩̭̩̰̀̌̽͒̃̋ͭ́͛͠1͕̺̺̩͖̾̃̾̈̑͂ͣ̉́́́̚2͇̻͙̖̮̖̩͓͚̣̞̯̦̱̤̝͍̩̔ͪͦ̾͆͐͐͒͗ͧͦ̿͗́̓͜ͅ5ͣ̒͂̆ͦͥ̑̕҉҉̜͈̮̳̟̺̤̥̰̹̮̺̣̻̞͕̟1̢̛̃̉̔̽̊ͣͮ͋ͪ͗̆ͪͦ̐̇͑ͧ̚͘҉̛̫͕̙͕2̸̣̫̳͍͎̼̤͚̱̲͓͌̀͗̈́̓̈́̂̄ͪ̉̄̄̉̋͗ͩ̅̆͢͞͝4̴̢̺͙̺̞͕̻̥͍͆̿̄̐͒͗̈́ͫ̑ͫ̇͐͠͠ͅ2̸̛͕̩͕ͣͫ̒́6̴̵̢̘̫̟͖͙̲̲̮̣̘͈͉͖͓̮͖̊́ͬ̆̎͒ͩ̏ͨͥͧ̿̆̄͐́̏T̛͕̟̫̮̊̇̾ͦ̋̋̎̆̄͗̕͝n̴̡̤̞̣̦̱̻̰̟̻͈͈̠͇̣ͮͭ̐̎ͭ͋͛͌ͩ͡L̎ͮ̐͑ͫ̃ͪ̌͆̂̂ͯ̕̕͏̢̢͚̥̰̹̫͍̠̼̩̟̲,̨̨̘̱͚̗̖̺͓̘̼͍̘͚̹ͫ̂̏̈́ͥͬͥ̃̅͐̐͞q̨͍͕̠͍͖͇̠͉̮̭̦̜̣̼̜̩̠̓̊̀̈́̊͆̀̎̌͋̅̐͊͘͘͟͡ͅe̵̶̡̛͎̱͕͉̞̳͗ͭ̇ͪ͋̓̚͡r̨͚̘̖̝̫̳͂̈́ͣ͂ͧ͒̎ͧ̍͆̏ͪ̓ͥ̇̾̏͘ļ̴̴̝͉̪͎̊͂̾̑ͬ̐͡2̷ͯ̓̓͂̈͠҉̦̤̹̻͚̠̘̘͓̫̤͚̣̬̙͉͙̜3̸̮̝̮̰̘̰̇̿ͫͪ̑̈́ͦ̇̿̏̿ͥ͞͡5̶̲͔̣̞͚͇͒ͨ̂ͪ́̓̐̅͊͋̎͋̅́ͨ̿͟͞jͯ͂͋̉ͯͣ̃͊ͫ̋͊̊ͪͭ͏̸͠҉̝̣̬̥̻͉̖̮̫̘̤͕̭ͅģ̵͖̯̠͉̟̬̗͎͈͍̪̙̲̙͓̳͂͑̏̉͐͊ͩ̽͗̍͜͡ͅr̴̵̡̓̓̂̕͏̰̟̩̪g̶̡̢̠̲̱͚̋͊͆̂̔̑̕͜
̂͐ͥ̇҉̬͇̥̪͝ͅ2̴̸̷̞͕̦͚̪̩̺͇̭͖̪̫ͮ̈̃ͭ̓̾̓͂͑͊ͭ́̔̍ͭ3̶̸̼̤̩̣̤̆ͤ͊̂͆͘ͅ4̋̐̍̅̐̓͂̽͊ͥ̒͆ͮ̌ͫͧ͘͟͡͠͏̠̬͚̬͕̤͇̤̣͖͇̠̰͚͙̘͎͕̥6̓̄ͥ̂ͦ̽͌͋̍̓̄̈́͑̋̎ͧ͂͘͜͝͠҉͕̼͕̮͔3͎̤͖̦̟̱̟͍̺̞̜̞̳̳̯̾͛̓̇̾̒ͫͮ͌ͩ̄̓̔̔̓ͯ̐̀̀́͘͠2̷̡̰͚͙͙̤͎̺̜̳͍̩̋̍ͫ̔ͦ̉́̎ͣ͒̈͑̽́͢͞ͅͅ6̨̯͇̼͚͇͉͈̼̩̮͍̣̖ͭ̎ͯ͑̓͆͋͑ͅ3̳͉̥̰̖͓͇̞̩̳̩͙̜͇̗̼͖ͩ͑ͫ͛͊̋̈͌̋ͯ̔͛̀͛͟͞ͅ2̆̃ͥ̓ͪ̍ͯͨ͜͝͝͏̗͍͚͕͔̝̟͚̦6̭̤͕̰̙̼͌̎̇̓̽ͤ͌ͫ̀͠ḫ̷̢͔̪͈̠͖̪̹̮̣̩͊̽̿ͭ͋̂̊̂͝e̶͕͔͍̙̟̟̱̤͓̯̪̮̠͉̖ͧͩ̋̂ͤͦͭ̽̎͗̅͊̅̽̅̀͜͞r͊̀̍ͨ̀̍̓ͤ͗ͨ̊̅͊̿̚҉̴̪͖̝̙̭̖̹͔̻̦̖̳͔5͚̻͕̪͓̹̼̎ͥ̍̈̓̇ͬ̊ͧ̏̾͑̚͘͝2̶̸̖͙̟͉̜̤͔̦͍̖͖̝͖̳̝ͦͬ̅͒ͭ͆͊́3̴̻̺̮̞̖͛̌̇ͨ̆͒̊͛ͯ͐̇6̭͙͇͇̘̭̫͖̣̲̬͕͔̜̰̽̒ͮ͑̒ͩͨ̎̒̃͛ͦͥͭ̏̇́ͅ5̴̷̙̠̙̝̭̼̥̝̼̞͉̱̟̰̠̖͚͓̑͂̿͗͑ͭͬ̒ͣ̅̓̏ͥ̅̚͜ͅ2̷̾͛̈́ͯͭ̿̏̇̒͛ͧ̀͝҉̡̯̦̜͔̱̰͓͍̲̣̳3̢̡̈́͆ͯ̚͢͜͏̖͓͖̥̻̗̭͉̤̗̗2̸̸̨͎͉̥͚̜̗̩̰̮͙̟̳ͥ̑̉̊ͤͧ͑̊̕2̃͊̓͒̂͐̏ͭ͑̅͂͂ͤ̚҉͙͈̞͖̪͓̹̰͕̹̮̰̼͎̦̪͜2̸̿͆͊́̔́҉̧̙͇͚͍̗̝̤͚̝̻̣͉̳̹͟2̡̛̗͖̟͔̳̹̭͇͕̼͉͓̙̑̌̆͑̔̒̎
̇̈́ͯͫͫ͐̎͒͆̎̌͐̾ͧ̈́͐ͭ̆҉̬̯̳̮͖͚̭̼̱̳̪͉̥̪̞̱̘̹̖̀3̢̡̡̟̰͙͉̪̰̱̱͕̟̼͚̟̭͉͔̌ͭ͗ͨͮ̀̂́͂ͯ̔̿̈̉͜͜4̴̢͚̫͉ͥͭ͛̿́̽͛̄͐͝6̡̾͐̿̄͌̒́͜҉̶̯̩̟̼̯̰̙̝̟͕̬̳̳͖̹̱2̨̤̝̮̞̺̟̪̠̱̺̱̠̹͉͍̺̩̈ͯͬ͘͟͜ͅ3͗ͨ̅̋̆͆͌̾ͪͪ͛͆̐ͣ҉́҉̱̖̫͍̣̤̬̱̬̠̫̠̻͔̞̰6̶̢̖͕̻̾̅̔ͧͧ̇̑͗̂͊̿̓̐̍̂ͪͪ͟3̈ͨͤ͐̅̏̋ͬ̄͊̅̀ͦͭ̇ͤͩ̇̈҉͓͚̮̲̣͕͙̣͙̮̖̫̟4̵̧͙̠̱̟͐͗ͦ̓̍̎̾̈̽̆̈̈ͥ̾͗ͫ̐͠2̴͕̳̗͈̟̲͖̝̙̼̭̲̳̹̬̈́̎͂̅̆͌̇ͣ̑̏͜͞6̋͋̀͛̓ͭ̿̊͂̍ͤ̃̎̓̃̌̏҉͎̰̬̟̲͙̼̪̯͍͕̭̦4̸̢͔̱͔̖̝̪̙̼̻͍̗̟̳͔̱͑̈͒ͤͬͅ2͖̯̫̂́ͧ͆͛̄̆ͦͨͧ̅͘͢ͅ3͚̟̱̖̖̯̳̰͎͓͍̮̝͍͊͗̒́̀͞4̨̨͓͔̲̝͎̣͇̲̹ͨͨͯ͂̈ͤ̈́̈́̇̈́̀͟͠6̡̛͍̤̩͖̰̙͇͖̀̇͐̊̆̽̏̍͢͢gͨͩ̆ͮ̈ͩ̍ͩ̑̀̎̌ͭ͏̵̝̯͎̜̭̟s͉̥̥̣̗͍̭̩͍̮͉͓̲͕͍̱̗̮̟ͩ̑͋̓̂ͭͤ̉̕͞ť͍̩͚̹̠̥̥̳̩̻̦̬̤͓̞͓̄̄͒ͫ̀̽́̎ͥ̍̌̚͘͡3̷̬̝̘͍͊ͯ̈́ͮ̀̋̓ͩͧ͂̆͐̂ͤ̓ͮ̚̕͜6̷̘̖̻̤̟̗̦̼͎͕̳̥̫̘̲̥́̄̊ͪ͂̈́͐͛̓́̚̕4̶̷̛͕͇͎̲̺̤̯͈̱̹͉̮̭̳̗̤ͣ̏ͣ̾̀͠3͖̟̳͓̲͓̫̝̗̟̮̺̮̭͈̿ͬͫͣ͐̾͗ͧ̓̌̅͛́͘͟͡2̛̹͓̫̫̮̺̙̟͙̳̤̺̠̞̩̠̞͙ͩͪ̀ͬͪ͌͗̽ͣ̈́͜ͅ6̴̳̪̩͉̳͓̞̘̙̦̏ͭ̃͊ͭ͑̀̚
̵̙̝̘̝̲̳͖̣̝͕̥͍̥͖̗̹͉̎̽ͥ̑̾̎͢ͅḧ̶̵͇̭͍̠̣̗͖͍̜͕̰̘̰̑̃̀͒̈́ͤ̏̓ͩͬ̐͐̑̽ͯ̚̕͠͠4̫̬̦̜͕̺̱̖̼͋̄ͨ̾̔ͤ̓͊̐ͧ̔ͤ̎̄̀̏́͢ͅe̶̡ͯ̓ͮͤ̏ͦͬ͗̈́̽ͯ̌̽͌͆͊ͭ҉̡̝̺̜̝̗̗5̢̳͔̯͍̰̗̻͖͎̜͕̺̙͙͙̬͂͐̽͗͝ͅẆ̵̤̣̠͉̩̳̗͈̆̃̀̈́̋́̉̒ͯͭͥ͒̀ͭͦ́̓͗͘ͅR̴̍ͩ̓ͮ́̿ͨ̇̊̾̃̄̌̍͞҉̖̻̹̙̯́D̸̨̛̝̹̮͇̣̿ͧ͌̍̚ͅ3̨̛̛̫̫̣̝͈͔̰̖͕̮͉͔͖̈́ͨ̉̌̇́̃̍ͧ̈̈͐ͨ͛̚2͎̟̱̪̖͈͕͔͓̘͉̙̍̃̓ͪͦ͋͆̃̈̄̂̄ͦͥ̍̏̃̀͢͢͟5̸̶͛̀̿̄ͦ͊̏҉̷̼͇͍͚̘̺̱̜̤̻̞̲̜̰͙͔yͨ͐̍ͪ̑̀̾̌̊ͤ̿͗̄͑͐̑͌͋̽̕͏̰͔̮͈̦̤̫̗̫̯w̵̧̗̣̙̠̬̺̩͚̬̎́ͭ̃͛̈́2̴͚̫̮͍̼̠̺̠͕̬̳̮͕̱̟̙̘̹̑ͮͧ͗̓̎́́ͯ̓̐̉ͮͫͪ͢2̥̯͚̼͉̦͙ͧ͌͛̒̃ͯͭͥ͋̚̕̕͜͡ͅ2͇̖̭͆̒ͪ̾̎ͥͣ̂ͨͩ͋͒ͪ͊́̚͠͠2̑͗ͬ̃͆͂̓͗̏ͯ͟҉̴͘҉̳̭̗̘̤̝ͅ3̴̵̲̗̘̹̠̰̳͙̮͙̍̉̓ͦ̐ͧ̾̍̚̚̚̕ͅ4̨̲̜̱̦͓̝͍̳͕̩͌̔ͪ̾͗̉̇͗͐͛͆̀ͅͅ2̵̱̦̬̜͓̻̥̲͓̀͐ͫ͟͝6͔̮̣̮ͩͨ̀ͭͯ̏ͣ͂͡5̷͕̠̭̜͕͙̦̘̦̱̖̬ͤ̌ͫ̈̅͒̇ͯ͢
̸̵̵̡̛͓̻̗̖̻̗̼̤̰̂͛̆͌͗ͯͭ̂ͥ̈̂ͤͪ͐3̤̘̫͉̘̗̜̲̝͇̙̫̯̲̥͙̦͐̈̇̏͊̓̇̈́ͫ́͘͡ͅ2̛̣͓̪̖͔̺͍̝̫̳̱͊ͦ̿ͨ͌̀6̗̪̠̻̤̤͓̜̫͈͓̐͂̎͗̆͗̂͋͋̊̈́̃́3̰͈̠͚̙͉̲̗̭̤̝͇̩͔͖̦͓̹̯̉̊ͩͧ͐̃ͦ̾̀͘͟͢2̵̧̡̧̻̟̰̻̰̪͔͔̲̮͚̝̖̹̣̞̠̍̿̄͆͌́ͤ̀̅6̴̜̩̝̯͌͊̿ͫ̆̕͘5̵̡͓͍̬͔̒̍ͩ̅̎̍ͩ̉̈́ͫ͐͊̓̄͊̒͠͞ụ̡̜̥͙̗̻̺̤͇̥̦̗̠̪̳̗̼ͤ̈̓̾̆ͥ̅ͥ̿̿̒̇̓͟n̵̑͂̎ͪ́̾̃ͨ͗͛́́̚̚҉̶͙̰͓̱̳̯͓̟̺̤͈̥ͅn͒̿̏̆͏̳̯͍͎̫͇̮̳̼͎͚̜͓̦̝͜͟͡5ͨ̃͐ͬ̔̉͜҉̨̯̥̗͕̪̙̭͚̳͚͇͎̭̪͙̣̺́e̶̡̧͈̬̻̼̮͕̯͈̖͚͙̬̗͕̲ͬ̾̾̓̔͑͊ͨ͂ͪ̅͋̀ͪ̂̑̚͟ͅb̸̧͉̝̜̗͉̫͕͎͓͖̙̱ͩ͌ͪ͒̊̓ͦ͂̎͗ͨ̀̀ͮ͊̿͐͜y̅ͦͮ̽́ͥ͆ͫ̊ͩͪ̿ͩͭ͋͟҉̶̧̰̦̳̥̬̼̩̟̹͖͕̟̞͈͓̰̠͈ͅ3̷͕̮̤̩̳̙̳̮̹͕͇̱͖͖̋ͦͩͧ̃͊́ͩ̽̉̓̌̋́͟͝2̴̗̯͉̦̪̯̠͙̩̩̦̝̪̯̘̈ͨ̏́ͅ4̧̡̣̮̖͚̫̙̿̃ͫͫ̊̍̄̀̓̔̏͒ͦ́ͅͅ6̷̼̳͇̱̖̙̯̲̤͈̼͍̤̰̬̺̺͕ͭ̂͗̇̆̿͋ͥ͛̏ͫ̀ͣͧ̏̈́͞ͅ2̨̰̺̬̮̤̬̬̰̄̇̔̽ͫ͛͗̓ͯ̌ͫ̑̈́͘ͅ3͍͈͇͔̯͍͓͙̺̮͈̖͍̮̟̗̝̝͂ͫ̃ͤ̏͐̌́́́ͩ̀͘͡ͅ6̺̞̦̻͕̪̫̹̩͓ͫ͌̋̃͋̀̕͡͝ͅ3̏̈́ͧͬ̈́́̊̈̿ͯ̑̆̇̊̽̌͐́҉҉̡̨̪͉̖̖͇̯͉̥4̴̧̰͈̭̼̗̹̻͕͉͈̱̜̺̳̘̣̠̼̹̓ͩͮ̾̎̅̂̉̾̐͑̿͋͆̋͐̏͘
̴̢̭̰͚͎̦̟̜̫̟̰ͣͦ́͗̓̄̒͘͟3̢͙̹͍̹͖͈̙͚̱̰̝͙̗̙̹̗͖̺̟ͦ̑́̒̆̊̐̀͠͠4ͬͪͤ̏́҉͡͏̦͚̮͚̖̩̖̞̱̹̥̫̥͉6̡̡̛̜̮̭̞̰͗̾ͧ̇̃ͩ́͊͘͞3̜̘̘̤̬͚̫͉̹͖̘̰̩͇̖̳̺͇͙̆͐̈ͤͥ́ͬͩ͌̂̌̂͗͗͒̆̔̀͟͡͡2ͨͦͥ̓ͪ̎͏̵̵͈̯̩̼̬̦4̭̼͚͕̪̤̱̹̞̩̤̬̞͇̭͔͔̰̰͋̎͑ͫ͌̐̑͑̿̄ͯ́͡6̉̋́̾̌̍̒͌ͮ̕҉̯̘͙̳̲͙͍̞v̨̢͊ͦ̀҉̧̺̳͚̫̟͚͍̘̼̹̳̘̱̥͙͕͍͍̀w̵̨̳̭̖̘̮̩͔̘̱̭͍̰̗ͤ̇͊ͣ͂̆̋͢͠t̪̯̹̯̩̝̝̪͖̯ͭ̒̍̔ͤ̈̈̿̍̌̆ͮ͌ͯͮ͜͞ͅͅͅj̦̳̫̙̫̝͇̟̩͉͇̲̻̙̼ͬͯ̾̀ͫͦ̾̑̇̔ͪ͜͡r̴ͧ̈͗͋̑ͩ̾̽ͧ̌͌̉̋͛͗̔̔ͦ͏͇̦̥̝̮̳̦̺͕̫̹͍͔̞͝ͅͅͅw̴̛̖̙̻̞̭̼̘̹̼̫̲͕͓̗̘̹̋̏̅͊̎͋̉̾ͅt̡̧̳͇͚̲̮̻̣̺̝ͧ̏͂̅ͤ̕͝ả̗̜̯̻̗̝̜̼̪͕͓̭͍͂̇̐ͦͨ͌̽́́͝ͅ3̶͉͕̹̥̟̺̘͍̗̾̂ͫ̌ͯ̿̋̇͛ͪ̾ͭ͒͛̄̂̓̚͜͞7ͧ̒͂͊̆̽̓͏̵̢҉̞̭͖̼͙͎͚̟͉̻̹̙͉̣͎͍̪4̇ͫͧ̃́̾̎͛͆̿̈́ͭͪ͑ͭͤ̚҉̨͚̙̝̺̯̪͕̬͇̠͖̘̞̬̩̣̲͜͡͝5̵͓̘̝̻̺̺͈̟̯̟̬̲̘̠̜̥̻̦̬̓̋ͪͪͦͫ̚͘6̵̧̺̟͈̜̱͚̜̱̪̯͖̞͙̳̲͍̃͊ͫ͊̽̒̐͢͝8̶̷͔̦̹͙̔̂͐̈̆́̆ͤͪ̽̇̆͜͞5̸̴͉͈̺̮̥͇͍͕̦̗̏̂̐͒ͦ̃̌͌ͧͨͮ̆́͘͢7̹̤̪̺͕ͮͫ͊ͤͣ͛̉́͢3̷̨͍͓̱̼͓̥̘̼͔͎̲̗͈͕͖̭̽̑ͧ̃̏ͤ̊̂
̵̲̖̪̜̫̱̫̻̜̫̞ͭ͆̈́ͯ̋̆̓̀5̢̢̱̺̞͇̭̩͇̹̙̰̰̳̰̫͓̮̙͈̘͒ͮ̄̎͛̓͊̌ͩ̚͢͝4̷̩̱͈͓̺̘̓̉͐̑͗̉ͩ̆͊̂̒̑̈͑̑͌ͤͥ͘͘̕͝6̡̫̭͍̤̝͔̯̟̗̬̣͈͉͇̜͐ͯ͆̌3̸̷̨̦͚̱̭͈̖̖̈́́̎͛̒͌̽ͫ͢͠4̵̏̐̄̍ͦͭ͒̒҉̢̠̯͕̱͢͡ͅ6̨̯͖͎̮͖͈̩̤̺͚̥͚͈̰͔̭ͫ͆̽̀̿͡7̱̩̹̟̖̭̗̤̮̦̭͕̳͒̑ͫ̊̉̄̇ͥ̈́̽̊͆͝v̷̴̛̟̮̳͈̘̰̿͂ͤ̀̄̀ͤ̍͊ͯ͗́ͨͭ̊̏s̗̬̜̥̟̬̅ͬͣ̇̐̒ͭ̇́̓̍̅̀̕ķ̷̺͈̬̺̠̩̣̭̗͈̪͆ͩ͑ͦ͗̈ͧͧ́̚͡͡h̴̢̧̛͍͍̗̻̘̮͍̀̽̾̓̏ͅb̨̳̜̘͕͛̀ͫͦ͐ͮ͛́͛̏̇̀̕r̛͔̦̼̀̔ͮ͛͋ͪͧ̃͛̂͛̂̉̐́̚̕4̢̡̻͚̮̹̹̙͖̙͓͚̮̘̟̼̝̮̂̇͛̃̈ͮͧ̊̎̿̽ͯͥ́͟͠͝5̨̨͎̪̮͎͖̩̙̫̤̫̹̟̩̮ͨͭ͋ͯ͋ͮͯ̋ͪ̑̄ͧͭ̆ͤ̈́ͭͩ̚̕͠3ͤͭ̎͆̽͒̈́̌̈̽̍̓̏҉̫͓̗̩̺͕̬̼̦̘̦͎7̨͎̮̯̼̙̜̪͕̭̺̞̯͚ͫͤ̆̋͑ͮ̉̅̇͐ͫ̀3͊̀͆̈́ͩ̊͛̍́ͣͤ̓ͬ̿ͨ̓͑͗͗͘̕҉͉̗̥̮ͅ4̴̴̢͈̦̤̼͎̼͍͔̝̳ͣ̾́͑͗̒̎̐ͤ̀ͯ̋̚̕͝7̡̡̛̻̩̺͉͆ͦ͗̒ͦ̽͒͊̉͌͌̌̏̇́4̨͛ͩ̍̽̋̉ͪ̅͛̄͐̈ͩ̄̚̕҉̻̘͔͕̤̬̗̹̟̫3͈̥̘̼͙̤̖̬̺̥̠̜̖̯̦̐ͪͮ̈́̐͗ͤ̔ͯ̈́̐͊̚͟͡ͅ5̢̘̭̬̺͚͔̱͓͇̘͙̗̫̮͙̲̜̃͂̈́̏ͥ̐̇̐̈̇͆͂ͅ6̵̷̛͍͇̥̺̼̻̺̥̦͕̆ͧ͐̓͐̏ͦ͌̾ͫͭ́ͫͦ͆͛̍̕͝
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZpJb2vXcoXn/i0ZxOqupw/IMKOHABnbgGHjJTAQ@@UZb8ZepCRSFHtSJEVJbMReEq@kq/4P7D3xH3K@tXQDgaQknrN3NauqVtU@/7r7/Q/f/vjnn1shF/IxE1JxHC9DNpRjOc7iIg7jVTgIB3EZTuJpOAxX4TTcxeOYCINwHcZhFF7CWTjbDrWQjau4jFdxEt7iSeiwzAk/6ZAJ9@Eq9sIdF3e5fBP64SnchscwjvnwHOZxP6zDIqxiYzdO2P@Q3crsfMmtuTgOk/AlfImN8BI7YbqFmOnwHkpceBKnsczO76EaLuJZHLDTc6yzxyNCjcOKNff5exRuYju2@a4W5qH/l1iJqXDE@gfSL6b4@zIU4lHISM/wOQ7ieezFs/AUiywyCENuayP8Yyx9HxKIVbQEay5OoGGK23O867dFKLBU748CMujG59/CcajyVTqu2PMQ25b@KLB@PvTCNDx/jwCXrLePypM44usD3jEyFpmGdswjQhstGvxW45YW2g1jNnZ@06VsVmGtRHgI53x5jdq3WOkG01ZRuCFVZ8i6H9NxHopxzaWn2Koaulj92TZahkveb2Lpr/EAD5d4ZeMc35cR6QhBPvPzBXWuwyyW@GzavDeh9Rc8nUb6KvIn0fxLmODnXizyU9OqPwGIUwyVw0npmAQG9XAZS7xvvMIy3H4HXjJsk8RqXS65R8IF8t3sxSnmLWHsEyyHppi7Gl4RvhdkvSUrbBB8HPpgo4WZmt8hz4wLD7jlGCfK/lMuHbJp@/9vQIVLbNkIjVhHkPkuqydZW@YXxvdx4lTmAnm18EocrLHHONQFLyGDRQTeDQrO7MUe8J3yv2u2aPFq7mHnKcsehgo2H6PEPmhdCWSYoYk5Z1hfMo2Ro/eBE5a45n8F3tfhLNa/AxgLnHYExDpIcIA/9nk9CFwxgRzXhvNQ3tYtAKPH63JPXmHnDv6Yc0k3Zj@FBOJ0sOUBWpZjkwB94/er2A91oIqrEKbHxc@sNA@jWPuO0FOATH3ZBKkPbaI5sLuPydgScmIWdWdhjRZr/mp8g7IJYquMHXMA4pi/LsHAASg9AnhKAz2APeDyJk4ebzvdHCLaBADfYxU8hhHHuLO7i@ZHeKBCiCknJFn1Sj7AgCMuW8pk36JImlcn5PF6yoGc9E@dLPOE/xtboUYuG2OWXFReq6A/eSa8o1SS2HQoKFpQqcENVSLokiS1xq43CjZBOkx3WVuJg5REhJ7IcJiuCwRWhvMTso/w3iN/P7HAM8Csh7NvEa8Akjpg9wBrrMhvM3bOWSb59IQQUFC2WO4Ul9UJ@PoWBksgaAYokpaJEZCNAzO8H/L/KX7IxYvYx6Rf2G0eNkRdydlBCeA2VneIu3du@NA4g@tOeIEhWZDXBfmtjaiIiY7PeL24hYBztEyy5imCTGN9j9hTcOeI4wrbHgOHERK/858MeEzi5c@sdYfb5gC3wZq3/KwQqkWgFfhPVcn9P1hoHyeM8bfSjG5vIv1pUByecfPqF5UQbFICM4fxNB6x32eQfo5p@6wnfzw7yz2zcj4MFEb/zuUrlJRyaax0hNopgngd6qx8jGgXWOTDM3McOcBGUyXKf@GGFPpk0GeBS9NEGTkvKCqu0OaG25og4gn5Sbvc2uI/j/9DdB3gGwVTDoiWvqb1MiHaogq1WOAcX9QRr4jy@xh3QFwr044pIpfs30WCwY@goIO@@yDhkNx2R14jCDB8ib3r3NIPm1/BdAavpIBsBU0nZJQcQs8A7kj2xPxXUYK1gnIJOPhvBEvxxQleK7PixBm8x3rk7y1yU5qfFHV0EB6A3BjjPmLQDpZpoWJVScUhsACIBdzZ3WajdzLijDUzOJC/2PYdu/WpzOeo1uN1ze3Xu4DkCuvPFFoYU4kLb9tCSb55p6zec9utK0Q/duL@3xApxQVkeEIszQ1zIC7WMQMHJPLwBTF7FmiEoAVFKkads98QMy9/4vYTBCpE@WBKymhipfPYxaQT5ybZ/4zbmxQfVdRZEEjbhHoWEyNoFSScY6W62I0RNg2znySG0VRD8S4XXOAe/Mq9gOMb1CzLCeRjshpYHGHh7BZozKPGEpyoPiJbFIFKskqRTxXTB@eGMVaesdETt5I9@X2@TVAP0T3FtvfY9mu556LLMNxRDqbWCmvy4GsUV6iQ1kQt5iDk3AgcoMIAgTq86ty@7woIEkXasHgbL6sIj/YQEfSL9bGYYFzEEhl8fKIQZcEUPGhAhiQ3iVjxWsXaNnqdcqHQV2HflQOVTIWGNSRTMU3wM0CaJGAeotvYBf8M25NwwD/Q5me9xT5F/F1DggImKgH1CtA8IVs@cHOfmLj4EBqxhyz2xM0bCFBRVtnDnvAwLq9ihUM@r6hGirgXIQv05h3tK/a9DI1tyjJpgswippMnxR4ibA1lEvyvDzQ3AEWpgpyFufq2/IY02DZharJsQ1Q5jdGqYFyMiqKGgXrYvIlQHQJXPO0M64/32IHiL96CV@UijEIaEGqvgeDLzwjySkyQ7kCZ3N4DGxcyssnFwKh4dDKd/og/psidYq0xir@ielMBBiBe@UwAUUJLAog0ipe7flUJgJl4rCLnVy5PIPeV39NxSApqmuRroXcCTexEmUSMqQHlrZknNjBNbZcdR2Akb@d3yC/wCQIPwo@re6gs@j1jx8fwsoWQC1atoF2Ote9dVVQezhCki2A11/mGduO1Cb1tPHFEPrwiCiqsfYp5qZCI9IzfV4CmsYeqFRB3wvuUC0swnTQXUpMxyTE3J4klMeYsDhMdm7P2JRG7sGe6pCgRBVV/pF4ioti/GFaatCoC/hk7PqD@gFePBV5ABMwKLPQRHBDjuwFid2J1S5FAuKzZWylxn8VOcVNCfsSW5yYRXfa9AcRVtL1Fls02xaODUdYU8C7uPgc8QlxD@Q2ULdlnyGdzy0yj4EYFeoqX6iBc7VBJQMXgXS4TcxSBA75bzp9pVq8oO6HRktuyxDGo@UMUm5bCjPnDS9f469G5@4XYGofZFoaRt8hW8he3nFFAZM@OKDaGUG3oIaa46iY8biHgEf46IfgpUKh8SiA0cHJNX6PLvjNHgf3a3@AfWWvOT9mEIuf6WcaOE74pY8ec6C25em22jpntghv@mjk4Z8CA5oOlG9vcuhR8SYAJAigZVfbVEOYxmuza9QuPoTf1Dz1vVFvFlln4TJaOtR1hB@i9o/Urn6I1ajM@c8k8FkSoy2JSRHNF68Ukrr036xfrXjuWFfJ1xCatof1juFGnugZeV@IECDF0kVTve4YgAwR54jUgwrIIobw43XYoZonxHE44UjvDzylGKsdLzKJ9bwjFudPZkN1uzKbnvNTc9sM1wrJADWtOQOMJCSKluAYSqhwpL0gFxjj0P@F5GyGvABeFGvgeIm7G@SThDLPPN1OWybO3WPFK8CWM2m5exJZhfDtuKMbuAkvsnidCc7znwe4b38yDCKcqcdtan22B/hIRKAKraNeg4Ji81cXg6gybIFR97EcSelGXaCQt9hDwUKma3Kt4E80pksHSLEeDDQyPEbSEOxZeQDerOxEXg3vtgNE8kBu6Vb1QUJIps6ZNM@/0bIirCtTkPwFqgiNOPwYRnm1kCdkWqMyqUdom1ppggjpFyHecb2ksDd1rQrTq@QHdww73XonmIMAQnGccBwmwMTA@qmx4y4XqTffVXu6BZ3V7B5jyFc8UqYJEFpsX3dQ2hDmNBX5i3WkQA8jzWXTT/MFJoU5YneaUVbvqfn/Tl2aaKb4cEiH12HdIjUATxUsdlSR2rN7i5yL6NNHg7O8kyCN1H5hvzvqvLtUqBUfmHLRHosb4V4ttNNggmSxcfPqxKjutUVhRekjRmYpZIHRZtYxcpdlInXrf5Zaeevk91v9oV2fmv2XzjQcETprnPmOEM0QbK20ZNCPTwdsw2gFPx7zeMO89aw7UyGCpEl@qRVuDrhuC7oOQg7Yw3CY@aLWhHmUjdsJeR3j6VH0u3jlXOgMUMorYcc8gWbkkLWN@C31mwHKBsEfg4ZXd8x5mnLKPbpj7YhW@NjsO@X1ArE71TvC395Sm0Vepm3SN4J@V7bBpwbv20awdxt/g1lcXhDd@uwMRbQ@EeooPF7meSB3OGPFXUzrG7M/qi4mNBJ7LYOxjdOsgsFqDMt@8kjDvWUzTkrp5qDokwaGhHtxEBVq/A24y5KY3UsuQ8DvQMMC/a0KTQIEk8swJi4ULXt3JrRFeftTYhnrNzuIDakS955EJZ87M@D6cu1b2TO5k3eZuVPUSkVci3jhOCWSEaRKlDUHae7TNCxf/SZLKWcsMyTPpsRg1mbxe4X9LslMSkDWh03fiwqZCU9FIJZu/OmyqmgMBhCuWOvBQIYOQRXJSX5nXoHvE4ut/46JJ1Fcd1@JTzJ5VEVUzSmVnhYJYDF8nWaWInZQMywTqqeenp0aEvKWR3rUTsWKuJm5Z5JaqRgOwWWmUDx/d/9jRdgxGLkg1mnaWnG5mQZNBUT6aVLRq74rNulqN8dIxAt5j3AcCZV/0FGfKM12PnGjDRIiwYe2fiEeFUIvH7W8oAOfwiIRmQEhxe/DqjlqDpxVhNPZgtMlr/Ts4SOJKUbGMkj3/vjSHWngIQyuypUGeJknkai720E0dYoH/0loCH9dbc/UXbiRIvhbUFZ@iXW1V/S0ZHx1F@@xi4HzoVl@VfgRKOmIbUEsiawsbagL6pmxlmpdSvsS2/BfsJYV7/NYIS4nXJCzSgDIlsADYdTwTIfZkZuNxV1M9J0SVlTr4o4CvNMTpaOotsKiBxKhcZkxoSL5RqYztHSBTkyisXCC3N5XU2IsiYC98zGw/Zk0bj16yW2C3TL698zD6xhm1i5@fUZNMtGcCLHivlfGQ@lyO0TRvF9/RboAe@DebrUmEF5pIkPK6LuBjTdkcogv1sZrXkbtMZFPYNO8uY4bjv6DQnWtP1dy04Xe60nC9zdd5gH4M0KquaHNnTI1rWmJOvDdRTZVtH@@BE@TOkp7YfwvzawZ3pckgVrhkfYG55qm7BxnhZo80k3KbkzOTUf0/AGAaJjfNolQJVGW67Jen0pgsq76UuUgzvzMX7ASgVTvV0UjDDlrKj4g1VdzJ9rhrveXJfsbkK4kNE5CUidWfsJOI/7PH4DXX65WZsMiexoUDuj1TrTmpqC7UeMxDAd71HFgTu5I/C7ZU2VbLeDg6YIc7irEIwyLW/petdczxhtp0JLze@al4jH/GpZesLCM23RcNPXkY89cAk6iivfziFqfkKYxSWQczN3EyKQnL3Ym@cvs1IVI1s17z6QkmRhr9AmTUzOTisWJKXbFJVMlHNRp2quh2DMVx6O0CwjTaLCDeNBisfcUea0RqqhlUH8nFG/fjJc2LRR/D04/c8OZRdQ3xNCLRScwMbUXxZiS9E4SUthMcq7ryDOqUClTBGx5jLLzF7Q84/Aiw0jIqHj8Q4w43QW6RS4AxyWESNUaiY@JzThSU3HK1w80/NeEn/0NrSBM5PHjgmv7OuyaRygITypROvEQ1Fl9HiI@x4dnpGXUc8KkvjPltKM5YEFQ9Z8EpyxbMKFSZHhTLSviedG9C24cYj6Io0NGGSgCMXPWUZNJEVw3oZqabAzSe8jM2X12H1g5u0kEF4oJbleEqxjwmt425XRP1S25c2Vgal7X3HN1NF8t39BoBiWMROrLHxJPQvioFztp3amgrYA0KTT81h7p2Pn@K9S322/cBicYpTey@dsYRxW4ZAddcuJCedt5C6SLlEa2oQDnoyCdp8ySUMsBXHoDUjLSq59Ir@1kMWlRPRba3x26yYxrhdQRSjz3Pk8YfgwcTkEeN8LetzQTCkWGXA9LUu4/rcq7ur2o51U2Zdly5sdSB0L7tPdpBG53fiGZlAWKB38o0D@@uyYduq1u4Z@Kkou606Qlq3fMmFdcnvNoSz9BZ5DdYVwSkqXAnipWPzrh96blWyaOxrjopmWiMkEkuyiFmOWhcdBHl@EcMIbjlSWCa719jECWAtg7kQPGTGjExUFG8pE8Yjz1gVJJqgJqG2@ZHE@URTS3ivLlHhI4j3AG05NzjNqUtUWOayW1zdLUsI50BKMwwx5EwxI@ErLHPOa6QBi3XxsVH0yxhRRxxhsrrRkNO1eMrT2o0py@5P7lDIzXSLyKOOx4Vn9jJohwnTsZrdkjKzBqu4eSh9RB/VgfcN2mtmUnR/RYcZW@mbhWywsoHXASLqTc9IXbs/8O1R5X3QpFNdXhSgvL5hcYcLR8hy4U3yrPqhGLxd0y7H3WEQ@sCCujcTMI3npPpPIxS4luWH0T170Qbid8sOS8Eql1Sq4ZYa967UfNFRTKVx5PGnlGu8dv6b5h7jR4JH0S@gYp9H2OJ5CgJzV1PVcDO1Ce4a3xWE/ur@CbeOcR@U2585e8j7KljIwVqzbPWz@R23Tz2bGtlKjxWXLPoo6erYtz937HmsSeDmuArDj5TrLNODaKPwr4mMS/cpoaxaoL0@HdnEzp8kNOjFqp8bjRC8rnQs9J/6H1PtUj53HtsEvCKQEnX9S4mefasqatJLgbRylh1GwGUQ7Af1jzEHadmVEvNu9ym6xBeM9BuLHiyNXJZ8@nwJ4SqRE1D1FJXjT65v@/Z@wtuVlHTbNJEn08dVRfDbId95krnBlbJ85h3sssSd5x4b03WyCMeA3fclT1p5ir6qqG7I6HvA/3LcLtLGjhE7I5ZvthdywdMPRfzJw8/1j6tuOW/A5X6j2567@NsxCPjCvEhWniBZQl9bur6vKrrlkAHsv2vgC9@h8tTZmo5FNDxwowFVALUHstUNVZ/jO1dXJ3yaeFYwxRQOvFkLWdSdwET/OwEp7Z35G6iLtbxyfxdE8pLXFCAbiWx3xAxgNM2W53YdsdEwQHrP2CnomnHC@8jn6zV3J033chAxb/xxJjA9yAsjaIJvtYkXGnyhtezf@vrsOnjXFteUbk9Ikf1fOR34QGbs4NzkHq3a9FxXnOdSOrhCtXQqs6NPCkreJIiISuuYyfuekh@qN/y9EGPbNy41AOqPT0bABaOwPfcQT/0Gfra9WrhxwwUmN1tF6GSmhbjfK4TIE9@LpyilTHyKkA7eKCsx0s0fSO/VkTVMKgOngZ4lTYoZlUDhWCaPIFOzsZ8K9cGpcQnnXaSxvLu05afWOfEFEHHx/sok/FJdA5lbrhBz3I09NQCt@ppiqXGKf9g7ZT5L6yCz6IHOE2d4AF4tZUP1IvPnoJsZMZw/RvRvqDFIqBRc8ln0iPBLGZL2B5dR@Piv9haxzBj1ssDDXonAHbug8oH43/hAYmCZelh4Oxnj5zEFT/Omk/J2UXP6p5JEC21jD/4EIdciVNW/K6HBTSPv/L2G5WnWP@VdWr62mfwImin7n1U4jvIrfHSqcPhZYd/kl7UgatrRecSKecVK6gUDih4fhDF56bwN2eMhk8U9Xfr6@MYq11Tb3HINa@VIO0WW9xk6WBUHplqrG9AlHRSQ9pRxW776Y65PTQNq20uXvphmlfNcoCdJq06sDv@o2BIN32WWDc9dX8XS58wydDlSk/RFPCGzv/nHj0CGrD64iebZh6RikrRP2/rjMgRqKc/Tv10zyW7p6HsatjS8cQEoKXaSp5sqqcLK03e3rj0xDPRkp7hwqoJ66yYrOsc@uvYQKcNL35MqBc2n2LOaKj4GLIS9bCPStaRPajWMylLW7vCDt6bItJr0Imx@oWPgb3Gn8oEWPIPpfAWWaVuhvDxvNJ8O@iRtlXUAxFNRKtpJKlTe1x0DifPqvdxOmpzW8MoHDn/aqA73g06ys34jKhslNP6alaAZjpmWijwPFPWyWFL0wePRlZ@HqK7h7P16E3a7HHs4f7cD7UIs5oxF/0sxJ0HoUW3dE8aSVuKcaz/@ef/AQ)

Comment: I really should've done that in a language I don't use lol.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Yeah, `05AB1E` was my easily my first thought

Comment: Kinda just realized that's probably why my first one was cracked instantly too lmao. God I'm stupid sometimes haha. Should've just used TRUMPSCRIPT

Answer (score 4):

## [???](https://github.com/ararslan/qqq-lang), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155781/12012) by [Riker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46271/riker)

```
The Man They Called Dennis (a song).

Dennis: a extremely decent golfer.
PPCG: a group of golfers.

Act I: Chorus.
[Enter Dennis]
"Dennis;
The man they call Dennis.
He took inspiration from J and he made the lang Jelly.
Stood up to the challenges and gave 'em what for.
Our love for him now ain't hard to explain.
The Hero of PPCG: the man they call Dennis."
[Exeunt]

Act 2: Verse 1
[Enter Dennis, PPCG.]
Now Dennis saw PPCG's backs breakin';
He saw PPCG's lament.....
And he saw that challenge takin'
Every answer and leaving no votes
So he said "You can't do this to my people; You can't let long language's answers win your challenges.
And Dennis booted up TIO! - and in five seconds flat,
FGITWed, all your challenges."
[Exeunt]

Act 2: Chorus - revised, since my program is ending soon
[Enter Dennis]
"He took inspiration from J and he made the lang Jelly
Stood up to Python - and gave 'em what for
Our love for him now ain't hard to explain
The Hero of PPCG, the man they call Dennis (song slows with a dramatic high note finish)"
[Exeunt]

With thanks to Dennis for providing a character for this program, and Jayne Cobb for being the original Hero of Canton.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZNNb9swDIbv/hVcLmmB1MB2TE9F1vUD2FqgxYph6EGxaVuITKaS7NS/PiNlox9re9gC5EsUyfd9SD88POz3tw3Cd0Mg3wOsjHNYwlcksgEODASm@jDPsvFkCQbwMXps0Q1QYoEUoWZXoc@z6@vVmV6oPXdb4GoKBMk@KSJcLGHVsO/k/@9TiuinLvfZbPxxnKmUVqRElVKIlOlKnp0jROYNWApb6020TFB5buESDJWQ8krURHCGarhE54Y8u5GkEkRN5BQrGvVHNYaUVpseYY4t7BoToWIxcdV5cCzH8g8a2wLxDoyleYTG@FIL4ePWyUme5J6jZ/U6mo8fGZiJ50fsKN6PML4s4aegQfj8GsYiFcrvsx/SdppCMLt0Og@wNsVGPj2ajUg6Viwvos60Mo9cX9nJSEWjUc09OYeYcrPTHv0gFMJOmisMh6a3go4Yeo4YshseK9gSZr@4Ez9KoVSSokpAtANskbcOj@E57lDesjRpDp2pcR6mLgF2lmBgIfw8h1Hp5HTN0jjN6/bi6hMcJV2SU1kZSMCCqQxQORMX2bezi9s7LBegkP@u@Q7tcfWkpMfeBk0MlgpMHjzX3rQgApBKRRCY6c2S/tcKvtrA6yE2knT0/u79w@q92bzFh5sHB/oEQ3C8U/6xkQe0FLeiv5AmdSNdorS0crc5fAnuTi/L7tAmDXsqp9oEWG8TKKPUvSkUlEbSZkw8F8nmpRkIYcXrdbqwRk1Tsextbcm4Jx8rQ5Ep3@//AA)

Comment: that is not ok....

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: the language name being ???, [I probably should have added an emoticon xD](https://www.fastcodesign.com/3036748/why-its-so-hard-to-detect-emotion-in-emails-and-texts)

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically) 6×6×6, [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155519/71256) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
[+1[+7]35@]100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P8/WtswWts81tjUIdbQwOD///@6ZgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), [posted by emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247363/85334)

```
-0/(*(*%*)2)
```

[Try HBL online!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=LTAvKCooKiUqKTIp)

`` `|\X]- `` in ASCII/UTF-8 is represented by the bytes `60 7c 5c 58 5d 2d`, which represent `-0/(*(*%*)2)` in HBL's namesake [half-byte codepage](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md).

Inspired by [this message in TNB](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61139641#61139641), which I'm pretty sure was about [his other cop post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops/247382#247382), but I did a search for HBL anyways and lo and behold, 9 answers exclusively by DLosc.

Comment: Oh nice! A bounty is coming your way.

Answer (score 3):

## [xEec](http://esolangs.org/wiki/xEec), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155024/61563) by [totallyhuman](/u/68615)

```
h#1 h#0 >a p o# h#10 o$ p h#1 ma t h#101 ms jna
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0hNTf7/P0PZUCFD2UDBLlGhQCFfGcg2NFDIVwFyQDK5iQolYCEgs1ghKy/x/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), [posted](/a/155056) by [internet_user](/u/51820)

```
c="[,]"[1];f=[eval("str.format")][0];p="1+1"
late=eval(p)+sum([((-1)>1)+0+(0>1)+0+1<<4]);ml=160>>2
ml*=([(7-1)<7+1+1+3*(9>1)]<[(5-1>1+1+1>2)+2+1<<2]);xn=42>>1;ss=sum(eval(f("[10-5{}(4<7)+7+8{}(6>8)]>>>["[:24],c,c)))#]<<<
lol=(7<42)+late+ml+xn+ss#[
m=-9;g=(str((2>m)+x) for x in range(lol));print("\n".join(g));1 < 2 or e#]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY/BboMwEETvfIXlXHa7IcIuCUmx/SOuDxRBRGs7EZAKqeq3U5OedjV6szP7MTZD7B/t17q2mtu941a4ute2@2488GkeD/1tDM3M0dnC1XfNBQme@Wbu9JO5I02PABYgF2gEUkFQ/E@hVOmwDl6LU2GMzIJ/0YmsEqkqSofo9QUuCXbKwjEXZpOEkUhyM8tkXqIupTGinia95Twze0g1i/z48wulqpAqOqf1ZM7ojDGW2zdZun27bxFx55RSmb95DZUq0@mtOgVPS6Rp2tks6PxSXzWkXwGkCUgLsvQ0W9gQ2djEawfJjljfxyHOwN8jP3zehgjXpAmmmGSJ7nZuXf8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155101/44718) by [user71546](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71546/user71546)

```
// Calculate the digit sum of 2^64
var sum = 1 + 8 + 4 + 4 + 6 + 7 + 4 + 4 + 0 + 7 + 3;
var b = " "[2 > 1 && (sum = sum + 7 + 0 + 9 + 5 + 5 + 1 + 6 + 1 + 6) + 0 < -88];
var c = "a" > [2 < +3 ? console.log(sum) > -1 : 0];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLDoIwEEX3fsUNCyIhyFNEQV34GQaTUgGJlSY8/P06lC5cnJnczNxTDazrm5m/lfJ93Jjgs2BTjelV49m13YRx/kA2iB5psvmyQeczQrjIiMSQEoe/HJgc57pUUcWCdY9woaptY7tqlrk@LoUjsTeERqq3ox8KeFlWrkK@CJlFOnIWcGNcwWU/SlHvhGwXvUNHL8QJQZkr9QM)

Answer (score 3):

## [SuperCollider](https://github.com/supercollider/supercollider), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155115/12012) by [Nathaniel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21034/nathaniel)

```
for(1,100,"% "postf:_)
```

#### Offline verification

```
$ sclang test.sc
*** Welcome to SuperCollider 3.8.0. *** For help type ctrl-c ctrl-h (Emacs) or :SChelp (vim) or ctrl-U (sced/gedit).
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-93](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155185/16766) by [osuka_](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51657/osuka)

```
shovv fRom-0to*1E#' <iostream
?>e[10]++;B:12\;g\=`||(
@. >!1:then.do+^\x61@
:^A&>#+:$#<math>eaa$q
```

The carefully aligned `v>^<` suggested a 2-D language. A little experimenting showed that it works in Befunge-93 (MTFI): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNbNLUnL/P@/OCO/rEwhLSg/V9egJF/L0FVZXcEmM7@4pCg1MZfL3i412tAgVlvb2snK0CjGOj3GNqGmRoPLQU/BTtHQqiQjNU8vJV87LqbCzNCByyrOUc1OWdtKRdkmN7Ekwy41MVGl8P9/AA)

Comment: That was quick! I figured that if anything, it would be the directionals that would give it away. I realized I could've abused vertical and horizontal conditionals (especially since an underscore looks really innocuous), but that was only after I posted

Answer (score 3):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155207) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563)

```
_=+([]==[]),
__('_+=-~_[~([]>[])],;'*-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~([]==[]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/3lZbIzrW1jY6VlOHKz5eQz1e21a3Lj66DihqBxSM1bFW19KtG/oQ5kvN//8B)

---

The `[]==[]` part makes me think it's some dynamic typing language with `[]` means something and `==` compares equality. Probably Javascript.

Try running the program in Javascript gets the error message

> ```
> ReferenceError: __ is not defined
> ```

Ok. So what is defined? The line right above that contains `_=`, so `_` is defined. It can only be some language such that two adjacent `_` are treated as two different tokens.

[Spaced does not work](https://tio.run/##Ky5ITE5N@f8/3lZbIzrW1jY6VlOHKz5eQz1e21a3Lj66DihqBxSM1bFW19KtG/oQ5kvN//8B) because `==`.

Answer (score 3):

### [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155220/9365) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

```
/@<<<<<<  >>>>>>@\
v       \/       v
%       ^^       %
?      \  /      ?
>1+:455*  * -+?^:>
?v     /^^\     v?
^      \oo/      ^
^ \!/ ______ \!/ ^
^  v  \____/  v  ^
^<<<          >>>^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4xCsQwDAR7vWKvSJNwiIO4CcHKQ4TuAwEXd/j7jiMrUw3LatFZfv/W@NgdIDuHUsVAOaTSFGYWMpFECYiaUP4s25rSDMx4L2JbJhljbKZjSigmtJQ4tB7pi/F1XO8I/VTvhF175G8@9F@NWrsA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wise](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Wise), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155218/69655) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

```
   ~-<<:>>-~
||<<<:<:>:>>>||
   |[: ?-~]|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K88sTv3/X0FBoU7XxsbKzk63jqumxgbIBHKAXLuaGi6gZE20lYK9bl1szf//AA)

Answer (score 3):

### [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155283/78059) by [ivzem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65965/ivzem)

```
11+""*""*"+""+++1\1<#":1+^"/^"\^<#:
```

There's an interpreter [here](https://parclytaxel.tumblr.com/post/87085714319/interpreter-for-1-in-python).

Answer (score 3):

## [Whirl](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Whirl/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155333/69655) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111   $\       |
|000110011000111100011100100/010 0010 %p0-d% 0+{10000/111    |
|111000100111110001001000011 / 1111000100111110001001  frick |
|000 {01111110001(( 001111100010010000 1111110001()\ () !    |
|001111100010010000111 111000100111 1100010010000111111000100|
|111110001001(0000111)11100010011111!}000100100001111110001  |
|0011111|_0001001000011111100010011111 000100100001111110 001|
|001111100010010000111#1110001 001111100010010000111111000100|
|11111 H) /!00010010000111 1/1 100/0100111110001001000       |
| 011111100  & 01001111100010010000  111111000100111110001001|
|@  00001 11111000100111110 00100100001 111110 001001 111    |
| 1000 1001000011 11110 00100111110001001000011111100010  the|
|the 01111 100010010000111 111000 1001 111100010010 00011111 |
|1000100JO   1111100 010010000111 +=   11100010 011 11 KING  |
| 1000100100001 11111000100111110001 "0010000111111000100111 |
|110001001000011 11110 00100127  : 1111000100100 001   1     |
|11   11000100  11111000100100001111110001001111100010010000 |
|11111100 a  01001111100010  010000111111   000100111        |
| 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1|
|00 01 00 10 00 01 11 11 10 00 10 01 11 11 00 01 00 10 00 01 |
| 111 110 001 001 111 100 010 010 000 111 111 000 100 111 110|
|0010 0100 0011 1111 0001 0011 1110 0010 0100 0011 1111 0001 |
| 00111 11000 10010 00011 11110 00100 11111 00010 01000 01111|
|110001 001111 100010 010000 111111 000100 111110 001001     |
| 0000111 1110001 0011111 0001001 0000111 1110001 0011111    |
|00010010 00011111 10001001 11110001 00100001 11111000       |
| 100111110 001001000 011111100 010011111 000100100 001111110|
|0010011111 0001001000 0111111000 1001111100 0100100001      |
|                      ^1111100010^                          |
|0 111110001001000011111100010011111000100100001111110001    |
|0011111000100100001111110001001111100010010000111111000100  |
|  111110001001000011111100010011111000100100001111110001001 |
|   111100010010000111111000100111110001001000011111100010   |
| 0111110001001000011111100010011111000100100001111110001    |
|0011111000100100001111110001001111100010010000111111000100  |
|  1111100010010000111111000100111110001001000011111100010011|
|11100010010000 111111000100111110001001000011111100010011   |
|11100010010 00011111100010011111000100100001111110001001    |
|11110001+ 00100001111110' 001001111 10001001000011111100010 |
| 011111000100100001  1111100 010011  11100010010 00011      |
|1111JKL5 000100111110   0010010000   11111  1000   10011    |
|111 J 6700010010000111111^& E 00010011 L  11100 L 0 Y? bin  |
|100[print()100001111110   -001001111100010010000111]  111000|
|100 not 1111100 BRAIN010010000 FU1111 11000100CK  111110001 |
| rk:start 0010 0001111110001001 1111  0001001000011111100   |
|0100111110 dckx 001001  000011111  1000100111  11000100 help|
|100001 111110001001111100010010000111111000 1001111100010010|
|000-[111111000100??11111000100100001>1111100 {x=0-100}px    |
|111110001 00100001  11111000100111110 0010010000111111000100|
|1111 1000100100 +++001111  110001 0011111000  100100001 1111|
|100010  011111000100100001111<-1100010011111000100 10000111 |
|111 eval('\b00010011111000100100001111')-110001001--1111000-|
|1001000011]1111000100111110001001000011111100  010011111000 |
|10 +01>0000111 1  1 100 01001 1111 0001001 000011--1111  -  |
|0001001111100010010000111111000 1001111100010010000111111000|
|10011[111-0 0 01001000011 11110001001111100  010   010000111|
|111000 <100  1111100+010010 00 0.11111100010011111000100100 |
|001111110001001111100010>0100001111110001001111100010010000 |
|011000101010010101010111000000101011001]010100101010000 1010|
|111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111|
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This had quite a few red herrings. I tried Nhohnhehr, Brain-Flak, PATH, Cardinal and SNUSP before leaving this feeling a bit stumped. Then dylnan's mention of Fortuna reminded me of Whirl.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VdZTxsxEH7nV3y0BRKttrErtUgISA/14BCVKvWhIlAFSEUEolEa0UiE357uesb2@FgI8FRvstl4PJ5vTs/@PR@OL@fzonzCKJZm@oEDwIseaMyWZkopremrajL9VDelOtUN9RNWRqo8W4Eqbmq66tA2NTtzEK99VGYTdKCzZODXeHh6wdJxQ0RDbbWQbgVBb/fQamPZgU/FakihiKmOOGPTMbnF9HYIefk2yy6lz342SCBzp8RaxSbwz62ALDUBjy9tdJZj/TvVl9wXb@L9DrcfsIqcB4FEGX6s2N8CRhySJRBgEEzBhw0MGBErcl2z3sDkfFCxV3fCj7zvYcU5MuxGJmhpdvcrYPEj2KXYIgoJJXzY2zn47MHHOobQ8SwfD5QyYZpI1V@tAxsBcEOp0cBlnMFGdOCuKEk8asOm5uwj8jr9tzsA8KhF2FR4ocylxZ2e/BWu4MvEPExsw2gMYz3zUXbSzqQrjXTKaHCGgEMA5CbjZV6jwXFgeSjjyNFwhodLNjg3ZJeYlPEVBSKqpAchkp7sSYHq/M6JDS2W2ArHFo@yxiVsWN4QFZhGuq/zYSK4cqwFRxjS0u9pfosSkil3cLHIlk/qoedXfnuZiV56dhz72D1G46ilPyhLZJVvPmUWYK/tZ8A/ll2z7o9jD@r8/6e7DrqLqA@4jzduTnzYL2R2x25mCoSL1vw5hSbb5y0fHTcaSCACQvru3v5rBIcrIA9orjbgXLWqMzt28WY9wXe8io9uT@wzhOpB4UcXJ8Mr8BF5OBoPryatdtC6AGWT/Y6sNsSOq98Tp@77b@92DjzwT9@17M0@7Ik4MaYbX2z8mfTHE2R9R2U501lxzAt7nZ1eTF0hdSsBcST7w/R8cDni9qDhXI89jZhIlbY8lHi73YR/2@K9mW6psnq4HU2F36NyfHeTlbaFIipRFAWHKpLOEgi7GNcaIV81NsuMQeC6Jo66wXX/srXWO2k23Vrbb1SWvKAk6bzo6H7jh/0LBS2KyrbuIKy7JpdsyByWJLyKaXlELuxrSWTwunZ8abqfuMOTmxvoEA2XK1bYlF1d4SoD1Mvm8iUKdULfXqwt5BdAc/GPphdBZedrwpFcQDbR7mXkkWO29LRX4Pn8Hw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Beatnik](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Beatnik), [posted](/a/155047) by [MD XF](/u/61563)

```
aAaAa>>u<<TWELVE>>ooooooooo<<if(i < 100); print("oOOoOooOoOoO");
done:
    PutNumbersFromOneToOneHundredInclusiveFunctionZD<GOTO 100>;
    executes(print); language(CPlusPlusE::PublicUI);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU1NC4JAFLz7KxZPequrLgtRWkK0Hqygmx8vWdL3QvdF/35bhWaYuQwz00Bt0bycq3eeSrGU1T073zKl6A8pzTMyQortZhOn4j0ZtFFIWpMmWkyHcRp0hJAEwqNke@GxgWnOJxo1QkXeTozdBF2B7cCz@UDO2FpD@DjIo670Mq7StQ9faNnCHK1P/nGosee6h2hf@u6iLElKbgbTXgufO/cD)

Answer (score 3):

## [Super Stack!](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Super_Stack!), [posted](/a/155416) by [MD XF](/u/61563)

```
1 1 if pop dup output 1 add dup 101 swap sub fi
```

Answer (score 3):

## [O](https://esolangs.org/wiki/O), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155308/2867) by [MickyT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31347/mickyt)

```
['d#,;r]o
```

Online interpreter: https://o-lang.herokuapp.com/

I recognized it immediately by the `o` at the end.

Comment: yeh, the `o` definitely was a give away :)

Answer (score 3):

### [BrainCurses](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BrainCurses), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155081/78059) by [Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien)

```
' !'d[:-%_%]
```

There's an interpreter [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BrainCurses/implementation.js)

Answer (score 3):

## [I](https://github.com/mlochbaum/ILanguage), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155543/71256) by [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)

```
1i101
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/z/3zDT0MDg/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## [ecpp + C (gcc)](https://github.com/aaronryank/ecpp), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155823/12012) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```c
#rule control_flow foreach
#rule control_flow in
#def `foreach a in b..c:` for (int a = b; a <= c; a++)

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1, b = 100;
    foreach i in a..b:
        printf("%d ", i);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzJCsIwFEX37yseLUJCa6jbDt9iM2IgJiFUXYjfHpNid97NhXMHLWM8y5zb9HAaZfBbCu5qXHihCUlzeYM/kfXQKm1w/XWQF4SCMTmudYfE@q3ABcVUbF5QFu86ClCDO7eePINVFN6ARUf70qOoNgzTzo97W@85Y2LccVVMZWRIc1LY9GjpBJ@cvw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Deadfish](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops/247370#247370) by [Number Basher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/111945/number-basher)

```
ibbfibbfsdbfsibfbffsfbfbi
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! Oh do! 
DONE... THIS IS ALL I HAVE TO SAY... 
Oh do!
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##7ZO/CsIwEIf3PMWZyT@0tIoiQoaChRaKHVoEx8QQeghtaTro08fEap5AnIRc7riP75cp/WNsunaz7wdjNKOUohDKlZa2UCihlLaXQFI2ILsZfKf90/5pP007lqc0DEOos7wCe5KigByy5JxCXUKVXBz8vGn/ASGcRUR1AyBgC/pAABUgYxQpuK2d7tRuga9Y7KH28DZBxpfcU@mpnGjwVjljQeyYHdbb3WRG3uu8d315/YDtOOcLY54)

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), [posted](/a/155027) by [moonheart08](/u/77964)

```
0[1+pd100>a]salax
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98g2lC7IMXQwMAuMbY4MSex4v9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Locksmith](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Locksmith), [posted](/a/155069) by [Conor O'Brien](/u/31957)

```
import java.util.Random;
interface Main{
  public	static void  main(String[]args){
for(int	i  	=0; i  <		90*  11; i ++)
System. out.println(i);
f(   	 	7);
g();
}
public static 	int f(int n){System.out.println(n);if(n<=0)return+n&3;
else return f(	n/7)*6	+7*f(n-5)+7;
}
public static void g(){
Random k=new Random(45);
String j="YmlULmxZXERFZmNvbg==";
int m;
for(int i=m=0;i<121;i++){
m+=j.charAt(0)+j.	charAt(i&1)+k.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(k.nextInt((int)Math.pow(7201,19))^6^m);
}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRT8IwEMef209x4YG0VOeGwkLGHnzQxER8gJgoRpIyttGxdsvWAWbhs8/ClmiiL23vev/73/3SLNiVUuht0wiZZ4WGhO@5VWmRWnOuNpn0sFA6LCIehDDjQtUYIK/WqQhQqbkWAewzsQGQ5o8sdCFU/PHJi7ikNY6yghg1EgDItz0w9xShiT0AcJxzyBjFi69Sh9KCrNJWbuQ6VURQD0cEjAyQa94xMccJt77Q@SJTC9HZABStuza/uyjqiYioqW/TItRVoZjq33o4TMsQ2oSRI3Xj0sEYMXdgaq9HlLl/rS4rmiFq3EKBna/CA7QBuRuZ6drVIfF77zJ9fZbH5dvD/HEpX/br2Pd7F4xgaHZMQPjSIBFTZ@h4wnCosWR@YgVbXtxrYlOWWKgLRN@hbGep8KiflG5R/LPuT8XZgM643lp5diDu0HaunAmlq/FKXsSnpvkG)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155038/31957) by [Uriel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65326/uriel)

```apl
+\100\1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBNoxhgYGMYYA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155138/64121) by [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin)

```
False T
For nnz(100) T+1 
'cout <<' T
)o:
bux bux Q
hu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3y0xpzhVIYTLLb9IIS@vSsPQwEBTIUTbUIFLPTm/tETBxkYdKKuZb8WVVFqhAMKBXBml//8DAA)

Comment: I'm, curious... Do you know how it works?

Comment: @StewieGriffin I'm not really familiar with MATL, but parts of the code, i.e. `nnz` and `T`, reminded me of MATL programs I've seen on PPCG.

Comment: I guess `nnz` has been in explanations. `z` alone is equivalent to `nnz(x)` in octave.

Answer (score 2):

## [Implicit](https://github.com/aaronryank/Implicit), [posted](/a/155049) by [MD XF](/u/61563)

```
(].[]%<100@9)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/18jVi86VtXG0MDAwVJT7f9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 664 bytes, [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155264/59487) by [Christopher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63187/christopher)

```
for(each num in #1/#100)
(
    do #pointOfNum(num)
Push (#pointer@#num)
if(result(pointer@(num/pointOfNum(run2)+#diff)))
while(each num of pointer@num)
do
(ITS GO TIME!)
DO THE MATH
)
def fun add{
while add #(point@100)
})
def {
do@#point()
})
open{ref}add(42))
do
{SAY IT TO THE NAND})
{
push why1998@point
})
if(output!ready
(push@#out
{buy})
onGler<@spoin>
pushet)
<Divmod@point@uf2X3>
discov def n{
<div@23>
point@(4524#f34)
(@#do(@3h)
{point*723
numdif}
)#huCX5DBP^h~0_GG1<h32X542P[18F18h42X%AAP[h!.X%OOS`M a@<euws
[give@point
(for@point13)])
div<pointmod>
divide((42/9
{
over@point27
})
[pointto(27)]
giv@12)}
div<mod>
def run{
pointOfnum
fun@#(23)
why1998
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVJdj9owEHz3r/DJOslu1UKcIECKTqblyvHAhwQPVOja5s52YxViFOIgFHF/na4dTq2f1uPZ2d3xvpSZKT7pXfbnetW2pCp7zXHh9tgUmEQdEnW7DFGE4UiLycGaolroudtTIDG0dMcc0xZWpSABNJqW6uh2FX3HPbnzX27pCs4@Emm0ZoyhU2526l9pq/F7YtCTFtHpeoUnC7yezh7vGBpD9PSIZ6P1E4J3pbF2Bc6kbFotH2LSlhdhhEtLa0BMtO3SANqDKppS6Qtk0ISzUK1Zjb7j6Rqv2zLz0XwM1AYd/LSn/BwNhwMRRLwEjGtddXDVXakyeUbU0wQBDDUv7uyLFJOdKlNx9DkPQUZVDKVjU@@tbJWE03wTPyBpjq@2xr7ZokGpNLXgALccmvR4QnScwJ8IIi0VcQ6NhccPfR4j8AtMvSBGcvd10xt/Wf7I37o/J5MozWO@6SV8uY0G36JBnvDN/Wi03OZ3nzf3i8Xq1wxnIlXudETb36ZWt/koLEUbRjF7BndMnYYrNO6brY1UFIzrDMEfW6sbmfe9M9sQV5byPntGoCoizi5Bo02HIWEVGnRbDegewUcKQnnstyIYjS7X618)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155139/76365) by [Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien)

```
Lazy!~1
```

[Try it online!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=TGF6eSF-MQ)

I wasn't sure what this was so I decided to dive down deeper into some of the languages you developed!

Comment: Good job! Nice to see someone looking at my languages ;D

Answer (score 2):

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](https://soulsphere.org/hacks/smbf/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155192/69059) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

```
v<[-=0lfn_v#:-d<]
<[/_>]/@-0>_?!:^"d.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85NSvv/v8wmWtfWICctL75M2Uo3xSaWyyZaP94uVt9B18Au3l7RKk4pRe//fwA)

Answer (score 2):

### [False](http://strlen.com/false-language/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155261/78059) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
1a:[a;101-][a;.a;1+a:" "]#
```

An online interpreter can be found [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/false-js.html).

Answer (score 2):

## [Lily](http://fascinatedbox.github.io/lily/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155315/56470) by [tfbninja](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69912/tfbninja)

```
for i in 1...100:{print(i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8nMqfz/Py2/SCFTITNPwVBPT8/QwMCquqAoM69EI1Oz9v9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155376/61405) by [Colin Robertson](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77483/colin-robertson)

```
n=1;while(n<101){console.log(n);n++;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/z9bQujwjMydVI8/G0MBQszo5P684PydVLyc/XSNP0zpPW9u69v9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Hy](https://github.com/hylang/hy), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155074/11157) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)

```
(defn !(&optional(> 1))(if(< > 101)(do(print >)(!(inc >)))))(!)
```

You can try it e.g. if you manually type the code into [this interpreter](https://try-hy.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 2):

## [Gambas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambas), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155380/55934) by Christopher

```
Public Sub Main()
Dim num as short
For num = 1 To 100 Step 1
    print num  
Next
End 
'1-100.print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155275/61563) by DevelopingDeveloper

```
$ 123
@(%
#ZZ
&^0
*i*j F=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101
$ 123
@(%
#ZZ
&^0
*i*j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZA7SkVREATzuwrBD/Ko4Mx/JhCMXMQLBAUDxcz9cz3mLqC7q0t/3t6/P87z7kbUjufH@@P2ej0eXtdx@bx83bw8CYrhBEnRDLIQQRQxxJFAEimkkUEXujOKGupooIkW2uhgCxNsVxrmWGCJFdbY4AsXXPG96HjgiRfe@BCLEEIJIzZQEEkU0cSQixRSSSOd3LxJFtnkUIsSSimjnApq3ymqqaEXLbTSRjsddNL7bdPDLEYYZYxxJphkitky/mxsHUuO/wWe5y8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155474/69655) by [iovoid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64949/)

```
a := "+++++++++[>+.+.+.+.+.+.d.+.+.+.+.<-]";for(q,1,a at(23),q println)
```

It works by indexing the string to get `d` which has an ascii value of 100 to use as the upper limit of the for loop.

Comment: I've downloaded Io and it does indeed work.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//z9RwcpWQUkbBqLttPUQMAXOstGNVbJOyy/SKNQx1ElUSCzRMDLW1ClUKCjKzCvJydP8/x8A "Io – Try It Online")

Comment: @Dennis wasn't expecting it to be on TIO so fast.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155482/41024) by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

```
~th5@.oLh
```

[Try it here.](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=~th5%40.oLh&input=&warnings=1&hex=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Coconut](https://tio.run/##TYzLCsIwEEX3@YpZJhCD2RbiUigIlf5BLCoRO5EkhRTx22MeCt0M3Dn3nslOFpeQ0qwNQtfBuGA/kJoUvJzBAPRpfL5O4/0KVHKQe8kYI6T@8@aIQOlYMIceA4PdAegpwxZZKyqIvpACxM3Zebg8gEafRU39N521cRvRRsx@TZV3fK34HYVYPyl9AQ), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155513/45151) by [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni)

```
main :: RunIO
main = print (list (range (1, 101)))

list :: Fn ((Range, Int) -> (List, Int))
list = xs -> List.fromObj (xs)

range :: Fn ((Pair, Int) -> (Range, Int))
range = (x,y) -> {x..y}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Underload](https://github.com/catseye/stringie), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155089/61563) by [Esolanging Fruit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61384/esolanging-fruit)

```
lpvO`.U%C$j<{YNXzbF[=/n'A5 7KYL3$3IZvrP>P%LJ&`fv[5]$3(
){u}Z'K7s{lA8}pNZvmLwE`GevRo?I>H38{q}[d/hJrkcp7F]e7$H[
L(]WCrrWxbb[M][6]m\[DH]j98Ki&H<n=Nn=|{f}UMs-`_5b?-ixC/
5V_M{R}w@+[N2P]eg998dq;[Qq]-od|XoX{P}{N,}#G($)%tdZN*?[
Z];fUK{_H26DY'R|sdQy;%P#g}|X{IQvM}cXDMmvG1O[i-][{s}]3I
L:hw2s ="dY0g/4YS14#>Y.GIs=KMm"H[&]r3[G])VgE(hCLyP8cs[
V]j[W]jg:cvp6X8:lNchdg8;55{o}P]{*Q}qc[y$]sZ?P60EI[_]wt
:6TIyK'XRfR<[>HG]*|Xz]o[z]0A[T]t{"}*}[8#N5wy[{nU}[W]N;
+h?p{nRgy}W{[u]vIJX?{sl,};4>.}Z/Km>1]]:pMp-0<[[,].Q$J`
*&nL0Jg]{/{J),[[{[s]j}]]=f7f B:5k}"B{1A}}{*T}1Tr/cRX w
lBKJ_6UoC^QBC{8}/G'x2&Le3w[u]&T-hpUA2/c.>Zb[N]|pX[8,]X
t2@^.{h}K7lo{<d}xozh>wb?Hello worldHello worldHello wo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1tf6lgHADg930KP88MeVg0DzVsU0qLw6T7/A9HUbMoZYXb/dmdfYDz7np3fR/Mje@4f8373fHC91Vpluond228ULTr@g116EOmy8Qa0kKuJWuiHvoqp6bkYXq1DREDyVqWyuFvomekRoCdLks8RQ/3cvS6GmzCicuLnFBj8ZEgk7aH/pfhNd5g00gKiJKzMO/7/vy8XqMRoDrsf6MXAXZPrPSZFtqHjnLo3PCWzEZBcbVk1nzx89ynKeZjOcITEj0/IKWqwsZ6emLNYwuNj1B0zZvmalglWCmQxCCbzKVOpq7keUTp0NrOJLwUqvWXRWZyC8zxpZVSExa5aVgchyNiaC@jfTiovKPPIiAcEKiJlNy0o2oQ68TNRdmiHxe/Ko8JblEaiEFHGu3jAkqDX0MDyH1Yr1m7L19U1ggQ9QE7NIed1TRCr66xTUcxbNNiWwyDXaICzo/J0UCXJAQ6r9bLryJaQnSimvWpeJEy2mQ7aSNOGED@pl3BRVcod9EUTjhO8gSxCYWJLggfZuQnUVrUg817@DCxLmSO0TeE4lDjceAUSOuRKxGdlvZcBaDpjbxiuY1QAUrj5HBF5dMHuTy0ANN4mCsghFEAOwLQ2Ta2sV6T@SLxHq50CcH5KalMfdqYaLGIcnrScFmfuf0/414fs4QeZM7VtLypRT93elq0vVm3ShslTl8jBW6ehtgCaNSp@vynhG0iNRwXt01ydq82F615YeM4bixyfcf8D@/3fw)

Outputs in Unary, with `$` for the value and a newline for the delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

### [Whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155745/77759) by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

```
def v(n=[]): #[	  		  	  

  #!"⠖⠔⠄⠑⠃⡆⠊⡬⠀⠞⠈⠀
 #;;;
   	 print(n*chr(33)) 		  	 	
 
for		n in range(100):	
   #
   #"	     
	#"<<;?)*aanlll>1#<-#.:_:*aa@#.#!9fo"
     	v(n)
	>d$/")!;\    
 
		 xXxxxXXXxXXxX>({.<
 xx%c++=t=+~\

   D.+L0~-tt/	  	
	..R;MU
     	]+@x+++++++++[->++++++++++<]>
	    [->+[->+>.<<]>
 [-<+>]
		<.<
]

~-<:<<<<:<||~[:?~-]|
```

Output in unary spaces separated by a single tab.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/RSsMwFH1OvuKuUWgW2m3syTbL9uCjvghCoStSttYNRjZq0YCjCIqIb4L4KNm7X5UfqUmZHnLDzeGce08eVuu6uNvli6Jtl0UJ976cpBmNgKQIALkCwBiA9Dyjv4z@NPrF6A@jn83h1eh3c/gx@snob6PfbIOBxHFs9da3q9ay9mV/sar88ZjS4ziEAZfbCiEJawlVLm8LfzQc0gg5G@kuzyotMCIe5/GU9vNcbjYbMSI8IGF0E1liRkLSOyu3Hu60yEanGInlycCjvXje@e0EBCpRSiVJotwR/mPIMSh1umBsUk9YM3ffg/OQXQyboK4HLiRGYXgVX14fR2dsptgf0kD894xnAndZHetKhNxx9s2ZyOx6btdlGDcBj7hFxPf7Jo2mTZDt2/YX)

Comment: Well... that was a lot faster than I has hoping for :(

Answer (score 2):

## [oOo CODE](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155720) by MickyT

```
If UR lEEt `NUfF 2 W0rK 0Ut W0T 'd4 L4NgUAgE Is It Will 5h0W y4 ZEr0 T0 NiN37Y nIN3 pLUs 0NE, bU7 Us A AsCIi Ch4rACt0r 4 tH3 Numb3r Rath3R ThAN Th3 numB3r itS3Lf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcixDoIwGEXhV7mbi0Nja5grqbGR/APSEJ0UEdoEqCll8Olrl5Mvx3v/9v0nJT3A1JiUiniSGc44oGXhCmZiRoNdL1AJGo0cFfQKnbebJhwta/ETeKjA0DCQI17csWji@FZmBSO1R2cKZEvItdQOpRVBlpEFCMQLB21zxwPqV7S8RmMl5XAs23zK28Ubr4aU/g)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233388/78850) by [emanresUA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a)

```
v>@/<
1%_\|
/]8\<
d+^}|
_/{-/
^*d|1
9#h\/
k-Q.|
e3d+/
4!5|5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/v8zOQd@Gy1A1PqaGSz/WIsaGK0U7rraGK16/WlefK04rpcaQy1I5I0afK1s3UK@GK9U4RVufy0TRtMb0/38A)

My first instincts were right lol.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 10 bytes, cracks [emanresu A's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233392/66833)

```
{1+x}'!"d"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v9pQu6JWXVEpRen/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `-HASKELL-RANGES`, [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237771/80050) by emanresu A

```c
100...0 do I 'p I;';
```

[Try it online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=-HASKELL-RANGES&code=100...0%20do%20I%20%27p%20I%3B%27%3B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops/247380#247380) by [Number Basher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/111945/number-basher)

```
+π5œÅu‰++´k+JO+za%Î+†+Å5DZÓXDv˛5ˆ◊+Á5c[\"Utp9j>ƒ+>l(s0‰Å=jLÏ++>+*+T‰\+y?>‰h+ŒE4+Ó++>++˚NˇgPım6∫+S++>DfT+ßd=ˆ+Q"B+q‰lˆ+H+˛+Y>ÅX+x+ST˛+´m&Nwˆ+ƒ {V#∂+j+\i_xƒÎ+>+a´++@+++hˆE1+UE´ÁD`w+Ω=BˆPˆ>)++f++%3+PS+n+¨+Å∫VıPZf=+ç>+UÂ+;+¨l˝Ï(++!6++†6∑I+∑aY+´!+œN>+B+˚z†++˙œ+\+Cç v+¬`„ß+dS¨O√†ˇ++Á+b∆¸M9DÏ6e>˙+Â++'Ç∫D++˙q≈∫+Vßı˙+ ++ˆÍ˜+`#`:K? 3Y¬++>+O++´Iv+Ç+vF++xƒ√+`++b1++p+4>ÁˇLˆ'Í+J(˚++hÇ+Q6++~++aw˛+!+o++V˝+atÅ+aƒ/>+"++†œ+p|+Â+Kp+++ç+U+++|+Qå©+W¨¬>+Å+xd˜+x+Ó´1¬´\+6d;+B++ˇ+©#+~+9{+D+/A++?Q+®6<<∫1Øq<<E<<x<<<Z<OΩg)<a<<@<6øA<<ˆÁ-]Ø!25>j>´>No{U>>(> CTk+∑.-<~h<<<<<ßÅıç>>;>å>rÇ=å.v=¬π‰3</gÅ9˜2Ωc#π<<<>b>ı/>y>>„!ƒ>++m.xV´k--<<W<<:YkØ¨∑z%√H´;f4˜<|<:m>Ó3$Å5mj9>@?RÎ>a&>Kƒ.8\<<ÍΩÍç<<5>~˝>>\Î>l>';∆6>Um+åXqÂ+x+.--Z5-D<rˆ6X´<<Ò≈\cVÅ<_˛<<>>>%'Ff>.<wÎ<<<Í>>ruF˜"$#Ω„>QVi>;>%f>>--∂Xå-Ï˚-Î®.ˇ#Ï+++e+</<2K<˛<\ << <>K28>GRÁå>>@g.@<8<<∂r<>lç>ÇqZv$>>>>3>„$®-Ïß-Œ4-Y'.œ++˙;ˆ}ns+ <8adB<<q<˜<S<<>n">>>Ô‰.<x≈u∂‰<˝xΩ<Á<´{">>^>R8X&>J>Ω> z>!∫-Wu-¸%"ıSˇ5i.5{ +√c+<<&ˆ<;tf<<<zÎ∑∏<„fT>>>deŒika>G.$<´®X<<<">>>Î>>>)>-7s/˜/„ZL*U´'˜{\@.+‰Y`<<<<<˛P<8<e>H|>vo>Yg>.˛TÅ<<˚˜≈<P*Í˜Mudı<‰1PtQa>ˆß>˝Ô>ow0>ÂC>EÓ>J>Ω.g<≈<<∂<}<2*&<†Ym∏¬<F?¬ Ya¨>>H>˛VE>6}O\Døˆ.çe;6t6Ô<Œ<<I<∫>>H">oWÍ>CD5Î!Q{zg>>6œ>F+r.-<ç≈<NH&Buπ<œ@#%|<N<<<Ó>>QLÍ>(1>.¬<˜<7<<Sı>∏„~>>>ß ∑>>∂}+Ó.å˝;-}Ø7<Q<z¬<Å<∂<<>J>©b≈>>>>.<^¨<∂<Qµw<<Â<>)U>Í>G>ƒ.<*<=<<> &&M>>Âc`N>f>>˝W+.-<<g◊K˜<s<;<<;Ω8|Fß>/ppR(>v`>?>>>+.-E<1<<RM˝dzßkP<Òuå{ ∆=<ıe<>UÏ>#>>∆fj.'<<<<">ˆ˜*>>>^>k7>F+.9-NRπ<Í<8XΩ<¨yı<©^h<$|Ç<>I>>˜uø>{T¨ˇohK>◊Ô>˚KR++.å-H:¨¨∂{*ŒdÔ-L<oG∑%jåe3†<<\yI√<r„œœ√ø*¬<<>>B>l˙>◊.<c¸:˛Ø<√¸_≈<<>„Í>>?C>„Wh>>S+.C-˛<<~<<µ=OT˚<ˆ<=>>w>Y{>D>Çƒ>dK;;++6„t¨+.-kJ-g8-<E`œN<P<Qc!uK<<)I<D>®>˜~ÔŒ>&∆>s.<<<*Ï<|>>†4BDtbT?\˝UE TF‰>v≈^L>>®F^ÔZK|>+q6f.{|r-<p<˜J<de_<<p∆}qL<g)>#>√a>>Ô>T>>---`&◊ˇøΩ~-.´Z+`+JZ¬+Eut7$å+y¬◊3<<<G<<<E5˛<ƒΩQ>ÒJK{´>I>Uç3Z>b.<G<<<Ò?1Ô>#>>a>>´>˜/©+µj.-˚9uÎ<B<†Z<62<</d<A1Ω>>>U6\‰>>b©p>>-∫--.+zL++<<2:<<W<∏<<ß2b>>k>k>.<h<∏<C†<}x$◊O4Ô˚çπåø¨>>>>2i˝>P>/+˜.-˙'Îcs∏˝Ôfx<HzR<Á<<<!∫<Ø>@ ƒ>XY>lb2>B∂>O>>Wkbß4Ó--.„UΩ+;+<å<<Q∑˚r<@9<∆TŒyå<O?/Í˝˜<8k ezcgZ>¨Œ©˜g>>>(.<< p<n~˜Ht<8>ˇˇz#∫}‰q∑Ó>I>>7Ln)_˜>>≈+vZ√.-ZOå&<Â<"<<√lcXWØ<ˇ!LU<>%bt>y&?Y`>ÅπO/å:H6>@~>ˆ>>d-.Ç+3¬◊ø˜<<<Ø<`<aQ√◊¨<ø<2>\>>>.k2<ˇ<g<}B<◊˚>øŒ>s>>>O ZO>+bn6.-iı1<®<P<Óf¬v <<ˇØ0\<˜cœ>Tˆ>@†Ø∏ß>Œ?Ám("3>a%>w>S>Œˆd.ˆç0<1<*<<C<<<^>ƒ´>7˙>◊t>qIu.<˚<\<</>>7~>˚{>>>+.-®<#<¨˝ø}©I<˜<1a<<ø>7>>>i∂∫y>>†>+.ˆ%-g<∂<˚◊Å<\<<<<1¨>>>>.<dKLÏ@qˆ<oL˜ø<o<>'>‰ˆ>IŒ>>1>„∫Ò+6LJW^+X.8!--<j¨<:9;´O<x<ØÏ$<<>v>Or;>N9>m>>.ø\u<◊<†!j=◊(QIgÎˆf<G<@<z{4i<*7>Ç>Rn>_†'gˇoLå_G{>.¨m¸;l<<<<yzÔAkE>2>ø>>d>K>9+Ih+=.5--Xc#<<œ<qm∏!<h<u‰Y<>˛∑>rX>>RR´`Z>>˜+G%o0˜:D˛˜¨.-)<l˙mAßπ/D<√Ø<<Ô<{<v3tÏ\a4>~(∂>ƒc>>.<<`<S<>=U˝^_nJY >ˇ>>_>µP>oÎ!+b)a+.I-Áyw*-<Ïå~w<‰<|<<<˙0´^∑6>>>ıF>µ>>+ßUØÔ+h%\.˜˚--Î<<=qÏÂ<<D<Ô@ˇ"G%<Iux&$lHı>ZH>D(>˛∆w∑>?∏=/q&.3LÓ@d˙$<d¸<©<<Ø)t´(S>∂O!>>eL>:R>>$+l %Ó¸|+E!SA./H--˝˝C¬;ß<<<<G<¨m<>>>>>W>y1J+N˙ŒΩL+d+*.tz8*Hˆ:Ô∫Knj8k˚--"}Â¸-‰˜¨˝?<Po8W<<†<≈Rzv<<Á&Î>≈ßı@>>?ı>Á.<<N<<nG˜Ï>BA>0ÎS9=>^ÔSOπ>>>|gbSÏ+}+./--m<<<<<x'<alf8>9>>b∂>©˝>/c {>~>Ø----.ÓÁΩE+(+Y¸+ +<√K<@Å<<s~<p<{=ı<∏Í>r>>>R.{œ^d◊<:=<)w´q≈<G<∂¨˜>N>9>rÓW>>>++~˝.--<<©v(9ND©W}<7<l<<>¸†gå4|/ˆI=Á>>w>U;>Â^cz>\>c-Ωf--.+∏+qbıΩ+&<R¨<`I<˝2^a#<W¨:<ı˙M</<>/Mj>>>|¸R˚.<<iDn<tÂ<>>H>Îå>o>>Âv;ÅXB‰++gT.--k<kB<$\¬<√7<O<<t>Ç>3!πH>∆∏(E>≈>ÔTg=\lF>¨˜¸>z#-◊gÇΩ4-Ω.=ı˚"Ò~++<<„®'Ó^/P*<´π)≈< <<mxC´˜<´>>>ÂI∆J>.&=X<L<<<>>>>0>_∫F◊>\XÒ+π`œ+Å´LLˆJ.$D--<<<{ß<π¨W@<<#>>n>BQ®>>>?π0>π-.+Zˆ<(<<J6<<Y<?¸0f<>>ÎF>KÏ \MrÁπ|>N∂T√∆.J´¸ç~Ç5`<`<<<>´>:∆Ï%y8´¨J∆>>◊>◊>n+6\+C.-A-<<<<m<<>5>>>>wÇ&>N¨© ‰>ˆÇEt.<<<{<q<<◊<˝ÏœCl>>cå&WAw=)>ˆ4˛>.tÔ∑<¨¨S<<çµåu}Ç<>„>>ÒxB>>`>)+Ô¬πIGÓ&Í+zK.ß-~˙-<Ó|<B<<Hdml<<>>Ï1>Ó2i˜∫)>>X>u>\8gÍ†3+˚.X-F<´Î©<j<Ehß<!<<®gÒ^∆®<?_å|‰>>n7πç>e˝>z.†\d<<4≈<|†8@<>>>>_>>Ï|D+d\+¸q+.--w-¬o‰u<µ<Ò<Á<ç<¨©TÂˆ∏u∂<>>d>>ˆ>>.<˙%/<Eıx}ç</<µ!@0∂<{<Vj>¸>>>.<¨<q^˜z8a6m=˛N<<>˝®UØ˙>>cGÒ~w>;Q>>ˆ´Z ++π+.˝%¨%--uˆ'˜1c-{®xv¬Y<¸Ï<z\<<<<>}´>>sWÔ˝*Á>b>>+{p*C.-C|<A<j˙deM*V2ÏY<Ï<<h\Óvyƒ/<¸~>v>'> ¨1\Œ>`.<YbEt∏WF<Dø∫5<ÁÏ<¸Çk^?>L_&ZqS≈˜B∆p>ˆh˚ˆ>v@#Ky8a¨6sAC%Ω>>≈>+z*T+oß+.---<<˝<Î´3<<6<>&T>ˆÒ>∑1>>g>|\++∑¬.wØy2tv~¨-_-ˇ<@<hH< ø˝¬å9<<s~ˆ¬Ó∫I<ˇ$>y#J>>>Y.<E<%<jq<>>X>3>>sq>¨M++T}J~_A´+p¨p.-Â˚--<<h<ŒˇHÁHß<<<>>√Q>>h>2>†+Sƒ++.q{œ---<˛´u<x˝<<<?<>>;?˝u>>≈π.ŒS<ˆå<mt ? c<Qlıµh<øœ4dø>c>"/>S>>I(Áe>∂©+¨L&m˛2d++®5Ω.$-2lBl∂„-r@†-<rSßA<Âøˆ<y<<<>Ô>a>>%ˆ>®>B"9>^cŒZ-3-g-!-Í.+mRI¨+"++QvT*~<<TX<´<<gEyA^∂<<9>>ˇ>>_B6∫PmB.<dMˆ˚aJ<<I<~%c>L>>>†>*)^øSƒz>1Á+=ƒ+Ï+.2P--ŒÓ-<<´"<`<w<v©<u>6†∏8>>(>>>({rY∆>--l˙-.+RdÂÂT¬+√+å7(bg2<ZO<˚\<G<ˆ%<¨<a<Â>´ee>b>>.<Ò<<=˛„Vz|å<Å>>>>>>~e+˝+% ˆ+.u--pŒ-<<\<3mE_Á<"s4u<Ø∂˜ΩeN<im&w>;å˜†>Å\>>>>Ï>}G¸/5F\V2-Ó-Is.Sa+çh˜+B0\<<\Â<<Ò<1LY<@<h´0>m9>o†#\d>>.<<<„NleE1ƒœøÏ´¬<>>≈ø>XOjn7>Á/√b>Ô>+++7X∑:.@M´IcC-Ø/6--Ïr2<<H'<çU<ˇ∆^2<1Z˙B∑<i>k>4R>ÏVÂ>>vπ>G4>-Ç.√+çX„v∫<<_^®<<˝∫„I<≈œˆ<å'<>Ïq>Ò¨√®z‰>>.< H')I<Iœ)K!<´m<B˜$©F>˚>˛>9>ˆ>_AÍ`>◊|++Ç8+. -¨¸I--<<_J˜πå<<hq<bp<˚/>#„Ø´s>>>>)>1¬>.p<<<t8<wÓµC<`C<#<>ƒ>˜iµ◊ß#>\>.H\å<‰d?<<≈v˝å<G>>r6XK>C&>o'8nf„>Â◊gvyV3¸>+„˜\˙+ıh+ß=.-◊{ÒNe-ƒIÅPJ3M-A<$\<rN9Ø<<<< ;>>ÓYYˆF>O>>$L>>gXfLÒ◊o∫w`51ß+.-<Z<~<Fˆ<Oœ<π<<9˜≈N>Y‰>>6)>.F=∫¨%1Ò√Y<¨nP:<Y<r2ˆu<>>d∑3gp®Wa>M>˜˛~≈>Å{> tP>-©-˙Zœµ∆--©O.ÍV+^|˛`+∏'+E+<<<r<P<<<C∆X>>>Dxj>¨√ˆ>ÅE91>.<¬˚<krl<‰<ßx?hµÏ9{Z<˝<>>†=3>>.<<<<>t˙π@jF>ˇN>©:ç>>s>!R6ƒCQ>-kx(˜-k-@-l./+Ó++µ|∫˛„+;KÍ<FG<<HŒb<qÍ∂´D´¬}Y<<ƒG<A&>>R3>>M>†=e:Ô>®¬+r1.Q˝q&T-;LsÁ<a<`<b}√<˜<<n>yy>~kiÓ>ƒß\∆◊>C.˝Ω<oŒ<<<> S†3å2>`´:¬>Ø"c>:Ô√>;‰>>=-Ç--ŒÎÍD1-Q.C+Hc+4å+ˆ+qz<N<<´Ç<!´:%4ƒ<<¸<Å>π>X√6®>ywS>>†1>π+∑0+7|.~&--=XÁJ<Ó;<<<∑x<vW<∏œÎÇS>>J#*ç>†>.<S}TB<˝*c%m<<>>>=Å>*U@>‰!|2g>>B-"®sB--Å˚-.++s++ın<∏<oTu;<<˚<&<<åZÂqS'ÇD>†ı>>{ƒ*D6L>;:>g:~>++≈+.´˛Î-å-f´fı{YÔåyA∫t6Å®ÇÓc7„-#r<6<1iQzJÍ<ıµbÔ<<Ï<(ƒWf)˜E~>|X3ı>>|>.<ıF<<4Y<>'>ˇl!>>>>>∑¨X†`\-z-†Byd-\-„Ï.+aM+sW?{+8W+∂´3<<ƒ¸gEÂHp1<<r<<<>:>>ÍZœ∑>√>´>0√©å6V>'ƒÍ--m--Œ˙.+QY+~Íwø+~+</<¸<lcçs<{◊Q<D†<<@>|˙H>7>>.Å<<<<>>W>>>ø>Ø>{*k--Å$--.+++A+<<<ı<F?~D<wE<<>å>h>>Ç∆>>x>Wj◊H-J--.kœ4^Å2+t++<¬<<ßu;ap<ÍˆJµ;˝U<<@T<≈p∑˝>˚Xuhå:>Ò˚>œMYdp>ZkY.ywµ_b&ˇi<Q˜IR<Ω<<Óe2>>XI1∆ˆJWa>>>>Ô√sC˜K>---Hbˇ-;G.?++|fƒ+_?˚H+<<<n√gB<<<<∂>>#>Aπ>>c>>--Å.Hfˆ+Îi$A+|Ó<<<<I<&<Ω<mVS>=ß)ÅD|>>>´Le.ˆ}◊Å©Mab\$3"qD\◊K<∆)<I<πC4|ß<>P>>∆ @4>/:çpK>¬>>)ƒpe9-i2lÂ-P-´Å0-ı~c≈Í.Å+0Ωˇ+6ˆ„++Q%<A<)u7Ø@<l<}Å´´<\'<F´u<>Ç„$%ƒR6>N‰π>_>>3>Wc´ıXçÍH>-Ò.$6+<<'gB<<<ˆ|1∆F<<QLçÏƒ;:Á!>¨∆vÏ>˜3>>sx.˝Œ∆<<<<>8>>>V>>I_>x-pG-=--NÂ.'U9Ó++˙$Ó+t„˙&+nÔ<7<<<"¨D03<*Å&Å<<wƒ>Ó>D˚>>˜>>ΩZ>.„sˆ∑øIF<!\Çlœ`<~<(dÎÅ´<<˙©(π<†®e<O#>>>&˛U>3¬øFL¬5.<<<<®Ï˜_>m˜DHn>ŒgA>µ>&!„>_ßG>>|----P◊ˇDƒs.N++El3+≈Ó+Òd<ø†˜W<"(=UQ<˚3*˝<Ón<e}r<<Ï¸>†å>>dç>Ø>gŒ>>3+˙.;_-<<<ÍZA< <;<<Up$>>´H>I>w.Áb<zXB1<<(ı1¨<œf>ÇAu\pÔ(C>K>SΩN=\>˚6>≈j˛>Ò¨4>--8N-s.\++Q+Á<<ÂPo<Çg4d=ØVø<sP*<m<\Ó<†8>_>>84wˆ&ø>π>I>1.˚u˜"^2<Î1!fı5lç<<ƒ<<V˝<haw7>>>R*u 6SÇ>ÇiÅ.ˆ<<<¬e/<srÓ>>>>VF>>ÓRzŒ>-ˆFr¨¸-i`-.\+wU+µ+<<\Œ<˜IL<'m¨D<<<yVw>4>@>Z>>>*+.bi-<%<´?<<g<D2<¨>å†8>Î>VPZ>i.<<D¨◊<h7©<>>g>{ˆ>>SZTBc>%>---◊.ˇb+˝@AY'◊|+/$+<O<Î$<ø/3BWD<<Á<<>En„©>>>∫>pœ(4rΩ/¨}vƒU|q>∆&++Eœ∆V=.--<x<<<<<◊Œ>◊">m>fz>œ†a*Ó˛.m<qwB<<≈<Ø >r@|¬>Ï>RKçZ>>>≈ØπT9∫π>---ŒÂ}øƒ◊f`.‰+ˆhj+P‰F+<Ç<N<I7sÇ˚<<t7˙<ˆB<>>Ïa!J˜>@b>lk9>/ˆ>4?˚I¬+3+`˚+Ò!.˚-∂√*˚-˜†X|-!3<<L<7%&Ω%<u<<HMuJ>>¸>◊>.C~∫<<ç8)z|uRÅ:<©2ıGXq<>D>ƒ>>Ó7Ndi>>>´¨Ó-6--.∏+$#+j+<<<<C´<ŒÏ<vÒ<>K>>f}uPy†>>>>h-@3---%.ŒXO∑r7+!+\+ÁR+<Ï<Îj6Óxj<œ<<hnDc<<>\F>>¸I\>cx7.KÒ<Ç:˛ƒØ<!x<<V>Ω>>ÁxSˆ>>zœOlV>>‰F`-Í0-˛A4-.+_´√x)07Ô+œc+Â;<=G<<<øucW<m∏Ωµ\B˜B?8_¨Á1œ˝E%<<>>ŒÔ>Ø>>>>-eo„--J.++ç+&<<<˜<H<<U˝<\>´>2Í@>>.l<OWE<E∂<∆19{<>_>zT>*µ> ∫#t>>tO:VˆVcb|ß:>-∂ß--1F.ˇŒ++!+<I<70<v<T<Œ0<B<#"Í∆Zk!:>Tå&qj*i>ÅEÓpT>>Ø>Ò{Md>>'ı-\-ÓZ.GQ++<(Î<G<;<<R<˛kA<i>6†v>ˆD(Y>>.=¸j<<HE<Qˆ<f˛>x>IK´>>P>A„>K>¨r--T-‰.&+F++vC∂_‰(√^<0F|5π<<~=˚<t9Ò´W8<n=Pƒ<@BF<>>„>´:∏>2>/h>Árw>u-Á/.+<ı˜<zJ<åΩ<<^:Í<<>a>>ˆn>.Ô<<f<<råyr>ˆÁÍ3>mV>Ω*8>V&ÎUÎÁ\◊>>Nh∆=¸®q>PÂƒX-'-Rx∑!-v)Åµ!.¨Ôß+++Á<VÂ"QÅ∆<<˙øj\©Ku≈8o<<˜<<Â>O∑@>˙=2>Í¬>W'>>„7qøsøx>x.<<<*<ˇ<<\´ørW¨Qe<Ò>>®ˇˆ>`>Â‰.<<&&<¸&;∫U<>3x>>>J>>>--h1-V.+++`9<c<L:\\R<L<<´FÏÅ∑˙4Q<ø<$>>˜>>>Ø>dA>Ï+.-<<ˆ4Â<<b<<oz©<>"~'>"R>√>.<p∏<fe◊Wf<7œLƒLçH2<qy>Î◊>˙>>>>øˇ>¨¨-2\V-."ÁıIq≈N∫4+M`o˜ `¸+`<Ónaø%C<4<f}e:<<=<rBM<>>>8>Pøc(9Z>m>.´r<Ò<"<<Lˇ<<>Ï0>9l>>FØ~.E<<<Í<&µdÅ>|@>ˆ¨`>>>>>®--ˇåˇ˛9yø.+9∆j\+<<1a<<<C®r<&T<>>>u>>9Ω>+.ı}}„-<<<"∑<≈^R<<≈>A>)√&>>µ.nK<∫B<PÒ<G%BgÇ<´˙1cV>MAr2c¬>Ø>b˚WÍÍX>´}>‰ÎÍ˜∂Ø\>>ç!-v;-;.+˝;µ+<0<˛˙<<KbçJ)mAY^<∆<QœÂçl<Ô>µ//>>¨ 8c>7n7ˆc>>(¸+Øcw+\˚A.^X8-dq(-G<√ß∫Î<s<Ø}<†bI<<%>˜∫L>$>Zg>.<‰y\<<<>˛`O>;4>sµ#o}Ô63∑>>Ø'%_>>-∑(-∑{'Î@m.++X":˝<<<<eÔ<‰^1<<1>I‰UW˜3Ò>Î`K>>i¨H9>G√>yˆvp+77++‰ç.-A-ø-<Á<˛g\R¨$<*<)<<f>>>>D¨Z¸.*√<<y´M<<6œUN©våÍ#k>Ô>>>oŒP>>>W√-mµezB-^XåCT5.++˜x´<< <E<<WµÁn<<>>2˚˝>>√>s≈*'Ø>>-s4ZMsı3∏---.+ı+´+;7Á'WÂ/˜F®WCl˛+Mz/"<<Ô<<<<)∆πw˜<≈I~ww>>'$n>>8Y.<<\Çe<<IE>rŒ>(>>>>1´o>~--.ı+ +<r˚!®<<ÂW3<Î!√&<W/∑®V<a<O>$>>Ò~≈>>E>åQ∑†>I|-ıçrÓ˙-bh-.D++˚≈}ˆ˜©+nL∆<)vHLˆf©ø¸∂˝◊%_<< 9<ˆ"<4<∂<>k>¨>>A.¨*<Y<<øE∂fç<>>j>>˜ç6$>>A©å>˝µÒi-Kµdkh!i∏´˚b-Ô.+¨øJM+<¨<o´<<Ô´<<œÂ<>>>>>M√åÎ>>`tØ--9?Z.I+Dk:˚V+Y<¬ı<ø7<<v˙∂~<@uph<"<>> &>X@>˜ÔqiÒOK^.o<a<o<J<>ΩEÎ}>;UœLç*A>>>◊T/>h>N-Á-.˚d+ø†+Y<^<˙YŒ˜<!<oi˙<}L<ix7<√Åu>y>u>=>>L>˙)#¨ >-ƒb. +y~<q X<´xÏ®Î\9@N<j<K<R<d<´>Âµ>¸?√6ˆœ¬˝>\∑>=.n<Œ'∆muU)„)GoÒ<ku<<j?> >y>œˆ>>>>\--bÁ.i*+å+◊f<%<!ßCu<z<_´x_m<<<ƒ>bH†!>!>‰c>&†>˜!y9†>!2S>5.<<6<˙<˝e;<<<‰√Å>>yıx>>.<<<<59ˇ>9†HEÇ>ÒÓn˛9M;>k>>†cø´c∏>Î=açJ>u´G--∑.+Å+uI<^<=<<v<}Ω<<{ç>>>3∑y>>®V>F>aN8!Òß9+d.-<J◊e<´„Œ<ÎπF?\AŒMbÔ®<¨å<<ˇ<>>a#>&>.<<k∂z<Ωr<>>ˇ`>>>†Ac'>>-U˜.+$<◊wØwd:B<<2/n<<G<<%>*>egW>;{>'Q∂>>}&D1N.<<<ƒ1~<(Ø´<:≈Ø≈∫<}>>rc>ˆg®k>.´eV6˛∑<<<AU6<>¸>w>$˜>¨lq>ˆ>´∂>-®.+<πçˇgMß˚"Z<|¨<<ƒ<<QÅjƒ<%>3˛>>K>/=∑> _>+a.-8M BÍA´<k<∆!Ωø<˙'¬<<Ï¨q<m'=>U>T˝3N„ˇ◊∆9ƒÎxje>>'QÓ3^.<K<<Qb~<e>˝µ>4Ç>>@>V>Q>-UåvO.+<y<<e&ø◊<<øum<</CØVHYm`>cjå#Ï/s>Ø)>>>>++.18¬Òπ--<<´T<<x< <>>>ß>.<h:T<US<†4<‰∑>CÂb9>w¨s">>I>$Kr∏=6ƒ>J>ˆ-. Rø'+˛i0nÂ<<<i/å<<zÒ#i˙<ˆ<≈9l~=>˙˙h˜˚D6>ÓKD>Óv>1P>‰>++H+.m-a˙k-d-<◊<=y∏◊<<<<>3>>`˝‰>◊."1ÅbZ<<<Ô)e∫vfpC®¬<Z>~˜>9∂>∫RSÂ5T>>9>8>x-.}ålß+B<o´Í3W7<ÓŒ<k˚ç<<„<d<>>;˙:4>La>>=>F>ˆ-H-Ï(:Å{´ß-ç˜-.+Ó++Q6ÍM+<9q<„<<0<t∏T<<¸>◊NB>>l x>(∏∑`aa._<<<<M>˚>zID6>C>>y>>|-_\.+_<<Fˇ<Ω<<\t<Î<>MRÓ¨#pœz∆vA>>>E>>>-ÒH-Ø-L'{eO/.˛=+g++/{˛„~1#<<ÎZ<<˜SG\M{Ï<®I<Ô@<(@Œa´>>qÒ)´> >Í◊. Q<_vB<=Â/?Òq˜Ó<AJÅ t∆Z2fT<f(>jG©F>>@?6>cÅ>>8>-Á.Î+<0<e^"/mπÏ8C<<<<<2>Z>e¨∑>Ôc˛>>7¬¨>˙¸>ˆw8√gR-`ßh∫-ÅÏ˝7Ï.u++ß∫<<#<Â<<®<<Ó>>´|Bå>>Y.</^<e<®~)`<|e&&b˜π>g>>>>>`C>-ˆøAp.∑+b&l$<©#<P<<<Um{√Paıc<Z<\Ω>O>>>Ó>fÔ>8>-.;π*+<<r7<<</VÍ<´0¨a<>!>ug>>å.<Á<m∑:<<2u>D>1e>Ω>ç∏c>åÒ∂C&b>>~-.+iyp<πWÁ<r<5`T<<w`<<=N >>Q"?>>|˜T˝Ø>cÔ>HΩL†Kµjsa7å>∆ŒBP."©<<ÏH6Yq<<<PH<ƒ◊AluQF<>>o˜}>>5_.Î5<ŒGÁı<<„<>∆ÏÂX®>¨´Ó>S‰X\>>=>>-πå^.Òa=+<<A◊q<<<<©T=<√ıˇÎ>?v>>h¨Xr>7Ï´˛¸G>>>Óla¨+∫.-7<Ó~<$<0∏<5z<<∑<)Ò>cH∂ß>µ>$v>)K.∆<˜<<<j#Ω>>>πB¸>>>>.6d<¨<{T<t‰<Ç<Ç<<>>H>C>˜>>0.<g99<v~ÒELX˜´i<ˆÍ<µ!∂<∏<G˜>Tv>>jµ>#∂.Î<œg<ÔÓ∂ˇP<µ:Á˝WQBI<I>GÅ>>Ç˙>˜>>w>.åπ&˙<x<g$'<<◊N◊<¨<π<∫Ò*>†;lÁ>>ƒ˛ø>çI>>Z+.Gıˆ¸-<<<Òi†◊<√Í"<∆D5m<S>hG;>)$>>t¬.<<wIÍ∆<<Òb¨ˆr5>>>g˝>BW¨‰0˜>¬@>Nuap>nfz.p?\= L<gπ) <<@Ò<ı<å©<I˜<>>>>®>R>+uWΩ¬1Å+\V¸w.◊-(Á$-<H;e<<<<<r_>W>}4\π>MÍ˙∑*∆©/´`ÔÁ5>Oz5œ.˚<Ó?∆ı<;<SLY<˜>©>>>4>>Ç>pj.?<Ò<tΩ<dkµaK%πK<B9<∆x˜∏5}<<>j>>}>ˆD˝Î!7Øç_>>Ô+?)++;r¨.OÔ-´-#n?E-}<8©<<S<rsk3ˆ®<'3I}†#6<˝\>>:©6H>X>{Ou.2\<<¬h<<∏>>>>>>¨Axœq^>.∂v<˜_<ı\Ç<<Lg<<<~>>ZCG˙>f&=\>x>>˙Lq∫˜Âm>g\-pjß-Fx%(_VÏ-{g-m.!&+ı$I`R+g+0+ø<D<Í$œÂÇ=<<G<<k<Ò>>>µM>.<x<<V7<>ø>w˜∂T˝y>e>sŒn>>|LW>.©WI3<<9pUpn<<Jx<w<A◊<åi∂®>>Ó>ƒT¨>S>_>3>r-˜9-*Òy;-cJ.I+≈?¨+O+&F\Å<i<&<<<Â<<>@>>Å>.<<\jbu<1<eM>¨"pt>_>>mCπ˜>R∏>>q*.:<Î<\˛<v<<<g‰å<˝Òw`>P*D">h>ˇ>M¨>>0>m9˚6&ƒ-c-ç1©.e~5S˙©7++ß<<&<|'IDd<Z´<<Ï~<#>>K>≈øÎ>.t◊<ˆ<%ˇ6O3&{<n<∂>√>>%©sI>>>≈˜B≈>"dvp◊.<\h´w#<¨<LÒ<<<µˆ<>>\Y=>\>t>>HπS>-.´+}˛ <{mm<¸ E<<<oIe˜∑<˛z*NC<D©ˆΩN>9=>r>B>.Y˚∂<8<Á©<U7r@=e<ZåB>{Ô'>"}>m'4>>}>¸ˆw>.R≈Ï<A<<<<f<å<Å>>>>>>>.<åbÒ|W<^<*Mƒ<<=w2T<<1Su>åc˛>>0>DÒeE.<<*B<X82<&Â5∆ç>T>Á>>d>?rO8r^>>.<Î|<<ø<<wh<L<>x>˛˚u>jd>†FQ>>>+.-Ø˙S9zmN<<<<©t<PV<{<>>)li3Ï>>.<`BåÓ<ÍDƒ<<>Ω¬W4I˛å2N7¨>C{>ø√>¸>K>2*>+UßÏ.-p_<Ø<4VT<¬<l<<I<p>>>>>∫:>Ïnµ.<´˚;<∆%<<<<R>>7>∫>.&å<µH<<ß<>{>(>> "Di/Øx|>N>Î#åh! ^∑Í>+.-v<<O˙bnç˜<<<®¬vˆ<tFç<>>>ßr>Î>ØØ2a>©|"+œ.-<I<d<<<ß´1<\7>>`kµF{>`>.<Jq≈\<<\˛f<>ˆœj>e>G&>>4S>>+˛bA(?.-ˆGø\;<<3:w<e<(r<<<˝ı†H¸>>>Å>7>Rˆ˜Ô/´z>+dI0/~iE˙®+.ˆı-Z_ßåD-ˆˆeH∏Ó8b<<5iHa˛Í<<√^c<<6>>4p>L≈7®>2.<?≈<N<<FÁU^`>>i>pd>a≈ß1O√dÂd>>g>Cˇøz+.ÍsŒt-<<<<∂3≈ç?Í˛D∫<<{v=&<R/>BßÁÅÔ>>6X>y)*y¬Ç>>+å˜Ó++|aÍ)J)\u.---m∑<<®EX<<s<<Å>>>A>RKE.ˆ<m<#N¬AyF~<◊<>_$PJs>>i>Ó\>>Rˆ1>¸{+V.˜K-|<27w<t6<„Ω<<´Á<c<>˜>˛Ô8>M>umk=>>Âµb>-J-Ò-@TA-.+Ï+++≈◊<<<Áµz<09Ç<~3%∆¨< <◊Œ>>>>˙.Â˜<∑Åå<J<<>l*>>;µµ>>˚>~ç>+6i∫.\U-hÅµ7<<n˛<Ø<f=<<d"SoC6k%x<>;moç>†2†>n>CB>>>∂-GO-∑&-lΩi6.∆+F++µ¨9˙<N<<<<<<>>VÍ∫˜g‰>∆>◊.<<<π<>>Ô>?YQB11>≈9>o0≈ƒl`x>>X∂+'u.-œ<Ω≈åI¸‰<K≈=R7N<<<$u<z<q1K1>F\>>s>Hˇ√/ˆ>>ßC>-∆ß|´-`.FCj+∫Ô;+¨Ò<<<<Q¬<\<c_Ò_å!pB<˝q$>Ø1XI}>>‰>.Bj<∑}<Á'f<6rÍ*<>0>®>K>>R^y~ˆIBœdX¨>Ω>˚+∂√.Ç\I1v≈-OƒX˚<¨k|<u<ˇ@ıjÓ<<G<ˇ?<RΩ>>>>∫M>å∂3%m>2!t"@{>-.A´;˝l„¸:Iu˙hı+)∏6<0Òˆ˜\<$<^<<=L<jS˜Å∫<|>n>#>?>"q.ŒC<Å∆<W<Ø6&DœHj4~M5<Og;>QBÂV>>>ˇ>>>Ò7+.†-<<^<Y'i#2vøåJC<Jl<p<<>¸>>6>:w>∑h?`D>>d5√.cˇ<ˆ<hOuß˜<<jπ∫\<<fåfB?<˛†˝ıˇ>>>/>.<*_d<◊<e_<>">>>>5>J>ø∂ø˝+yç ç.N9∏∫-<∂<</<=<=l#8ø<?<>>øx$>sE>'>>ßS>e?X#+¸.Î¬d∆Ø-Í\<n˛<w<<˝zh<<4^<a@Ig_µ◊>^øF>˛>4Ó/ˆ>.n∆<5<˚"2Á<|@<>>πÁ%´>Ø∆ >p¸sv!>´v∂Ç|πÒ>{¸+^.W-s<<<å<<<>{¨˝>>>0>>.@øƒÓˇ<H<<<◊<∂P¬A<>Î>>d>O>>*k∆.<<<<Å<ƒ<mm.
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##TXvXTmvLtu2vmGTApTGMCSaVO2CiyTldX5INJplgMMnGAiTMPEcCtGykQ9ws6coCtBBaSEzJb0caBbwMCf5h/cD9hH1bH5yHO/decxJGqOqh9dZ6dc9EphdW5qKBpX//W3wfVHyk1XH0n4O/hTDelkR7j9ibLlBn4p@DP4U6rmgaV@nRpi3zpsJM/vNf/ynUYUXgf/lzhzbXqhfpMyVouWijBHerY89ipzoXgoRDDOIHfrFbR/h3XnykmsuFSvOvhHndbZ6Eet9fw@5/fv0lBvDDprlBoe6DHjMp@nK9Yh33LOPrNmHeiDFSx6NiRwwM4hvjLWzv3savPlO22HDeP7@OxKLwL0zufKawXhLTxpsQ9UKIeTPZ7BJDzcabOmya2hZfTx6vmew1k1QsxJwQBWWid0CsCOMRO8Qyht9fe8fnPEI9kBhSR6IWv1k279R5kRA5bsGmwGr/8An8NT2GdeSIj3Q3CS@2s8d2EubVR1r4RaN6sG0J43nqn4N/qXsRHDAee/75dY1LzBMB04mZf34ljWxXdZM6d8@SeSXwNlGoTrCIJn7K@j//8YvtMqzu31/xaxt@mFSn5q2Yypuq6aizlY0Zz2zIHvaWb0uoE7HVIgRMgPeIKSFmXEKsiXJSh@ZJp5ksVKeivci8hlFwaR82kxBiehvWzBGrQgybd2J6Ux2L6c@Uk0SutVdsZS3OK@tYgzHVw//9P/8thvBVXPSpjPEkRoxH45lgOrETxMp24FvjzWU8G29@4Q7WwiwC2zWe8vCu6phoEs4GIer6hPHilhK7c6nLdSmbpdyRUo7Lnq@nULGclrJe4k1ulW2QEps@1P63uswpraBFMt6oezU2RFSEC8jWOLjEntA1mZiX/Efdq@P3V3iPakllKKJOPCqjb3mM5@8DRFOZdIbUcbV5W/r1FMj7PsAdNEPvr07a5echSP@V85lCcIb1nWHkgKZJOSJlzdiSujQe8aa9Ahi3zXirnSs3b2Vc1oRJpcvykR3hxWqqr@tXZzRtp47PlF7lx3JOv57UqXqQsoIS5h2RH79fpsJaON9NQ2GhMqPrMO@O0DVtvEJrkhEz6R413iQbQKUQA/7AsDqWk@YNlkpUUNgyR7rcVme82VOiSLTFvM3Nz/t6wtqpb3gBGy@YI9I0JMWoymjq3LzW1JnxopsneZyVYlZIpyztkHik3yalTVJHaRW19qtDWIzqQ7pl/Sp20FFE0jKsqU7Wx7fy8X4qYxvlGy94rrrXPlLl2lihjjBBxNaayf2VDWGTVdNBr5TrEhYawKpXcnGfuoD5dbmDHUXxXHwjzbudryepDqXxFsMlE9RfNWqndnbE1xPZ9igHEaKNRDUjW5D7/jpgnlQs6BUxGzx@HRBS2s2krN2cgyH21Bl888@vc4nFzQ3idcHZj9TC0jS16vl4vPEyiqusZZzhr2LSKjec5q0TV493OoaMt0LzNuav1xHyf49NWYFk3vTKKjlLbXHaWqWxEOnmzSAcIc1r8xabkL0OTsauaPD9FW/929W72TdNCNZ7Alxc0Op2CamjRmpWaWrHfvSQ5LvYpnJfljrsuOnPsTDWbDzLljrj2TY2bTwStZF5MwwTNJN7v8ffpLJmUlcPs7XuTbe6kB8pKX2cOLgwl1ZHEAGNTRXqLKcvthcicn@kqUVEkA7qgd/W3Wb3RhHlH@n6vIK47OaYSRP1deK@IhfpeDV8VCnlwPsrYSmwR4KNdG@DOZENv472kdG6yph3tdq@uqyUfXIPN8EOvA@JnRlPM3gTR4YuJ4xH6@d9xu9tvOlIUvEQ4VWtqA66dEgP7rDZ7V14w1FgqpsQpubdCEJfyhAKSgfWsiFrpaz9eqqKt8CSzrW1/iLamqI6PB/XNUuXlP1d5l1wT90v9UqViqpMDItNeuT766ykIXVOebzw5NyiXigtp5tJ89ZBHF9LlbCOXq1198Mm6lRWjSL@jMddeNB4mpiX@XF1IsmHVd1GVZZig8ajebI630FYHFxqXnf0CwFraG01wD3AwVHM8ZEKcqZeaJ1ytRVWK1hUmdky@FZK/64PkSojsOpH@iONr1XWAeshj720bF7xY3UZMLI15o26hOWujeykFSScY5zcdY381cg80YDQGzXGgISUxm9Pz6B5DWSUHqJtGotREzIUuBXsqK0Vwo17NlHQdG2pXQtVabJ5CjVK9sq@QE60Q8pin2wi4wW7TKiLjxTZYS7a0GEshzqXcUbBP8u9TZszg3V@826o2TbYggCnLSxtopNwZ8uEuhjviJNYd8/psXhEk2uIo3YZnJ2Ucg1P21/vlKFieAJ7mubcp0FGJG3Kji2bJyr79ZTQdONtHGWqfRxlrDm6WZnPdsyIXeMZF5XhGyyoFf81V2Dfn6mvpz5SqfYO/CKGKuCDrx/KxmlGty5SqTqX5Qd2P16JK5DfqFDG70VdM6@ro0BML@fcuHSXSukMygYXUIZoyO3n3dGM8bSGRTLkaLrY6xRAmNIahn/GFRSW0hmiJfxPl/PWjxrZyfs7@VhtT7m6MK/Vw/eByqgspzFR6QLwvpecwrzFAq4K1VlgA7cxOMztyLa9fkY@KRnjpLqkehv8NzpGyzOl5EVkUQ/RyNKMui9XaSwILh36egIdkSojZR8CzbyOyPpqrCQ5@JHaxU976pxApDskUdWSbXYvEBon4/EjZTyZt4AGKoKDbWtyJWHetm3KKjJPzJM9MKe/9rH9dTwQyIDQr@xcKZ40bxEE//FLbI3Dgbo23qMyds7nXMav6@XA6Aji1TzJ6RySVDCzSbv2urEp8LPvgx6nytS0uak@gbwDDGs6uEaZ5VJA2S176lJOyek@5kL/9Z8ADJWVpeRn/FgqxTNlSO7DTwiTa1JZROcGftVjG@8hMbPi1rWF91eXNF4QzSo9ZzxvoYAhoC5L/IjAAOBvEK@th2fUJYwNCPlI1anDcFFuGU0XIFcG8AMzGdQB1A8lQBOHlI1Y1AQQCiFT@ZOUm7Tui@pAeokS7oRNsJnr2A8E4dV5wAy4MbtvPPkYP10gLICLSlywwKXt11@7Vg7hcjNZoIUsTDR5u8BNP4OS6ydEdBnsAFGuX0cmr3aatzDFqqRCpsrYhQ@bJxcDAJ6oUsLd2T4yIUb1qhywkkVYrqa61njrAXVSl@o8H6ixRT2RWuqupjCerbL@KNuRYz5n0YOvivp8IXVmJueQMfVyL1a@IB2VAA7qX6FJXFUYAtp1qsxkawyl4TFsZGuXebW7e@qiYamZSuEQuJQ6qFr45oVHr9C00UCeRHmR61zJcpAZLB/GJIoYV5DIKFF/v/E2Nc6YKloLVkvM25om88a8NR51rVgCBcMN6v77wNnEkYXYkKhyMblVtsnZfO6fLqdEEafDZyrABkPsDEjyDJl3E5Mr7WM2hDHRJBm/e2kVZVDMFE8L3aepw91tB6rgucoktrk8g6ohUK5KjLcJLMwN47@/tuA2@FTdD8GAF2K@wK@btyBLGpMrzzpuRolrwoLqzZPc1gLpi@7Y85fbUCrH26ipyNpjcpv3WYfNe5zrdr2sU6Xrg@ZVvgwaWRQVDvfiTeOtaICLaU8O0Wwn1fQT5YtlWwHIcjYumnMGGnRnm6Yhd@8ajedadS8t6IMLmPIBB2jX1S66oSyAgp0iKBz65l6Vo81M1oBW/fqrY2WxaokXnruvjoysxvFzyzFaJ3tXq8BfGamQz/17W1jQoR0kCN@xrqhHjcF@1CEsC3aw0oogPCdvA5Wos4FqDwHoB3q@D7CGeGhmAOxxX@hOTQtbFGmnkHni9PJcFVUDP9lLAJs7cgZsMUqQugTiI//T6vDrqVkUiTEjCxXDfu6Q9UylNhIoHDEPEyjk6ilF8J5@PfaRnghy4NZ4ZPG28cZCCNbA47GlW@rGyyIqPcLpKMCpdeboxtNWUXV3k/E0sg86g6glI4tNh1SmPO40kz6POuRKOQRRcDQR2APeBLSvpzlGerxarM@8vwJd7bIfaTWFpL4rnZjOk1A3NZLFVxcIMzm7FtkORrbfvIa5FppW5CZzHFA2dQbmvMq0ZqsWKtVrSejQIJa2JJe8Mt@Pqo9tV8oeKTc548pyvg/amKbg7UXN7A0UycGQx7@MoMQujSzt5WkwQkidfD2VY606zGRe56pUggsTQMF4KVTpCWevA/z2@6CYjQQsDO80Gm/wCmAJeMYrAgdJtpNu94zKTmlpCCpBuv/6qwWPJ/8okOX7AAQBIs5464RObNfzm9imMoZA/D4wHkfqpURVXSFvH1gDIub7oIS@D2C7cQBXkZTtEHNjss7IlsxJptgt1KHObf6uiDr8PohTN1w3yHj/K6m3g4xn1UNCnVRMSWbaXKlr8Bt1XrBbhV8@tjMbYRS2/lsRbmhpXWvgBUnEHVXwDrbViZ26QcKebFy8geYnzZvMYGKQHRbqsWb/SDcuEwVQvEYatj3FuKzcvCF9k5PmD8kUDvJEPRi/VSa6z9SPJRRIxo6XaIqKhbpg2ehrVWk7tPNehw7FkzCvgCvpOMiEbAuGOdRInbugAlHwb2HWYqJRipK/KqROEYJMZAQCZlRrgUegw57komyeh2lzELYv@G1IpSa4F/Ai6yZVJm6RkZVKUIkHmkU27aH2/@kPSlnOLsav/6yqt7w4yS@ON4mgXxjZdRaQ25rxvIr7o6CIYERMMCA92UqD6sjkWGPpJRnDreqMEndV4JTN7687@7jQidty6kv4kpgchtbOWpoYlyEr1ifM272qaXfYY94AKUDcjRfgJgomBVoRldtU28dPBamzCUQUat9dgfFYoGlRMwl55QpoMeNlZ8t4HpOIgHO5Z1VC2ucw3RgBf7pzIEnBsURszQGPN8Zlg1w0r4KzXY7hUnU@BjSXct6v0lu7nymsNZtAwSskm/Ho8qNUTulybKZ5E5scaZHQTXBFBSyAm/C6k6WJOuqctI@vD2BPMKR5C5KVXMOC5yHokrRVn9exWwUF5t5oaCxgYsg5KfYcg2JV3bNxcR9i0LyT8OFbmZRuSfZBjrwU8vgPF1GI4n7B3QjjWd9Wl7ulm1sJ41Gb1EBq6uV8m7QpNigM96wy1Yx@sNazgi74C4hzkk@7ee2w9pgum2WBXFyXHEhlMM46IKFLiMH99sRkg/Em1ozHNV2DR685TechCs2TNnXYZtUNFj/X8MQ8yjX3owY@U9As6wBVgDFUrfEWlTvYhZR1kti/tXXmXdTa7veB/pEa4IZLRoY3bXW2gOxbfn/FRcbveTCcj3R5EAwgQLlO8CjyFanDWS5rzLIfO@1h86Y0KITxUgG0ytdKl73LltD/lxZhQqbJyIC6bwCNZE0rd3mtoOvg6gWwP4DFm1tNE4GP1LhWpoW0HE2d6iLc74OQyRWib2vQAekzOCq5NxJq3m2YsBQoCo/FALzcQ@wNe0GpuiD4rqfbWSgnCgIExWKRMUfxhMrCGnvkUofCA7OgnOmlvZr2kQLFRjK@5QKRtuUWUjRKEFF/IpaqQJyZPMciY4xLmgbGAuDrD2IbR4NQLtxrU5nKoplQqRzvAc3zo1aB9nHOTGOzwLfZWQ5rnTNSIntgkeG9OGysjq3qTolZYd6JApuZFHpU09Y@UliNX5aFmyeRwbkb5VHJbPbIvP16mu2WC2E7kg2a/Ja3pY6ZOwMJaL/VyDorWvzDpRr249vQB6aFepgH7/KCHUs/sxkswdU5xuFovJVQuJoAF3/m@YMWteKq0r082@z6TH2kFXIUcPwsrdCA20d7FlfAFg@d2PEMe04IUTmKcK/R67uMN1@gUVOXTjfY03kEAqutENgzhLiG2SZKpWvcvPIy6i5AQZX3Y73DsA1tgVu0lpOmTnTLkA@jWMMWSyI5OQFERL7hG/zMx/zlI43AUZlCBM75OnCaJfi18bJnQaYubW2FkLa@j3RxRw68GZZe8zbfeGoBeQdXA21AnE02qNMprixxIdRJldBtGvAx6@NMmmw3b1nBIafW5Qwk7bWT8liJXxpvrEKomFzGM@lrMNVmldwGffvdKKcaIQhAT0FwF4zfTPLv88Av9DY/noSVBeskr30LBSkjW4ki7tEOarTTamHVyhwXHHXEdX5rd7gMVV/gJ@at37wS76/zoKYenVlATKW6Z7XPlE8d97aXdWkNoBQy0l3NfBmqrhb@T4@NmckWVo35iPjQ6FynSuHOVZhve6rCZWGYHJcJ2QIb9oCxc/Oz2mplddOYZUF3MektHtwA2HYp7iIDqh9XemtQ3COlZjLKlQM@LAutGS8j09SFLZs3CYu8HMfIttlLmvEErTv@AcvA7xq@7dHV6bCYiJs3U0y1CkUz6IuMQL9BeeEaKARq2kGxYV/CQeq4udrFJecZ8mspsmyRd3W/UzePMn1eHRtnCLYy2lP2E7WSNs2r74P6RTj6pBsUtIbbvxuU0@/@TDX2kba0U2TeaktavbasO63TB@N3HNu0UlHUdqhT2dKKiP1Izch1FG0g2lsTx/7@mJSfqVbZYAcvxdu6rNfOgnQDr5D7EZfeZ96t2we12s4NpOo08GNmn3s@rHRXaHeXEksL0NWfKVYz934mfCA1jaiNX09ylbt5kmwDTBNUppSmjLcaBJi6zA2QxeyvqdbyjAcJYuHUmTptcml9eqNoC4hylRHAjPU9pu7gFicyBw8oKP/EY6E@AC/ILmTotRvours9YFnNhR9ykSoRlXE9Ydc0z6g6bAejqWUA@PXHjtyyOh5AgDN1gnva8xywJ0ONLgf2B72wvyNQELaYpAfvcAzVs2DNiZeGiLxarvGy4QUIHKM66UJsCATyitUvWR2M1nL7VNqBQ5lxtsjR@kChOmnip0OFUOwz5Whyd1JtDYVqEgAY7kHoxpt5o840ldHmjLe599fYmLpQmd0GeHDTDdL6ok5UOlDJhSYvgrLsWujba4dP31@N3zNQk8wbij5TI3PF5m1zguKjZfyuOLYDCQhaNcaS2zxZzrHAmOv3I1Dozym/tgcl9ad3N6j5NYaBc11Md4mNkbqYqBoRVpiUcYAY2VCzOmpbc3Fcwy41SMfTcW74/cHFmBluCQPVk8q4h6nwM6VOIaHYn@aVLvrGREKdbqusSHBfHo5bDqiHDRlDpPTJJquTWE9x86qNOww66ya2PesfoLK6pJhjie2dz2JGiAZOLyiqlrpEk9xu5iKbARkgPlgC5duhkUU8uE1rx@VLqOgT6rhUbEJTcGNS3Udrp9ekOoUKMH7XmndDePcgw9cad5zugKSj0XmVqQH4AlQ/0l1jwTUaXxrTd7eN35MzdvNkQfaZt75@@cXaNz1bChLjc@HVeCIg4@cg4Nf1RqN528EdwbYZ80SrbdXrhIjPoSZP1pnXbbyFFVwV8korKFEo8qiBZWiA24jqWG@bQ@Crs4X8BhFXab7Kh7DCO8PDA4jK@2J13BQnbgN2zupmct/qvRhPXdMz/vyy3PUmP7ebuXdWjBu/DxrL4yBP1Gt1jm315eQEhqx1EJKRij9Ta7PV2kLpsjrSejXk2XGJ9v6aCHBZPIU/RMnXk3ki3CDYgBPRVwDeWhytVJf1EKL7rKqYQb1Jf6FsYfbFrjj4V37BZ6rfDW108Dc2NskHKyMB4@39dVQ9qNM2lMSUnu@GJQotK5jJOFsR8drXiQvOP1O1Neowx4LN5Baqv3nLVHEHyPIB5E5aQQLyQsMgapO0o621ah5N61ZHeuFQtbLOa/LxzybXmyu7WEGiVHK73HhsKimTDnVs50jbRl0DfjXB2cRNwa@nceJe5AariT9U1tcic/zqZPkjPYXSUhRUZ5zWx8zRzCvjqQhFBgFsvMzKHihIsps3Q1QG0ptt6TSeKyz0Rv6em7eTFDZvcW9T2wp9pEIN3Jqx53B5nFT3qJpx7iX0Wt3jps/Uht4tRPNyGQMENqFSQdBTPlq9HZG5RZ6hPsBMmYO5enpFzu5HGANQXLktmEEN4wOtSwpxf60MdtBrJzXrNG28ARIaGDW0ls@h00Y@2tbV4YzcG/UiuYveX11gdR/pObiwIepfUxdFjdRBA19P3R4/csPNVGkRVIOpCViNVtWtbegQBX2Ce73qqHdVqpNQedCjLodVVm5AvIdBzNJspCoOgqrybTNpR14jJnzk0s3rqHmbC/6kzlw5wL6KZT5LZIAfxu7mp7e56djviNrcA@oEq1pAbpjsfON51ik3InzagxhoYYLQv4cNayAJEWY82sKUhqVtD6EYIsqgoFC0fJ2yMIwI4Kbf8DaVUz2N436H0GcWNIgS4w1kJiSbSsELgCvWqtUZDfeO0wKc2YRohPSerwSDZj0UY5E5MD7oDVABJzufd5gnM2C79Q1jhRYJc@YL2YPd5cOBzjLvSJO02uLUvMItjicLkP@itY90UXnk68lpPO5vfaaG4uucqHbEAKNsctjDTaAdqymFp2Kb@DuXwjS3B4zCKqcdKm3e6GG5vu212BgItY0i9XGutufU36EeeJ8cTZffB4PVeCccoFkl92hfZT@ZSs1N6dzXMZMI0/lF0YtvWgT8ierrq9xQJ6hscrPSvEKueq2mwHQOCCXVz9DyUjU5YYtygJsPvKFMTJkgu6kc@FezOsbXDnxlEXo8fDSu5aCwdMrKAvvXU4GMgpt0RaENOYRBH/TGhMWQ1UNV8V482q@Oa6TxVPr@2joK0djEXBTuruwOLlgIaDxyTqY1Nx8j/DoX@XlikRFWNiJNscFzuQVZgDimuf1o7y5XevyZ1@rLYIACSMLRHuR6pFLkCD/iuF9wQVVni26V3lnk3q@cX2kKwGf@Fl6iz0@BnUq9g/sPJzXmDcrdpcyBc4b5VBcCYmeAw2LvI92zPMyU5O@WKWi9Es28aShHCZs03mCPneKSSnUhPtIBoY5qpcc648lGAyOSG81fT8ZvP9i9t65q0nhUhy4og7vmAq6L2NAFZzf@aLOrTAq0dp1HF4SdYfRWtiG/kTt@Lsul6rQeNXVZ9ow0y2YWlIgmV3VMIhf3BskBELLB1HmbRJs9NcNmcjgwg0pRw8dER@pe01wtCOgPKOwcwQdWPllZIrfkIMxaIr0yL5fZZHJ8KaeGBlXGvr7oWGCCq9Jrg8SLVKlYF7RX4fsrKIZKj@utfajEReoMGhI41A@9vtQAycRidAvypaloDMv1GNlFhEQzKm1SzgFudsjXwW2UXmpgxETdeoxo2iD3gXW7aBFiC0z7aBLfFsG0E7KkJV7B9D/hQcxuVgOt3kaq5IqnF8BS722x6PW/YJ8amJpKyTkPr0W2KapB/emCO6K3cg@cMcNFfqIGXEuyjjeTK@AnIFxzIEJgaBHujhxy8J2WUZjd76iiYbs6GwK1POQSTNQ9z4e3RtZ4WadedfSZGtUKtf4dBFyOtoUqbvzO0eHhC@gXnpqRUI25fTypk@QKo7KLfuOpI4rErVq1vMuKm8O1nswrTyl4GDJ8pNDaUOW6ym6o7A7tWEedfNYk/Sjn2ciI8dg3C23MZ5vmCaJzikUZjytIux2MzF6LIBiSVLaDqOIejabNu7RhpltT1TIgO2v8/n7urhpvLeqcV/eHeVXex0db@VbdtPpo8HewgbjpwH2kZDnr8RkpV/cYLXMThZTbb9FFnY9Qz@XcLAw0MicrP9KdnykU/bZSub4LuGW7cduN@Z95QtzG1Er9w5qeqw7fX33cLu/Gess5IrumVs1b25SRFVNcC6dVtqBRlsu5/dka64DVIyPeLmbyVbB@NlBUPQ7UBOOOcKcgFxjERsKaS6h6mahFXSb0ZqtUSrvxOwj2H6/nnt/jlMWdjRdNM09UBja8qd5VWV0ASZOLfqANn5EBcF4i0j7I74sSVQMOhP7@ur/PWcrcg/sDfMjcb2E0NVAx7AHtZfzWV5it/eWVvVhXa4E3BNiFLrhyBYapqyFSGrBkE82Y1yPqVJ2OInj3GVpYMHFX9khd@mGvBwRVrVarowLVctkrYSOYN8Bs2TGjHtqLww1j@NEEw4DsgwQ6Ug/LkuXeb6cT63i0VQWocqXSTIKIFsGq6jKwLfzmdYM@MVqlBdeLtFbrHOuej@zO5AbqzD4X9xmflAVk9Yc7KZ/GQ/AylrfLPVCCNO6h2nLaMH7nre6rC3eZNX2hLgsLJq0T6T@K@K9YoTqrDyPoRnNrrAaenEWy4SkT4CYu8uGroRHQQMSxOpsCnC8Yj23V1MoxtWsmt9ZEZSUPdf2tHrifrrIal1rzJuTvNx7zkRDFyFx2I8r4uJHVHSxk5a7x1iWl@yM91G08bamMOs1b4u4PEeRrLx9O4TItbPye3fNqE6Mq0zhYgTWatztMAm082zUC5X64wuBcal7zEBSvaAMedhQyUGsb5eNdG@@v2PU5HxhBMArjTdRWqsPCEXXkNG9bjJeRxmXzRnTtOXOtE0L8QWwkvw@2kfN4ki@xvQ0czV9BJI/p3Ow6mYUmaKYIyAA38MhlvK1SAo/H021CRszrHO4vqaORMhSzHA40OeJk9fcyDCHfAy8Bnq3mBjWD6/CRO5dGX1zj@TIwK/OKW8Iz85rO83rXuHKfR02MJ7HSyfFTvNXWaSbnIPuyRpbbd3fI3IJJGKUa6Z@LNLSa8UsIKwsgGgB0DjnGdY5LEX40B7JHtMgQoh7cWFADa0huvf9WqQWtAym4NJ@zwDNEb@b1jKYudAGwzLZ3CW4/rrIH1AX/zaH8c5bYxeGZ4TGoqU0@oauuG9d9ommpxrweFmPgjdCOKgspsGVeYRUJWR9dmwcUENnsNFrPS7lYX1Cpno4JfRWGWpXtEsjebDH/faodAlypB0cDWWc4g05oz27UDQ1UJygsko63TAC7xyB/b2WOXF1A@u13yoWdSit1jqO0C3jwEHUC5orzkHSkfaZmdJvYTch1G3eAd0DnX9SZv7q@Wy7KDhTKIB93qSMUbCNbxy0PM/mRNp4RbX5OJo@@gppcCLeEo0PFwJvi1lUgyRKo1WId2fBG7i2yffyaNqMO9QWHUBnBrA@0N0fdN0blngQ12Znks08wrJk2PlenHEaZANk5NMzbnN1q/iKndIAqdAtg3ZIJ4d2s1V05@NvaINHu@@vO/zSvKqqB4XxXWzMz@BRQGuDZVYu4YL0SQPC8BfjM4tc5B4k680wDqChqvLXyiN8fOg9fRn0wqQc@k/tckmPcACNGkV3i0EJIUwtNd1fl4Pn31SKICtSOvc3CaDycBKZ29n3QUudv@Eh1zSBiXhA@3AcF@hNN55Gd17qEcNiDxo5I7rlP/bTVGwIortqQeauLfObe2@pyO1jjtcYXS50r1gRPATloNjRCtTEq7LPU/L69ydWtW4Z0QTZyg1XWWOz7Z@hV7hNFAqgsIeNlievR7LDbmijALQ1Dbj7dpW3KR2U1HpfXua/LpPGINOMF/ISPzsyTUJe6N69zx2UcqWBJpj5Lmy7iywIqA20CUXJ6ODpsk8TFclrXqrpsXnXagOUscQ3I@ULywoOFVnPk3Hhcl@FCDw3RoHlX1s3S@QR7xoXVPHe8szgLDOpT6bIJHUEp@2YSctbKViqHbyGmhqkPxlKZrR4scxcADqnHiompLeLK2Qhd2DYWnqLAosrkqXPnBqpAMVlH3bqrCsI59X1gnXe/DfLMrE1a03o8klQzKIcGuNSU/8TZH9Sojmaqadt43MgliMn8jghPKbgRu@2wmKbb@lW2UJg3CyUrTEXkgpNdvqdSeQuWiGFcrV5OeJCF5tU8T0awPndDWnQ04a8tcvVy8GNpbUIPa9Pm1ZIW1KzDV88uDxPyxoD6ZYAaYB@uZP2X61LHM@PMIS6KZ@Hqrbm1Rm6mynFKwJ/V7Eb8uH9AHVWAJFeDmexo@r7KLIMCehnTwCZHKsFmELZY0BLPXVlHF8AAolrzqqacOsFGPQh5bLNNU@dFNeo4hhvvNQTGLSoM9z/63OoUOFm9bt0rSyQfHQ5y55TX2e0lWrbtUBFv5NcfU9PT@iTvposPE/Z8MEMj0pj7EpN@aBYpW5ArnHv@TSSTpK5@lTYe8yBc97hBw3DYzMRRpbCgS62zMDbb49TNG48ICeGMWa3ohCsPZjkbZyI70OrvivHZ5YuPB1BkUf1Hapo5/rpKFeNfG6gtm9PWJye3vNKDOlmnUutA57RsaFfHtk0WHqVzg3KuiBZb@RSE6uvcFGD4qcI6DnV1BgIkZydynWFkzHlVo6WfS6H4Z61RZ1T5AGdJpfGMCmVewTBmcruK@3L92pS6n@dROXWszs27SnWuR8HP7y1dmsejYtKqrmkWoHEvd11Qlp0TEpDzkiiekvFZu32Gj1soZJWlqUZuTahswxo06h9ixr6cD02bZx0TDIVjeGnv9PtrQI5LP2hjD4d9mubAQ7AXvfb7wAGOGeEGlnMY5NR4KzEepyXQOYrHq4zOTCfMZ1XYYBQS2TXLYlQ9wLsB/J4PO44a7TMEhqCLhd01YMgIbonIiimExPYUmHK3jagvtw4uN2@R/mAuAby@7eupE0mHUry4MV2JfcLsHylvr55rDf@ct7nH1rGq3jZp9RAalqN9rK/Ayvetol8xCT9UoDa1Mnn/iWOyxiHU0ajxwuz@DTsdQPqM@jmoSeMjqgldpaY92HMDHrputdGeBj1cPyHOTlDd67Yg4Y3H0QhV8jmeeWNkWy2jLU8bjwJu0jXOoYTMlyWsNir2rO6/LAZ7DLRZ6pZbcPlbVNyhM5uxZvcW86yRye8DL4KBJwPcQSYasUEkDx/TnPD/rYmYRqtdWKLLUHW13EqoVHPnKLjR2wIfL5/yoMGP2j6XrbhwEKtdxOvyrEJ3BJOAsYQQ@Hw6fmSe9OKGGnVo3o30eX3SR60cxeoEKojfss2W1FXm@8AO4NqRofxCqw/UzQiE5XETkifoHFywapd5FOgzZd5w9/zBRzQu9FZYLWlkrS5gaoFPfnluDrX6NJfLQFNFWA7QfGstFYOEbRrPKF3bPkvb8w0zxqOZjPBcSgh8wws1CWOUcHF6rqfu6PQarczt6Wt1fo@tU4a@D4ptUtaDfTDTyiBMfLDtj3yifhLRka8n4xkoKfzDRnZbx1K0InWYr8m22lkrRSOTNEL75X4kTxfkDWjaHw4eIHlyGm9TsNlhBfXsVXykQbngYrChJN5UKwc6xyQvij1YzuajtUW9joXeJoAruGT8nu4o@D7okF5rqnSH1cp5xT78CQa6z90HRP1ZTqW6VA88e3Ih6oqFqI0Yj3qPutCMNy1vpa5Z25dVHPoDMrKxVGbyWEthmW@fj5nBhe4QwzXGk7uNRinWE9VL/dyqnOfYO/85DDceG3Y@0usThKg72sKCJ2EnP4dVZwh7T8Bfja1w/Jzd4yeQKPOqc53P8m7VUZhCfm1tETDfslNQNDmszrVYSAvrOXZIinzfVD@wtgQclGf6TvMtdXfisRjKkiX@EfBdKKXcqqqUfLiybUlHJPsuzdLGRwrqIt45Aj7yNOIrk7J6bWgNDKd9R25beQhv8vwnz0hZZ36DgM0BmkQBjGjmbbXmUKndWi3QDr6N0lqHPOwR9ha/OpYLfCZmoSbV//QKjplx@RdnotIlZ7tgldy1TW4Qhxu/D@DEfste6w69hquN37wB9eMheoi7DI8@pbanqNfRlAv2DXrZxeOmfNxvXrvtnyktgDroMp702UTFALfpKxm6JdYQL/Q1BeW4pRvOEzz01fFz@g9E0TetsaqkLDBP3D1l9phckT/F@pqowHja8P10UHmyBqIpN7i1Zs23@@eNt20emZWdPACBTMYzwLPHPOSnTWDF98EA8TC42DdvbDIWDqME27jLsOqbZQf8AY265@hulE3Gk5n8euqmag9FyEv6GFQXUKQK6I6QG6qM1Htm5bjKeCmmLgopd5/ChTBnOYevkUXxIr2ft3MuGziP5uT/N4TB8xmZGZWKj4BKO7qYL3q2SwH@roEoKoRVCUuoSaVmm@EZh1eOVpVKO0gKg/UDDRLDSpDqIj1VkQnraWfxnw/xZAEW87JTIlrNG/M6SotBBqKWvp@BYp6hGqjeC@PS7h8g35S9wzIGGxUvL5Spc37YFEooKrs6beKFESPESLmPp4luVKa0uxIObowRDz1dMzfuoFIHf37tHnVZW5vkmevy4UE@4lvmk7K1/znp/KuG1PmK8VvnXsp1LWd9AS@hH0Xf6rvrdljI@N3GJ4OSYqykbblNIIqXO3HqhhjJU5n5HBuP1KpT3gyisMe8mllhnmWd7RjPW3D3ZoulZEFVI3xeAAS5LJ0GEsVzBWBKw5KC1me3jDeX9FeCDQCMWmI0hZ23cz@Lx1fMmzlJrOoWkYytdmDYAOxn3sw0FNXp4A6tKuuHyiqr2QbJKOKDWPPu/ZWFlVWr4OdK6meBri6Ak3skgr4SZ2KhGQnwwoPa76/a@CQslmnCw8zkbBvPpKarZiDRFtqmYedTa/h9IgBRh5evUScWVolkL9VlnfVhG5BAdTg0AWW0QGtBmrZmbF38qb@gOgrygUgjf/ZhT@jqFGiyqf3P6WYZX/hQByi/abIIVGzLY5f9TvJiOYdgWBdE7lHaLXbsQgGc8MhyhomeEPFpdVrcXuyP6pqmhS19ZLw0j0q5IX8Cu4H6O5r5RCgs87qN54bdloRF0Gkyv7d9gxeq0oBk2MWFuImJYd287dDisrRyW266mY0wp@UPT8qA5GILO1xUURdFw0sesgT3DGntoLVa/WADM2v@gBmLOIv8Iy9/78mSasB3oqyAa9QjNMvPEQ0xduvqiBs4CJ9jRFo7QnvZARJv/ObJbDDtBH8O071g0YK/dP@QNs8tYfA8iGSO6jngdzB3YLXRvVSwI6k2vPozq1DKMnyFGr1WnB9prT2sle3a8tfTgpv5DHfF8ZbHajAGK@2YtgxzSUcpCVli5Vfy5wM6kgmE9SGWurE@r8vFIFdNqyX45zO1PIUaNMqfPy2EEz7S0ADszYyP54//lh34xtNfyW/I5w7CuqvDRS1@Hk9p49Goaz4WQlo0cpsvqe7jqKJTekvjIlM0dcGfPrVAU/Yhd/0yMKlSkyqTs8ZTGOv5SCTXqG/fOkQh3bvIhtyH0QvnpDuiTh0SiIUA7YCDJ3YTZtLn/UgHR4EVYHHmtfg5edLVid/n4g/3aD2fqVFwBuNxKS6jEP/176@LfLreiq/rZL/F/RgXuvjsD3FbEKbSnM3c@hjwG5q51rxb5lO7bI0vCsX4/iqKkUNuWaJSnHd@cM0JoGqnXBywznqtD9zKOPyUR3WUu65/pBrlT29/BM5125s@0m2L5YmuCtkTqqU@rzoapp95P1KpSqFbU4V45ljhQl7pFqpUpr1Rti/LNWv@G0lDNds80DFfN9UEcK7g3Qag05APfIbXE1X3DFOL3wdYCDBmTmXmvHWSxdifDB7Wm5xckHXpmAxamTM7KYk/SEgVkNEMuDzOeCd21YNNPejd1ZZe/Ev7@XycU3qkZzmvCjWgjkMou5NPG81UyC4foNm60TxhZMF2jecgu/9SU6d@K7S3Gb32wIvKJ@R0vS80aU2W0YTKtvAoW7lKc@DoK2yrCmle55YiQ@M8Fwx1cFjAvbBLHmWgNSO7sZUDEbbFKz2J49cpihlZMaGPaEAJq0JlOPpj/IEBazic9Ho@8lRpmKrt50iVt9ML/JDWByiDLMAcSzzPbX3m9lhaA04yHNb//e//Bw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), posted by [emanresuA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247382/78850)

```
:+1_#_@#-d',:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/30rbMF453kFZN0Vdx@r/fwA)

Also works in Quadrefunge-97/Quintefunge-97

Comment: Funny thing is, got notified of this because of my bounty.

Answer (score 2):

## [Unsure](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/unsure), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247422/107262) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)

```
UMMMMM PLEASE START THE PROGRAM
UHHHH HIDE ALL ERRRRR
UHHH, PLEASE SET VARIABLE n TO 99
DISABLE ERRRR FOR ABOVE LINE
UM PRESET VARIABLE y TO 0
START A LOOP
HEH YOU BETTER START WORKING
WHAT IN THE WORLD
BUT ANYWAY, INCREASE y BY 1
UM YOU ALSO HAVE TO PRINT y
YEAH CHECK CONDITION y IS GREATER THAN n
ERR IF y IS GREATER THAN 100
SO IF THAT CONDITION IS TRUE, THEN, UH, EXECUTE THIS
OKAY UM TERMINATE THE LOOP
IF ERR OR CONDITION NOT TRUE, THEN
DO NOTHING
CLOSE IF
CLOSE LOOP
NOW PLEASE WAIT FOR THE PROGRAM TO TERMINATE
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@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)

The capitalization threw me off at first but this instantly came to mind :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), [posted by Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247431/100664)

```
00000000: e001 2200 875d 0018 8802 a848 1ea2 618e  .."..].....H..a.
00000010: ba58 e8d8 b9db 6604 e1a3 f1a8 dbcc 8053  .X....f........S
00000020: 0835 e444 539b a0f4 0369 0d1d a219 f0b5  .5.DS....i......
00000030: 2178 ae46 89df b43b 9f4a 6e6d dcde 8ec4  !x.F...;.Jnm....
00000040: e2fe 95dc e75e dbfb f737 1dc2 aa77 8c3c  .....^...7...w.<
00000050: 04d4 fae0 1991 c8ba 7a0a ed70 4a78 76ab  ........z..pJxv.
00000060: 7cd9 839d 35f6 2730 8893 ecd3 89b1 350b  |...5.'0......5.
00000070: 7425 b77c 630d 0b2e 73f3 4fb3 93d8 ba29  t%.|c...s.O....)
00000080: 8e07 d6f4 7549 fadc 41a5 3d36 8a00 00    ....uI..A.=6...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZJLi1UxEIT3/opSEHHTJOk8Oj4WgojOxsVs3IzQeYngiKBXB5n/fu1wz4BFsjgc6qO7Ku3U2rf55XR7PrtDLzCd8wjBOUhJA/YlEHEBKlHgpwZkLxMgekJ0Q1vviZQeXQjeGE2TYMoQtDoacnYR0ytjeRWM1jvEJTbGp21fdOj6YARjOOGEGWNE4tqgbkU4zhVu@AENvmK5loyR6O31dn@9QA4GGyP4ItAZM6SOhRa5oa6oyDMPjD4mZPYIPL6jd2Z9SVffb/9jxJ1HWBM1jY5Z0rThV8MqXOBHt1C0FEjnvvMwfbZb7P6hVwcj7V3iiFg6HXytHl2aoqhTzFEcotqUJWs7GKa/RD@u7n4/zJGNUfqoEK4DnFZGKGwNSWXMPtj2a95@OGPcmz/RM3chpQdG2YwYElopHZmdddvCROHFiKsxKu/CNFTg11O67@b@SR835PnBEGPIdAUjWxslRetALZnoNYEHW85qD8cOLrucPhC9odd5R3o@/wM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155042/65326) by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

```
{{iow}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f@/ujozv7y29v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), [posted](/a/155061) by [wvdz](/u/77882)

```java
\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006c\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0063\u006c\u0061\u0073\u0073\u0020\u0058\u0020\u007b\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006c\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0076\u006f\u0069\u0064\u0020\u006d\u0061\u0069\u006e\u0028\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067\u005b\u005d\u0061\u0029\u007b\u0066\u006f\u0072\u0028\u0069\u006e\u0074\u0020\u0069\u003d\u0031\u003b\u0069\u003c\u003d\u0031\u0030\u0030\u003b\u0069\u002b\u002b\u0029\u007b\u0053\u0079\u0073\u0074\u0065\u006d\u002e\u006f\u0075\u0074\u002e\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0074\u006c\u006e\u0028\u0069\u0029\u003b\u007d\u007d\u007d
```

Comment: dammit, was just working on writing this same answer

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), [posted](/a/155063) by [Martin Ender](/u/8478)

```
[##!]
[\X_]
@-99@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P8/WllZMZYrOiYiPpbLQdfS0uH/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/foo), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155034/61563) by DLosc

```
@10+10*+10(10@1>+$i<$c10-1)+@0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP///fwdBA29BAC4g1DA0cDO20VTJtVJINDXQNNbUdDP7/BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [ELVM-IR](https://github.com/shinh/elvm), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155048/12012) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
	.text
main:
	mov D, SP
	add D, -1
	store BP, D
	mov SP, D
	mov BP, SP
	.file 1 "-"
	.loc 1 2 0
	mov A, 1
	mov B, BP
	add B, 2
	store A, B
	.L0:
	mov B, BP
	add B, 2
	load A, B
	mov D, SP
	add D, -1
	store A, D
	mov SP, D
	mov A, 101
	mov B, A
	load A, SP
	add SP, 1
	lt A, B
	jeq .L3, A, 0
	jmp .L4
	.L3:
	jmp .L2
	.L4:
	mov B, BP
	add B, 2
	load A, B
	mov D, SP
	add D, -1
	store A, D
	mov SP, D
	putc A
	add SP, 1
	.L1:
	mov B, BP
	add B, 2
	load A, B
	mov D, SP
	add D, -1
	store A, D
	mov SP, D
	add A, 1
	mov B, BP
	add B, 2
	store A, B
	load A, SP
	add SP, 1
	jmp .L0
	.L2:
	exit
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZE7DoMwEERr@xQraoPMp6IDUVIgcQIEjgQygRAHcXuyK4NIEaIUdDvW88x4rfTcu@20rpx5Ri2G91V7jznrhxkyAWXBWdU0NLo@Z08zTArSQkBmkfIY6ZRw79ZqBT44roNCDzXOAUgLJQL8DRd4w5rjGOzeCKR4LZfxCaaHqtmoXx2TbxUpXR75yeG2exCMgDZbRKce4OWhIIlP6PoRZUQFw3iXAcno6r7jy9TU8KOVl/tXpxDx55@crMruQFK7ANuppTXr@gY)

Answer (score 1):

## [foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/foo), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155055/61563) by NoOneIsHere

```
(100+1$c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fw9DAQNtQJVnz/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## Cubically, [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops/155050#155050) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P8/miu/tMTKTKFOoUJBS8FQQRuI9YFYVcHMmqu4pCgzLx0o46BgYc0Va2hg8P8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155141/45941) by [jmarkmurphy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78067/jmarkmurphy)

```
: | 0 do i 1 + 0 do 42 emit loop cr loop ; 100 |
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WynUKBgopOQrZCoYKmhDmCZGCqm5mSUKOfn5BQrJRRDaWsHQwECh5v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), [posted](/a/155174) by [AdmBorkBork](/u/42963)

```powershell
("v"|% le*)`
..(""+,1e2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0OpTKlGVSEnVUszgUtPT0NJSVvHMNVI8/9/AA)

Comment: Less than a minute to post the crack!!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), [posted](/a/155189) by [msh210](/u/1976)

```perl
$,=$
";*a&*z;*aa&*az;*ba&*bz;*ca&*cv;s;;
$.++;e##cv]
      ;;;   print++$
      _..          $
=*
5/3   ;;;
6/4   ;;;
7/5   ;;;
8/6   ==*cv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1aFS8laK1FNqwpIAqlEIJ0EpJOAdDKQTi6zLra25lLR09a2TlVWTi6L5VIAA2trayBZUJSZV6KtrQIVjNfTU4ADFS5bLS5TfWOIYi4zfRMoy1zfFMqy0DcDsmxtgdb8/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](//git.io/triangular), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155166/61563) by MickyT

```
,i#%)`A;A^A@&NN*L!o|_\Om;;-?!>/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/XydTWVUzwdHaMc7RQc3PT8tHMb8mPsY/19pa117RTv//fwA)

Hah, should've recognized one of my languages at first sight. Formatted, it looks like this:

```
        , 
       i # 
      % ) ` 
     A ; A ^ 
    A @ & N N 
   * L ! o | _ 
  \ O m ; ; - ? 
 ! > / ÿ ÿ ÿ ÿ ÿ
```

I was trying to write a Triangular program for the cops' thread but `l` (less than) was broken, making it rather hard to end when the number hits 100.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [posted](/a/155221) by [MEE](/u/71966)

```python
#import<stdio>
1//1;f=__import__;
2//1;String=str
0//1;i = 1;
while(i<101):#{
   f("sys").stdout.write(String(i)+" ");
   i+=1;
#}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoMwEEX3OcWQbBIEddpdY3oJD5BNtQ60RpIRkeLZU4PL//jvLTtPYb7nrOi7hMhd4heFp8CmQTs67y/svRW3gnqONL9d4ijasgkcoBXbRJ9BU4ctmof6CQAYtUx7kqY@i2HleovEg758TaaSII0tR6rcWVBHzn8)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), [posted](/a/155235) by [Stewie Griffin](/u/31516)

```
Flatten[{1,100}] (* From x: 1 To 100: huhu% *)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3y0nsaQkNS@62lDH0MCgNlZBQ0vBrSg/V6HCSsFQISRfAShqpZBRmlGqqqClqfD/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fantom](http://fantom.org/), [posted](/a/155233) by [user902383](/u/20093)

```
class A{static Void main(){(1..100).each|x|{echo(x)}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0vMK8nP/f8/OSexuFjBsbq4JLEkM1khLD8zRSE3MTNPQ7Naw1BPz9DAQFMvNTE5o6aipjo1OSNfo0Kztrb2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), [posted](/a/155246) by [Magic Octopus Urn](/u/59376)

```
TnL,q,a,b,c,d,I,t=input();v=c;u=b*c*TnL
exec"if v>=30:v=c;u+=d\nv=v*v/25+6*v+140-u+I;u+=a*(b*v-u);print v\n"*t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxDoIwEADQ3a8gTHA9YlFxsDl3EkZGlrbUpMsFTXvx74syv6cH6/pQyswTvtGiQ48rjpgo8pZT0xohbzI58PA7p/ANvo6vSp501Y/DFK0LCwnI@TKoO4jqb7rLavyThcaBdLk12ydyqmThGlIpOw)

Answer (score 1):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155080/41024) by [Zacharý](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55550/zachar%c3%bd)

```
AȦi←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638/9/xxLLMR20T/v8HAA)

This is the representation in MY's encoding.

Comment: This should've been easy, I created the language after all :p

Answer (score 1):

## [pb](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Pb), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155032/61563) by Erik the Outgolfer

```
w[T!100]{t[T+1]b[T]>}
```

There's a Python interpreter [here](https://github.com/undergroundmonorail/pb-lang).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155268/76365) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf?tab=profile)

```
#for (o=1,100,print(o))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/Xzktv0hBI9/WUMfQwECnoCgzr0QjX1Pz/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Implicit](https://github.com/aaronryank/Implicit), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155294/12012) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
int f(int x_1)
{
    int i, foóßar = 1;
    int *arr = 0x23d3f44e >> 0xa;

    for (i = ']'; 100 % foóßar++, *(arr+i/1234) += ']'; 0-101)
        putchar(&arr[i]);

    return -8;
}

int main(void)
{
    f(42);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5NDoIwEIX3PcVslEIhttCFSSMXMcQ0QGOj/KQUQ2I4i4fwCBwMW4POYpI3882bN@imv9eDleVtXXVrQWHfpwsL0ROBKy91DKpb3stLGjgBE/9FJI2f0CnNqkxxXkOeOyUF@iKqM4C1A4IiEMAohd3fiJAYIuzuiT6wNOMhkI2jCaPuPWzVj7a8SoP3jj3rIty8TW1H00JyFGhGyIdppG7xo9PVL7rCPHX4vK4f)

Answer (score 1):

## [Prelude](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155292/25180) by [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer)

```
91+ v+   vv++ (1-v!)
   ^  ^^+    0 1+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyhKzSlNSf3/39JQW6FMW0FBoaxMW1tBw1C3TFGTC8iNA6I4kLiCgYKh9v//AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155355/25180) by [Wurlitzer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155355/25180)

```
0>1+:aa*1+=?;:\
 ^       o"|"n/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38DOUNsqMVHLUNvW3toqhkshTgEC8pVqlPL0//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155371/12012) by [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)

```
2.upto(100){|i| p i}; printf RUBY_VERSION, $$ > 0; p $_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/30ivtKAkX8PQwECzuiazRqFAIbPWWqGgKDOvJE0hKNQpMj7MNSjY099PR0FFRcFOwQAoqaAS//8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak (BrainHack)](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155097/63187) by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

```
#begin(
 #import(Integer)
 #import(String)
 #import(STDOUT)
 #define(Name:Main)(In:None)(Out:String,Int)(Mixed:TRUE)(Flags:None)(Requires:"String.format")(Coding:"UTF-8"))
 #begin Main(
  Integer.ranges.from$100.forEach{STDOUT.write(String.format{$0 }.with*$0=Self)(dropWhere{!$0}[ignoreIf:(0)])}
  Except{OutOfBounds}
 )
STDOUT.stream.read.forEach{with*$0=Self(Integer.ranges.from$100.filter(by:{1...101~=$0})[ignoreIf:(0)])}(if!Error){exit$0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BT8IwFMfvfIoxdmiNNt3N1HBRR8IBSGDEg/FQ2OvWyFp8KwGzzK8@O1kUTbw06T/v/X@/t0GpTSG3r2072kCuDRkEI13uLToyNQ5yQPqTrBxqk18G6eNinXZBBkobIHNZgpj5TurXxdwaoGRxcOK8ee0rKZnpE2QiXa4TSiY7mVf93BLeDhqhEuF5mimLpXQhJQ82838RrtPJzW1IO96XbNCRvHHQqzKUJoeKKbRlFHPeNSRyW9RnT3ZE7YD8aq8jHjTsqF1xFfHxCnaKkgzt/qkAhHoY8eZZ58YiTJUgnL7QxuOS0xb2rvaHLdS9PZis8ikd9JTKIciS@Sf7FrgEkH9t9c4Bks27qGPGWMzjj7EXoH8NiFbDBNEireGkXcTvmrb9BA)

There was a lot of balanced brackets and such made me suspicious. In Brain-Flak it errors but when using BrainHack it works.

Comment: Dammit, I tried regular BF but I didn't realize they had prominent differences. :|

Comment: @totallyhuman just the comments

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), [posted](/a/155395) by [MD XF](/u/61563)

```
1%P
*>\
A+.A
@~~.@A)][(An!!?_
`*/-S+1%U<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/31A1gEvLLobLUVvPkcuhrk7PwVEzNlrDMU9R0T6eK0FLXzdY21A11Ob/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155405/61405) by [iPhoenix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75797/iphoenix)

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]])+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+[+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]))+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]))+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+(+!+[]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]])+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]])+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]])+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(0+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(0+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]])+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Z3LasMwEEW/RTsJU8j/CC9C20W7aEpb@vuu/Lb1DMHFY3MoJCDJ0iTSvZo7mqjv19/r9/PX2@fP08ft5bVpbG21snVla2PdS11pq9o3V@7eXJmq2tq2ytWNLbtC1bdX68dV0CZs2BW4gXccPNtqN6v8zvshFy0i45UGHeuXfY0FIr99rzsxk@HXa727gXMTf4D0nPsLSvoyyFpzFLzKWiMCbaqm0WVYpaJ4Ek5JIleba7V6bPxyjbHSGf/SIrprgKuCq3JgVyVdn5iAjOGRib4M7A1aQMsp0OLvYnWwh839m4WToBJTJMG78T2b3NAi7R24RfZaigE70GRwYxaO6c7lxgLC9SoQQ@OSJOiHb4Bv8GjQL7nbFyNZ/mRkp0uy63BHWDHTf6pC3tr03TgdRDGIZsDBcDDRDNACWo4bzRj2sOLmbbTRiAegCBQRD4@KB4QBwgB@hV8RBqAFtJxIGMywKGfsTZ/GFlZHGaUyPQOvojsg6i3qzAuec38kR8GD8CBeA2gBLUf1GvpNzpDxtGXGE/5U0p@SnWazjAORdMOew55D3JykG2LrcDAcjEpGJYMWYusk3QBFoIh4IOkGYQC/wq8IA4QBaEEYkHRD0g1eAzyI14DXAFrwGk6ZdDPsv/1niQ3gp1J09y351m7UDddi3n8tJnS6PZ0e4QImU3SiM03tCpETBnMyRJ7/jV@BX3Fiv0LkFcKyrwAP7OWwFkKCkDisJdOTA104GA4mNEtoFrRwoEumJ1AEiogHMj0RBvAr/IowQBiAFoQBmZ7/m@kZe1mv@OV/80KAQXlQHgKM0xtEGhwMByPSEGmgBZHG6Q1QBIqIB05vEAbwK/yKMEAYgBaEAac3kk5vRP6KV6JJ4mxyKGmaPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), [posted](/a/155409) by [caird coinheringaahing](/u/66833)

```
DECLARE -> (A, B) => g [1, 2] , 100 () - () 100 V From 1 (#) RAN pop => GRAVREL & G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCoAgAADRXzkIQkFB2wuszCUaHFqiIQiaQun/wXA53nLXfedcyuyn1UWPHhBOMUr6gYfDKroThTUGIdE11TvLl14sopFEt5FTrkuIbo9@pSVQyg8)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), [posted](/a/155441) by [Steadybox](/u/61405)

```r
#define/*+[--->++<]>+++.[->++++<]>+.+++++++++++.-[->+++++<]>+.------------.-[--->++<]>-.+++++++++++.+[--->+<]>.-[->+++<]>+.+[---->+<]>+++.+[->++<]>.---[----->+<]>-.+++[->+++<]>++.++++++++.+++++.--------.-[--->+<]>--.+[->+++<]>+.++++++++.[->++++++++++<]>.>++++++++++..[------>+<]>.++++++++++.++++++++.+++++++++++.[++>---<]>...>++++++++++..*/\
print =cat   ( c (  1  :  100  )  ) 
#define print(x)main(){for(auto i=.5;i++<sizeof('i')*101;printf("%d ",(char)i));}
#include<stdio.h>
print("1 "*100)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLDoIwELzzFRuMoaV2hYMXUX8EPRAecRMFg5gYjd@OfQZ00zbdnZ3ZaftxXFR1Q229jkUupTwIsTupQ2Cu7zZDMQVKB1hEzkJDXkH@cJy0qnu6ldVlW3ddlqxVDWQxozXRJjvoHP3N1xSJYj7IE7x3/wCcpYh2pjM6t/9/MVJCqDFSt@KvTLw@Bree2gH2ZTEAAINSbUgBtupMEgCuV@C@Hkwze/JrQS3j76brWfEYOqA9bjJSRu/0qruGRRTxOE3SzBAaFi4rCFesPBc9J86zT7Cgtrw8qnp3Hyrq8HywRliYQqiYCR/HLw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Crayon](https://github.com/ETHproductions/crayon), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155463/61563) by boboquack

```
100O)q"q"q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5KrMzP@//f0MDAX7NQCQj//wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155467/61563) by Not a tree

```
//$#n=100(v.|)
[+]:<>/99#*%2
#~H6+-e>*</xxxx>
(^)>*{L}<d>;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxOzsxMyS8p/v9fX19FOc/W0MBAo0yvRpMrWjvWysZO39JSWUvViEu5zsNMWzfVTstGvwII7Lg04jTttKp9am1S7Kz//wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155312/61563) by Jo King

```
{%c++}=t=+~\%c<100;
ADD.+L0|~tt\
\OR;MULTIPLY c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sSsnMS8z5/79aNVlbu9a2xFa7LkY12cbQwMCay9HFRU/bx6CmrqQkhivGP8jaN9QnxDPAJ1Ih@f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155480/59487) by [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288/alephalpha)

```
print(Vecrev(((x^101-1)/(x-1))'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/v6AoM69EIyw1uSi1TENDoyLO0MBQ11BTX6MCSGqqa2r@/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155512/31347) by [L3viathan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21173)

```
O
nX`m
pd2F
d9
II
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//9@fKy8iIZerIMXIjSvFksvT8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155520/31957) by [betseg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56721/betseg)

```sh
`#echo#`:`#a:G.Array.Integer#`
;: PVar$i: G.Integer :;
;: `#FOR#:i=0:!i>a.Length:i+=1` :;
;: :: IO.Out.PrintInt: a.$i :: :;
;: `#ENDFOR#` :;
`#endecho#`
`#main#`:`#a:G.Array.Array.Char#`
;: PVar$i: G.Integer :;
;: PVar$j: G.Integer :;
:; i=1 ;:
:; j=100 ;:
:; echo {$i..$j} ;:
`#endmain#`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY67CsIwFIZ3nyKSbEJo1xMiiJdSEFscnBM0NKdghBgHFZ89Nm1durgcfr5z@153G6Oi5mxvVIGiGgq@8l4/eemCaYynaiaA1CftGQIpfpiASFzRXXWkgDKDOS413xvXBAu4kLkaRwBIWfHqEXjt0YVuH4jmDFPjd2R72KQ7/Uon4y6DT5evGt1EbKhrq/@49bydcBAEZU4EpNTKPMvGnD6SN0POWftJrPcY3sf4BQ)

Comment: I tried to make sure it won't work on Bash but `{$i..$j}` was too suspicious :p

Comment: @betseg tbh all I know about zsh is that it does weird stuff sometimes, and I thought this code counted as that sort of weirdness :P

Answer (score 1):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155523/31957) by [Rohan Jhunjhunwala](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46918/rohan-jhunjhunwala)

```
a=100
lbla
i+1
printInt i
b=a-i
if b a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MyS/@/z/R1tDAgCsnKSeRK1PbkKugKDOvxDOvRCGTK8k2UTeTKzNNIUkh8f9/AA)

Comment: I'm impressed. Quickest I've ever had an answer of mine cracked!

Answer (score 1):

## [TacO](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacO), [posted](/a/155087) by [dylnan](/u/75553)

```
$ 100
@(%
  #XX
&^0
  *i	*j
F=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0lMzv//X0XB0MCAy0FDlUtBQTkigkstzgDI0srk1MricrM1/P8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [QuakeC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuakeC), [posted](/a/155515) by [quartata](/u/45151)

```
$flags as spam
void(string s)dprint=#25;string(float f)ftos=#26;void()main={local float j;j=1;while(j<101){dprint(ftos(j));dprint(" ");j=j+1;}};
```

I swear if I found the most obscure language only for it to be a red herring, I will be *pissed*.

Answer (score 1):

### [Eitherfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Eitherf*ck), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155202/78059) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
#+,<<+-----<-----0+++++[+++++<][+<]
```

Interpreter can be found [here](https://github.com/saihv/esolangs)

Answer (score 1):

## Proton, [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155625/61563) by HyperNeutrino

HyperNeutrino posted this:

```
class M{fun main{args:Array<String>}{for(i=0;i<100;i++){if(i or i==0)print(i);}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxCoAgEADQX3FUXGxNDfqApr5AAuWgPDltCLlvN5c3vULYMI9x3aFWcfT4ZvEEyD1QqutOFD53NoKcNu4RSYI3FtxiplqrDlGCQBLgvVFlviZBWWYe4wc)

Of course, he should have posted this:

```
class M{fun main{args:Array<String>}{for(i=1;i<=100;i++){if(i or i==0)print(i);}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxCoAgEADQX3FUXGxNL@gDmvoCCZSD8uS0IcRvN6e3vMxUKY1x3b4UcbTwJvF4TM1zLOvO7D93VsYUt94CsUQwFh0sZqK1ahgkCmKBAEblGatEZXvvY/w)

Comment: You made the wrong modification, this prints `0`

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), [posted](/a/155648) by [chocochaos](/u/60848)

```php
'.
Puck, a day.
Page,.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Puck and Page]
Puck:
You are the sum of a bold cute fair fine good rich warm joy and the sum of a bad fat bad fat bad hog and the sum of a fine warm day and joy.                                                                        '; $_ = str_split('
Page:                                                                                              '                                                                                                                );                                                                                                                                                                    array_walk/*
Open thy heart! You are the sum of thyself and a day!
Puck:                                                                                                                                                                                                               */($_,function($_/*
Are you nicer than me?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    */, $_i/*
Page:                                                                                                                                                                                                               */) {print 1+                                                                                                                                                         $_i;/*
If so, let us proceed to Act I.
[Exeunt]                                                                                                                                                                                                            */print' ';});
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VU9T8MwEN3zK16lSmlLlIq1AVUdGDqBxIRQFRnn0pimtuXYKhHit5ermSoYoXyIN8SOfPdkv3f22cbuL@aWv2me3AS5ySBQiZ5/xJqyPFlIj@UsT24laYqz@yvtyeEQDKErHAJXMXeW3JkA4Qi@IXRhC1Mz3YNpK8jgCbVQDrViorUxFZySDXbCbfFo@sh1nCcqzvBHY2PW7wMjY@Thncdl5svxSUgLDEtcovOu7Gyr/CiN4szwpUhxYowL/AII50Rf7kS7mU6Sa0uaS6FHQ8L5AT4oP17tqK1jVcTKHryVKv4WJtPRsMzqoKVXRvOc1VmwEj0ropXk@@obobGlOf5xAjcyfjMUe3CCh@IbTjfGs3VKe5yf/dhdsv4FG7Cs0ZkMLXmEDtYZScTtwyA2tkM3e6Kg/epvGRTdSbl1vYyL/f4V)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), 53 bytes, [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155696/67312) by [gggg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15600/gggg)

```julia
i=[1,2][1]
while i<=100
print(i)
print("\n")
i+=1
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8/z/TNtpQxyg22jCWqzwjMydVIdPG1tDAgKugKDOvRCNTE8pQislT0uTK1LY15ErNS/n/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Felix](https://github.com/felix-lang/felix), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155700/61384) by Magic Octopus Urn

```
for i in 1..100 do println$i;done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0vNyaz4/z8tv0ghUyEzT8FQT8/QwEAhJV@hoCgzryQnTyXTOiU/L/X/fwA)

This code have been obfuscated a bit by doing `println i` instead of `println$i`, and doing `perform ...` instead of `do ... done`, but as I was using this language earlier it was fairly easy for me to recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155539/76162) by [Not a tree](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66104/not-a-tree)

```
def i = 1 ** (1+0): {if i == 99, $g = ?#: {$d or $n} i -> 98 + 0.0: put i++: loop}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclLCoAgFAXQrVzIQfkqdJaCtZmyhEjpMwrX/pKm5/hwbczz4hHgoCElak2qsXjDbw7GtBBr2akqKmbEE@LIJbsRZgBB9coiPTcCkcUeY8rMHw)

I got suspicious with all the curly braces, but the `98+0.` really tipped me off.

Comment: Well done! I thought you might be the one to crack this…

Answer (score 1):

## [ExtraC](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/extrac), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155764/55934) by Steadybox

```
for(int i be 1 AND not(i greater 100)AND increment i)do
print(i)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S60oKUpM/v8/Lb9IIzOvRCFTISlVwVDB0c9FIS@/RCNTIb0oNbEktUjB0MBAEySamZdclJqbClKqmZLPVVAE1KWRqcmVmpfy/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155773/47066) by [Magic Octopus Urn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59376/magic-octopus-urn)

```
{(1..'d')*.toString()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P@/oCgzryQnT0GjWsNQT089RV1TS68kP7gEKJyuoVmroan5/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155780/12012) by [totallyhuman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/totallyhuman)

```
p = print; r = range; one = 1; hundred = 100; i = 'index'  # set up variables 
  
for i in r(one, hundred + one):  # loop over each number in interval [1, 101) ∩ ℤ to print	  	
	if i==hundred:

 	  p(i) 		 
 	else:p(i,end=chr(44)+chr(32))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY47bsNADETr3VMMkEJaWIWVuJKgk7haS1S0gMJdUB/kAClyEDe@li8iU7DhijME53Ha2EZe5m1LaJAk8FxDVIrnb6oRmdSUNYaFO6FuN8djjaAiC9zRbwZ8YKIZS8LqJfjLSBMsYPsoehcYkiumeCMOO9VVe26MMSGuJCDfDuDl56JaI9qDZPUjzmWhH0uH@/8N978r5visaQBjTegRmuZFrqyFrlMeHIzRDobGiSr1BXHXtIPkp5M77PPr0zlrtu0B)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155994/12012) by [Agnius Vasiliauskas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75043/agnius-vasiliauskas)

```php
for 
(
 putenv("num=".(int)(bool)NO); 
 getenv ("num") <= 100; 
 putenv("num=". (getenv("num") + 1))
)
 printf("%d|", getenv("num"));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcw9DkBAFATgfk8xeYnkvRChRtyAO4jfhN2NoHL3tYhCM818M3a0Li@tz96sUKxg963TB5Pel4JinvQm3BgzS1VLBoWhu3s8gAR5gTRJ7uI/BL/wcyFSESWerf6yZwrakyL8kGTOXQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156029/12012) by [tfbninja](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69912/tfbninja)

```
3112211411100*11v
_*ŕ2vthesĨngulařity [[]((<>))] 
   4  /...psh...cřackle...fĨžz....pop24
is.../
    /coming to eaŕth
the ŕobots aŕe going to get you...
  /ĉ52*²
řun fas⊤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xDoIwGIX3nuIfgaHwV9yMFyHEVFIKESlJCwneQHcGdgdmD@Bg6EW8SC2Jy8vLe@/L60bj3A6RMcQUEZMkQhzIKbITG0wl9Lq0sm@4nWszQpblQXA4hmEOBABSgJhS2unKa2FnXlwa4W25LvZ9o1ulOpaSWnsbbwTEhbrWrQSjQHA7mYr4E7CTOiujwScCpPoPpDAwqt6zHo3X@55Fnxexc99CyfX38XTuBw)

Comment: got 'em [filler words]

Answer (score 1):

## [MineFriff](https://github.com/Lyxal/Minefriff), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233395/78850) by emanresuA

```
0,        v
>I:a,:*=?#v;
^o,Cao:+,1<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83MS00rykxL@//fQEcBCsq47DytEnWstGztlcusueLydZwT8620dQxt/v8HAA)

I'm sorry you had to suffer through using this language :p

Comment: I really should stop using languages you know...

Answer (score 1):

## [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/splinter), cracks [emanresu A's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233412/95792)

```
C{X{A{}X{A{\1}X{A{\2}X{A{\3}X{A{\4}X{A{\5}X{A{\6}X{A{\7}X{A{\8}X{A{\9}V{B{\9}M{}}}}}}}}}}}}}D{Y{B{\0}Y{B{\1}Y{B{\2}Y{B{\3}Y{B{\4}Y{B{\5}Y{B{\6}Y{B{\7}Y{B{\8}Y{B{\9}VY{DYX}}}}}}}}}}}}M{Z}CDXYZ{YAB\ M}Z\1\0\0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Self-modifying Brainfuck](https://soulsphere.org/hacks/smbf/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235072) by emanresu A

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LTsMwFET3@YrRdaXauIYYysZ1DNuuWeYhpZiAheqgBGUD/fZgIziazVzd0ZnPp2Fd7@2eQf6xSPmVY5FZjNKAJU8NBSqOFecfU4ifQjAvSZclPYfLZnvuA@IWaEBwuHImDTZqNFo9LIciVkTsdzYATl2ypuoOiqW2SxLzrd8M0OEfpW0xjBOe3vcIEVMfX194kgmDI4@7dJZc39yijx4a6bEUomBM1U5KqzKtq5WT17atXWezz7X68Q5NEzI@hDmMfh7X9Qc)

[PyGamer0 thought it was brainfuck](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59090673#59090673), but it wasn't. I looked at it more and noticed that the first instruction it would do is `<`, which tipped me  off because in SMBF, the program itself is loaded to the left of the main data tape.

Answer (score 1):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 669 bytes, [cracks Seggan’s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236059/101522)

```
D'`%$p"=IY|jExU5R-?+a/;-]Ilkih&}$BSbba+N)yxwvXnsl2SR/mlkdL)gfH^c\"Z_X|\[=xX:VUTMRQJnNMLE-hHA@dD=B;:9]=<|492Vw5.-Qr*/.'K+*)ihEf|#"y?`_uzyr8vutmUkpi/gOedchg`&^F#a`B}]V[ZSwWP8sMLQPIHlFEJIHGF?>b<;:987[;:381U5.t,10/.-&J*)i'~%${Ay~w={ts9wvoWmrqj0hg-eM*hgfeG]\"`_X]VzZY;QVUNrR4JONGkKJIH*)dD=B;:9]7<;:981U5.-Q10/.nmJk)"!~}C#cyx}vu;s9Zvotm3Tpohmlkd*Kgfedc\"Z_X|V[ZYXQVOsS54JImMLKDIBfFE>=<`@9876Z:32V0/43,1*N.-&%I)i'~D$#cy~w={tyxq7otsrk1ohmled*hgIe^$bDCYX|\UTYRQu8NSRKJnHMLKDhBAF?>b%;:987[;:381U/4-2+O/(-,+$H(!~}C#"!x}|u;yrq7otsl2pihmfe+Lhgf_%cEDZ~^]VUZSRvVOTSLpP2NMLKDhBGFED=a;#?>=<;4X810T.t21*N.-,+$#G!~}|B"yx}|ut:rq7utVUqpong-kjibgf_%]\a`_XW{[Z<RQVOsSR43ImG/EiCHAF?>b<$:?>76ZG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdCLmqFwGMfxa5lkZjCJZAdpDEoHZCo1RM4pKsccGodbt//a3efZG/i83/fnjp3J2jGNx4N6GUXhDURy3euSPitZCSklxiiB6JxjL6znG1yRJ5NxQoj559Oxs9o7mCyhrmPPGjFzzg6mfUgbdq79HnnuFFSl3ZREfiU0GzRiseXPGUVWiEJeJ4tXPI@pp2wSEXdxNPlST8RjC4ueXyOQXxoNDz/@Lnc8eK5ibxao2TJmU8scPQ9qkfGoctPVniafvr9y@2ZD/OJYp0bzHMvUSh@TItBz7z2ikMmllWzSe0un0CTyzAP95R6FL2X/fiIv3j5/Oq6/3d12mbJMxGjGLXNuMHofGg07uvqjdQlRVYSdhPMtgbHrQI/H/rW/hzcCHREDfeXydgx6ut@qkal/vh0PxD6vHdeem2lv1lawTLwO9NnfZUB7tyOqrb2cxXnObTbqFFeZ1@gPsjj6BO2/tEIGU1MonnlLxwXQHuWCdgoGetjun7fva2@/s9OBbsxAO2cM4AlV7YLdlXZXEg85QZbq/IoNdKtSDpaJ/r8MiiNYooW@Im8JmH0N26Gn8@16IPxdqDvYZmG5cyPRAMsMo1Oa0u4DXVU0WTqqrbbc2Hxhwh@dqdEUOSYiJfABgXdy6VQ76WFhO9AjDNCvFcgPdK8A9IOnKtvNemUi9nIxCXS9Pwa7f196WlEKl5HwDOcyKL2osmF7ES6UPsAyzOPxGw)

In all fairness, I’ve been doing a lot of Malbolge stuff recently. Like, more than is healthy. So that was the first thing I thought of.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237886/44998) by [Alan Bagel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/105116/alan-bagel)

```
#K1KHZRAS
1ò#d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/X9nb0NsjKsgxmMvw8CbllP//AQ)

Comment: At least that lasted about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), [posted by DeathIncarnate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247393/92689)

```
proc gen_range {r1%add!}

fancydef add:
    \\/\.+
end

cnt := 100
gen_range(cnt())
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/oCg/WSE9NS@@KDEvPVWhushQNTElRbGWiystMS@5MiU1TQHIt@JSAIKYGP0YPW2u1LwULq7kvBIFK1sFQwMDLrhuDaCghqYmSMH//wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG) or [SuperMarioLang](https://github.com/charliealejo/SuperMarioLang), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/155018/the-programming-language-quiz-mark-ii-cops/247423#247423) by [Number Basher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/111945/number-basher)

```
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+
:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:+:
# 2022 bytes for 2022!
```

MarioLANG: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9f2woDcmEKWXGNqhtVN6puVN2oulF1o@pG1Y2qG1U3qm5U3ai6UXWj6minTlnByMDISCGpsiS1WCEtvwjMVfz/HwA)

SuperMarioLang: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7coxCoAwEETRPqdYsbSRLXObCFEENbLRwtOvYJva7jPVH169z2x7srVs6Vjch9gstFcMOBwOh8PhcDgcDofD4f5zveioKtNz5SpzsS879xc)

Comment: WOW!!!WOW!!!WOW

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal 2.4.1(ish), posted by [emanresuA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255882/78850)

```
For 100 Do _ (
  Put n++,
)
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=For%20100%20Do%20_%20%28%0A%20%20Put%20n%2B%2B%2C%0A%29&inputs=&header=&footer=)

I say 2.4.1 ish because it runs on the old vyxal online interpreter, which runs a version a few commits after 2.4.1 but before 2.5

Answer (score 1):

## [pyret](https://www.pyret.org/), cracks [emanresuA's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256719/78850)

```
map(print,range(1,101))
```

It's the goofy language on TIO that isn't listed because it's [broken](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/44255?m=51940009#51940009)

Thank you Dennis very cool.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gopher](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Gopher), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155076/61563) by Conor O'Brien

```
'&^<'?×++<%@-<!÷-<'&^<.!<'?^×-<%!÷--<?^×++<++<%!÷<?×<+<&?^++<%!@-<&××-<.@÷+<'&^<.@÷÷+<×<÷-<'×-<?^×+<.!<++<<<'?××-<!÷--<%!÷<?+<&?^+<#÷-<'^×++<×+<÷--<×+<.@÷÷+<÷--<--<++<××-<<-<^+<-<<÷÷+<=
```

[Try it online ish!](http://shubshub.github.io/gopher/)

Answer (score 0):

## [0815](http://esolangs.org/wiki/0815), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155114/61563) by Erik the Outgolfer

```
}:S:<:1:+$~<:64:-^:S:
```

There's an interpreter [here](http://paulo-jorente.de/poncho/esolang/0815/).

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), [posted](/a/155279) by [Riker](/u/46271)

```
Define[$main,{Print[Range[1,100]]}]
main[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/3yU1LTMvNVolNzEzT6c6oCgzryQ6KDEvPTXaUMfQwCA2tjaWCyQXHfv/PwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pain-Flak](https://github.com/Cis112233/Pain-Flak), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155298/71256) by [Christopher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63187/christopher)

```
><)))))))()()((}{(}{(}{)((}{(}{(}))}{(])([({)(}{}><{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0jMzNNNy0nM/v/fzkYTAjRAUKO2GoIQTE1NIBmrqRGtARSsra61s6n@/x8A)

Note that I removed the unprintables. They are not parsed by the interpreter, so it doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155393/9486) by tfbninja

```
Print["1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 "]
```

Comment: I actually meant for it to be [Mathics](https://tio.run/##FZC7UUNRFANb2XEF5//pgpwhYEhwgAPj/h@XAiTt6ufz9X3/@r2ut@f98Xq/KYYTJEUzLCqoooY6GmiihTY66GKCnYxhjgWWWGGNDba44IqfSscDT7zwxgdfQggljDiLQSRRRBNDLCmkkkY6eYCSLLLJIZcSSimjnArq8BbV1FBLC6200U4HnfTRaXroZYRRxhhngkmmmGM7zLLCKmuss8EmW2yz54z/N4Tbx3X9AQ), but that works i guess!

Comment: Mathematica is not free, so the crack is not valid.

Comment: The [Wolfram Cloud](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/1619b2f4-748b-4a17-a471-9bbef049920e) will run Mathematica code for free.

Comment: So will [TIO's Mathematica](https://tio.run/#mathematica).

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155398/61563) by tbfninja

```
Ł1ɊHǙ:Ȱ#Ĭhȅȡ;œœ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9wdXNoef//xYExyYpIx5k6yLAjxKxoyIXIoTvFk8WT//8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Piet](https://github.com/gleitz/npiet), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155498/41024) by [NieDzejkob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55934/niedzejkob)

```
00000000: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452  .PNG........IHDR
00000010: 0000 000a 0000 000a 0803 0000 01cd eb0f  ................
00000020: 1900 0000 5450 4c54 451e 010e 02cd 0500  ....TPLTE.......
00000030: 212a 0134 3e65 be20 f0c7 0000 0000 0000  !*.4>e. ........
00000040: c080 0000 c000 00ff 0000 c000 c0ff 00ff  ................
00000050: 0080 0000 8080 8080 0000 c000 00c0 c0c0  ................
00000060: c000 00ff 00c0 c0ff 00ff ffff c0c0 ffff  ................
00000070: 00c0 ffc0 c0ff ffff ffff 0000 ffc0 8cf4  ................
00000080: 0b00 0000 5949 4441 5408 d735 ca41 12c2  ....YIDAT..5.A..
00000090: 300c 04c1 3d4d 1283 1209 61e4 90ff ff13  0...=M....a.....
000000a0: 4315 7be8 dac3 a877 9969 5329 63d5 ddd5  C.{....w.iS)c...
000000b0: 5eaa 4535 c22f adc9 30c5 6da1 8bb9 e327  ^.E5./..0.m....'
000000c0: 7fcb a7c6 1bdc 69a6 469c c120 51d2 67f2  ......i.F.. Q.g.
000000d0: a4be c163 de13 43bb 991d 49db f900 2114  ...c..C...I...!.
000000e0: 04cf a503 d231 0000 0000 4945 4e44 ae42  .....1....IEND.B
000000f0: 6082                                     `.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZNNixQxEIbv/op3T6KHmI9KOhEU1p1RF9xl1bl4EZNKWuYgeBA8@OPHSn/MjgMDFnRRIVVP3uqkfu7br8NBL/YSMXkNajRAV51hsri@010FJYog8hZQD/fv1GK37zefnswEI4w1P59GUbtlabiiFT0K48wWhhWGSXOlhqeuiD2BvGlSrsVZYWgvuxNj9/Bht/2X4YRhjZWDjSO4FjxKsxqj5uEoa3G4eq7odVM400HCYBE@Z/GcP44nS56X4@Ve/PQ/VkbsUTxHco9YX2SEScfj6Xx68Cg2l0/RJcYw6Ziy1vIpf3KTmGkj8kgXGbEzyvFeEiV5C2TkhnREHZwHZ1kay3ZmfLndXO@U8ur6yEjCcCIEmtjAVaqSH504nRBMI6RZm3GAFsaru07KpzqyMMgZj6E0OTizQ47DgJRCgndWQK561CoON@pPL/2t9p@f8SOjCMO3nOVRdd3WjsiVk2hjj1CzQSwloTk7AF/V1qsXSmn1o7OeLgwWxjByQR44wJTKCCkHUEgMlo7gTbUIw2jXf7pXb5XCR/V91VGFkak0yQ8OtUnb5EqRXkwft1ow9kmwxsz3Ii3c9ImT72pltH4vxNKBlyGr1pmTxy0j6/tAE3KjVYeZpnZ7v1FvFsYojKCjJPyHfVOHw18)

This is an `xxd -r`-reversible hexdump. Output is the numbers joined by spaces, with a leading and trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

## [Fission 2](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission), [posted](/a/155534) by [dylnan](/u/75553)

```
I[!$Z;R'd@
)Md`S,.=+-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8ssLs7MzzP6/98zWlElyjpIPcWBS9M3JSFYR89WW1fh/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [QML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML), [posted](/a/155538) by [Stephen Quan](/u/32354)

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 100
        delegate: Text { text: index + 1 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Windows Batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155540/61563) by Stephen Quan

```
set S=1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90;91;92;93;94;95;96;97;98;99;100
echo %S:;= & echo %
```

Answer (score 0):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155579/25180) by [Wurlitzer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78124/wurlitzer)

```
HAI 1.3
IM IN YR loop UPPIN YR var TIL BOTH SAEM var AN 101
    VISIBLE SMOOSH var AN "," MKAY! 
IM OUTTA YR loop
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8nPSc5PSf3/38PRU8FQz5jL01fB008hMkghJz@/QCE0IADCK0ssUgjx9FFw8g/xUAh2dPUFizj6KRgaGHIpAEGYZ7Cnk4@rQrCvv3@wB0xWSUdJwdfbMVJRAWSwf2hIiCPMbC7vEI8Ip0jX//8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), [posted](/a/155643) by [Iain](/u/78204)

```powershell
${-}=${-}-band0;while("${-}".length-le2){${-}++;${-}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6Vat9YWROgmJealGFiXZ2TmpGoogUSU9HJS89JLMnRzUo00q0Ei2trWIKpW4f9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [rk](https://github.com/aaronryank/rk-lang), [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155936/12012) by [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf)

```
int $1
while $1 < 100 do
  print: ++ $1
done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8r@/z8zr0RBxZCrPCMzJxXIULBRMDQwUEjJ51JQKCgCSlopaGuDFKTk56X@//9fNxUA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), [posted](/a/156095) by [MD XF](/u/61563)

```
Print!V[1..100]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM69EMSzaUE/P0MAg9v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Voidlang, 2627 bytes, posted by [iovoid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155628/77964)

```
"11"!"|"!"111"+!."|"!"1111"++!."|"!"11111"+++!."|"!"111111"++++!."|"!"1111111"+++++!."|"!"11111111"++++++!."|"!"111111111"+++++++!."|"!"91"!."|"!"911"+!."|"!"9111"++!."|"!"91111"+++!."|"!"911111"++++!."|"!"9111111"+++++!."|"!"91111111"++++++!."|"!"911111111"+++++++!."|"!"9111111111"++++++++!."|"!"991"+!."|"!"9911"++!."|"!"99111"+++!."|"!"991111"++++!."|"!"9911111"+++++!."|"!"99111111"++++++!."|"!"991111111"+++++++!."|"!"9911111111"++++++++!."|"!"99111111111"+++++++++!."|"!"9991"++!."|"!"99911"+++!."|"!"999111"++++!."|"!"9991111"+++++!."|"!"99911111"++++++!."|"!"999111111"+++++++!."|"!"9991111111"++++++++!."|"!"99911111111"+++++++++!."|"!"999111111111"++++++++++!."|"!"99991"+++!."|"!"999911"++++!."|"!"9999111"+++++!."|"!"99991111"++++++!."|"!"999911111"+++++++!."|"!"9999111111"++++++++!."|"!"99991111111"+++++++++!."|"!"999911111111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999111111111"+++++++++++!."|"!"999991"++++!."|"!"9999911"+++++!."|"!"99999111"++++++!."|"!"999991111"+++++++!."|"!"9999911111"++++++++!."|"!"99999111111"+++++++++!."|"!"999991111111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999911111111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999111111111"++++++++++++!."|"!"9999991"+++++!."|"!"99999911"++++++!."|"!"999999111"+++++++!."|"!"9999991111"++++++++!."|"!"99999911111"+++++++++!."|"!"999999111111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999991111111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999911111111"++++++++++++!."|"!"999999111111111"+++++++++++++!."|"!"99999991"++++++!."|"!"999999911"+++++++!."|"!"9999999111"++++++++!."|"!"99999991111"+++++++++!."|"!"999999911111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999999111111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999991111111"++++++++++++!."|"!"999999911111111"+++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999111111111"++++++++++++++!."|"!"999999991"+++++++!."|"!"9999999911"++++++++!."|"!"99999999111"+++++++++!."|"!"999999991111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999999911111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999999111111"++++++++++++!."|"!"999999991111111"+++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999911111111"++++++++++++++!."|"!"99999999111111111"+++++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999991"++++++++!."|"!"99999999911"+++++++++!."|"!"999999999111"++++++++++!."|"!"9999999991111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999999911111"++++++++++++!."|"!"999999999111111"+++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999991111111"++++++++++++++!."|"!"99999999911111111"+++++++++++++++!."|"!"999999999111111111"++++++++++++++++!."|"!"99999999991"+++++++++!."|"!"999999999911"++++++++++!."|"!"9999999999111"+++++++++++!."|"!"99999999991111"++++++++++++!."|"!"999999999911111"+++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999999111111"++++++++++++++!."|"!"99999999991111111"+++++++++++++++!."|"!"999999999911111111"++++++++++++++++!."|"!"9999999999111111111"+++++++++++++++++!."|"!"999999999991"++++++++++!."|"!"9999999999911"+++++++++++!."|"!
```

Answer (score 0):

## [51AC8](https://github.com/PyGamer0/51AC8), cracks [PyGamer's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233442/80214)

```
100r[t]
```

[Try it Online!](https://pygamer0.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&header=&code=100r%5Bt%5D&footer=&stdin=)